# LaTeX generated website with TikZ diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, online, html

I am trying to generate my static website with LaTeX to avoid tedious/verbose HTML and underpowered markdown languages.

I know of `latex2html` and `htlatex`/TeX4ht for generating documents in the HTML format from LaTeX but neither are working with TikZ.

Does anyone here know how to get the TikZ diagrams working? Any tips on using LaTeX for static websites is also much appreciated.

**EDIT:** I now generate SVGs from the TikZ diagrams by inserting this line into my latex source:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
```

I like the idea of using SVG because of the resolution independence but I worry about the browser support.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to write an *entire web page* in LaTeX, not just graphics and equations.  In that case `htlatex` is probably the best out there.  Can you describe what's not working with this approach?

Comment: Also, there's no need to hate on HTML and markdown.  They have their uses. :-)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what's going wrong with the TikZ diagrams?  An example might help.  I've been merrily converting TikZ diagrams to SVG for months now with narry a problem.

Comment: @andrew-stacey, matthew-leingang The TikZ diagrams are ignored by htlatex. I am trying to have the TikZ figures converted to another format like png and linked from within the html.

Comment: Please can you include an example!  As I said, I've not had any trouble with this at all so without an example to test, it's hard to know why your TikZ diagrams are being ignored.  (Also, I think you need to write my name as I do for the notification system to work: `@Andrew Stacey`)

Comment: I had a suspicion that there might be something missing like the `\pgfsysdriver`!  If you do some fun stuff with `.htaccess` you can figure out a system whereby those browsers that can handle SVG get SVG and the rest get PNG.  But that's _definitely_ off-topic!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My solution is far from perfect, but it has been simple and good enough for my needs.

I wrote a handout for a programming course using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) (a documentation generator that uses [reST](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) as a markup language), and the diagrams using TikZ. The TikZ figures are compiled automatically and converted to PNG when generating the website.

For example, take a look at [this page](http://progra.usm.cl/apunte/materia/sentencias-de-control.html)
to see how the result looks like.

You can also take a look at the [Makefile](https://github.com/rbonvall/progra-utfsm/blob/master/diagramas/Makefile) I use to compile the TikZ figures into PNG (.tex → .pdf using [rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber), .pdf → .png using [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php))

Answer (score 7):

There is [QuickLaTeX](http://quicklatex.com/) which allows the simple inclusion of (La)TeX math and also TikZ pictures inside [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) websites. However, this wont help you much if you don't use WordPress.

---

For normal websites you could use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class to convert TikZ pictures to PNG images which can then be included. See [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible/11880#11880) for further information.

Comment: I was just saying much the same thing :-)

Comment: @andreasw: There are several plugins for WordPress - the reason I've picked QuickLaTeX for [my own blog](http://texdev.net) is that the LaTeX stuff is done on their server, and returned as an image. So there is no installation or similar to do.

Comment: @Joseph, andreasw: Maybe the same interface could also be used to include TikZ pictures as images into normal websites. Maybe worth asking Pavel Holoborodko, the author of QuickLaTeX, about it.

Comment: @Martin: Very true. Pavel is very responsive - he did a few bug fixes for me when I mentioned QuickLaTeX in my blog, and uncovered some issues!

Comment: @Joseph: Much as things like this are a useful stopgap, they are an awful solution to the problem.  Above all else, they don't produce accessible webpages.

Comment: @Andrew: Not sure I follow in the context of Tikz diagrams! (In the general case, conversion of arbitrary LaTeX to other formats is pretty tough, so it's not exactly an easy problem to solve anyway.)