# How can I use TikZ to make standalone (SVG) graphics?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conversion, svg

I would like to use TikZ in other settings than TeX and I'd especially like to use the drawings on websites where the text should be searchable and selectable. However, I'm unsure of the best way to convert my drawings to SVG.

How do I best take some TikZ code, render the drawing and turn the output into SVG?

Comment: Use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class. See [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/11880#11880,) which should be easily adjustable for SVG graphics.

Comment: You can write an answer with that? I'd like to give the credit for it.

Comment: Alternatively, when loaded with the correct driver (put `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}` before loading tikz) then you can run `htlatex` on the file to produce SVGs directly.  I prefer to run them through `scour` (a python script for cleaning up SVGs) before posting them on the web.  It works well in my experience so long as there isn't too much text.

Comment: It's not a great one for how it's organised (the "answer" is in the question) but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15039/86 for more details.

Comment: I will post an answer. However, I don't think you can search and select text inside SVG graphics in your browser. At least Firefox under Linux can't do it.

Comment: From [this question on SVG ouput](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51732/latex-outputting-a-tight-svg) it seems like `dvisvgm` can be used.

Comment: How about upping the challenge; SVG with MathML inside?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Great first question.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I've tried most of the suggestions in the two posts you refer to, without good results, except for the Metapost suggestion in the second post. I shall try this, although I have never used Metapost.

Comment: OK, this is strange. The second post you mentioned led me to search and find www.tlhiv.org/MetaPost/tools/mptosvg/ . On this site, it is explained that first MetaPost is converted to pdf, then to svg. So I just used the online converter at the site to convert my pdf file to svg. Although the online site claims to use the same pdf2svg program that I downloaded, for some reason the online converter produces beautiful results whereas my downloaded version gave poor results. This may be a solution for me, but it would still be nice to produce svg directly from tikz so I'll let the question stand.

Comment: I see that pdf2svg relies on Cairo and Poppler, which I also downloaded, but perhaps they are not working together correctly on my machine, and they may be working correctly at the online conversion site. I shall work on this. But a direct tikz to svg solution would still be nice.

Comment: It would be very nice, if you’d provide an example tikz code, so others could try something out.

Comment: After a quick look into the produced SVG: Try to use a font, that you can also provide as webfont.

Comment: @SantoD'Agostino: Have converted your example to a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Which `pdf2svg` tool did you use? There is a commercial tool (by PDFTron). There is also an [opensource tool](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg) (current version: 0.2.1).

Comment: @Andrew Stacey When I use the advice at the linked question (with the command htlatex), I get a blank svg file, and the html file contains only an error message:

XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </img>.
Location: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/User/Desktop/SVGexamples/EX-1.svg
Line Number 253, Column 22: x"  class="sqrt" ></text> 
---------------------^

The zzfile.ps file contains just a single square root of x symbol.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey On the other hand, when I use the mzlatex command I do get an svg file, and the graphs are correctly rendered, but there are no square root symbols, and the fonts are incorrect.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use the [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class to produce tight PDF files for one or multiple TikZ pictures. I originally wrote it to simplify the creation of the many pictures of my thesis. Since v1.0 it includes a `convert` option which can convert the produced PDF into a graphics file automatically (using external software, which requires the `-shell-escape` compiler option).

This is very similar to [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/11880#11880), but SVG needs some extra care.

You can write your TikZ pictures the following way:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert={outfile=\jobname.svg}]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{...}% tikz package already loaded by 'tikz' option
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}% Example:
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,10); % ...
  \draw (10,0) -- (0,10); % ...
  \node at (5,5) {Lorem ipsum at domine standalonus};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then either you compile the file as usual with `pdflatex` or another `latex` and convert the PDF to a SVG manually or compile it with the `-shell-escape` option and let `standalone` convert it for you.

Manual conversion can be done with a number of tools. It is simpler under Linux, because these tools are easily available there, but should be possible under Windows as well. (The `convert` options isn't really tested under Windows, btw.)
By default `standalone` uses Image Magick's `convert`, which can do PDF to SVG but will not always give you good results.
The `pdf2svg` tool seems to be better suited, but isn't supported out-of-the-box by `standalone` yet. It can of course be used manually as shown in [Exporting all equations from a document as individual svg files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/exporting-all-equations-from-a-document-as-individual-svg-files/26091#26091).

---

You can configure `standalone` to use `pdf2svg` directly by using the `command` key of the `convert` option. Unfortunately, there is a small bug in `standalone` preventing it. I just fixed that and will upload the new version today.

With this you can write:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}[2012/04/13]
%\usetikzlibrary{...}% tikz package already loaded by 'tikz' option
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (10,10); % ...
  \draw (10,0) -- (0,10); % ...
  \draw (5,0) -- (0,10); % ...
  \node at (5,5) {Lorem ipsum at domine standalonus};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\unexpanded` is required because LaTeX expands class options. You can also add `\noexpand` before every macro instead.

If you need this more often you can also use a `standalone.cfg` file which enables this for all (local) `standalone` files. Simply create this file as follows in the same directory:

```
% Local standalone.cfg file
\input{standalone/standalone.cfg}% Load main standalone.cfg file
\standaloneconfig{convert={command={pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}}}
```

---

I might add a special `pdf2svg` key in the next version  as well, so you only need to write the following then:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert=pdf2svg]{standalone}[2012/04/13]
% ...
```

Comment: The new version v1.0b is now in CTAN. Mirrors might need up to 24 hours to sync. TeXLive should have it inside the next few days.

Comment: Escaping some special characters in the `command` key seems to be too complicated. That is why I prefer to invoke the conversion outside the `standalone`.

Comment: I am sorry, but `ImageMagick` produces raster images only, see
_Avoid using ImageMagick for 'Vector Image' to 'Vector Image' conversions EG: converting between formats like: PDF, PS, SVG_
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#vector

`pdf2svg` is the only way to go

Comment: @escalator: Thanks for the link. I actually didn't know that. Note that `standalone` uses `ghostscript` on Linux by default (ImageMagick by defauly only on Windows), which should be able to create true vector graphics. That is also the reason I didn't noted the issue with IM, I'm a Linux user ;-)

Comment: I tried to compile your latex file with `pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex`. It generated an svg image. But the size was horrible: 17 MB. pdf was 13 KB. So, this method of conversion seems useless. Or I did something wrong?

Comment: @user4035: The PDF will keep the text as text but the SVG will contain the paths of each letters which blows up the file size. However, 17 MB seems quite big. You could try to use a different PDF-to-SVG tool.

Comment: It is worth noting that the `pdf2svg` tool described in this answer isn't actively developed anymore and that it should be abandoned in favour of `dvisvgm` which is part of the popular TeX distros (MiKTeX and TeXLive). See [Martin's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71648) and [Koho's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377790) answers. `dvisvgm` not only produces SVG from DVI, as its name suggest, but also from PostScript and PDF. Also, it automatically crops graphical content to the exact bounding box and thus does not require the `standalone` document class.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Is there still a chance the `convert=pdf2svg` option might be added in the future? SVG is really taking over the web these days, making this option all the more useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, after some LaTeX kernel updates this raises a "(\end occurred when \ifx on line 5 was incomplete)" error message, which happens whenever a `\stop` is executed inside a package.

Comment: @user202729: Yes, I am aware. But it should be a warning not an error and compilation should complete.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [dvisvgm](https://dvisvgm.de/), which is a built-in tool of some TeX distributions (e.g. MiKTeX).

The basic usage:

```
latex testsvg.tex
dvisvgm testsvg.dvi
```

Then the SVG file will be saved in the current directory.

If you converted a simple math formula but get garbage when displaying the SVG, you can run `dvisvgm` with option `--no-fonts` to replace the fonts with path elements.

```
dvisvgm --no-fonts testsvg.dvi
```

As of version 2.0, you can call `dvisvgm` with option `--font-format=woff`, you should get SVG files that render correctly in almost all recent web browsers.

```
dvisvgm --font-format=woff testsvg.dvi
```

If you use TeXstudio, you can edit the `texstudio.ini` file (located in `AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio` for Windows) and add the following line below `[texmaker]`.

```
Tools\Commands\dvi2svg="txs:///latex | dvisvgm --font-format=woff %.dvi"
```

Restart TeXstudio and you can find your custom command at **Tools->User->dvi2svg**.

Comment: The `--font-format=woff`is a great hint which is missing from the dvisvgm FAQ. It enabled me to get sensible output in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge, while keeping all text as text.

Comment: This is also the top recommended tool at pgfmanual page 118 now: `Unlike the tex4ht driver below, this driver has full support of text nodes.`

Answer (score 20):

I use tex4ht and set the PGF output format to SVG. This solution comes from page 110 of the pgfmanual http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf.

I've only used it to create SVG of a TikZ picture in an otherwise empty \documentclass{article} but it looks like you could use this to make html with SVG graphics of a large document.

The advantage of this approach is that the SVG is produced by PGF and you know you're getting vector graphics. Also you get the result in a single step. It won't do functional shading or matricies and text in the pictures can be a problem but there's more on fixing that in the pgfmanual.

- In the TeX or LaTeX document preamble before you load the TikZ package, e.g. with \usepackage{tikz} in LaTeX type:

  ```
  \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
  ```
- Then process the TeX or LaTeX with httex or htlatex as appropriate. You may need to add tex4ht to your tex installation; it's at http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/. For example to process my file called logoname.tex I do

  ```
  htlatex logoname.tex
  ```
- The following output files are created in the current directory

  ```
  logoname.html 
  logoname.css
  logoname-1.svg
  ```

If you have more TikZ pictures in the document I assume they would become logoname-2.svg and so on.

I'm able to look at the SVG output in firefox and inkscape so it seems to produce good results.

Comment: This things works for me (with `$ htlatex file.tex`, not with `pdflatex`)! (Cf. the same solution [suggested in this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35154/2391) and [a not on using htlatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156998/how-can-i-convert-tikz-to-svg-on-a-mac)) As I had some problems with installing `pdf2svg` (I am on OS X), this answer solves my problem whereas the most upvoted/accepted - does not.

Comment: This generally works, but one needs to be aware of a bug in the tex4ht driver of pgf 3.0.0. See https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/327/ There's also a thread on tex.SE about this, but I can't remember where it is.

Answer (score 18):

On linux, you can use [`pdf2svg`](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg) (an opensource tool). All glyphs are converted to paths, thus you can't edit your text. But it is the only tool that seems to give good results for images mixing drawings and texts.

In your MWE, to get smooth result, I add the `smooth` option to `plot`.

Here is a snapshot of the svg file rendered by Firefox (*click on the image to download the SVG file*):

[image]

Here the two commands used to convert TEX to SVG:

```
pdflatex file.tex
pdf2svg file.pdf file.svg
```

Your MWE with my changes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-2:2,samples=100,scale=1.0,>=latex]
\tikzset{bgrid/.style={help lines,color=blue!10,very thin}}

\draw[bgrid] (-1.5,-3.5) grid (7.5,3.5);

\draw[<->, color=black] (-1.5,0) -- (7.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[<->, color=black] (0,-3.5) -- (0,3.5) node[above] {$y$};

\foreach \x/\xtext in {-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
\draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\xtext$};

\foreach \y/\ytext in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\ytext$};

\draw[thick,color=black,domain=0:7.5,smooth]
plot (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) node[anchor=south] {$y = \sqrt{x}$};
\draw[dashed,color=black,domain=0:7.5,smooth]
plot (\x,{(-1)*(sqrt(\x))}) node[anchor=north] {$y = -\sqrt{x}$};
\draw[thick,color=black,domain=-1.5:5.5,samples=3]
plot (\x,{(\x)-2}) node[anchor=south] {$y = x - 2$};

\filldraw[black] (4,2) circle(2pt) node[anchor=south east] {$(4, 2)$};
\filldraw[red] (1,-1) circle(2pt);
\draw[red] (1.5,-1) node[anchor=west] {$(1, -1)$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement your suggestion, but this doesn't work for me in MiKTeX in Windows. I can produce a pdf file as usual, but when I use the command 

pdf2svg file.pdf file.svg

I get the following error message:

'pdf2svg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Using the commands htlatex or mzlatex produce html files that do not have the graphics in them, and do not produce svg files.

Comment: @SantoD'Agostino: To my knowledge, opensource `pdf2svg` exists only for linux.

Comment: Sorry to hear this, Paul, but thanks very much for your time anyway. I now face the question of whether I should transfer my latex operation from my Windows machine to my Linux machine; if I do this (which seems inevitable, the only question being when), then your answer will be relevant, and I will store it for use at that time. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @SantoD'Agostino [here](https://github.com/jalios/pdf2svg-windows) is a cross-compiled version, that works under windows for me. Just download, unzip and add the location to the `Path` system environment variable.

Answer (score 10):

If I run dvisvgm with option `-n` and the evaluation of PostScript specials is enabled, I get the expected result:

[image]

Since MiKTeX doesn't provide a dvisvgm binary through its repositories, you have to install it manually. Recent builds for MiKTeX are available from the [dvisvgm website](http://dvisvgm.sourceforge.net/Downloads). Simply extract `dvisvgm.exe` to the MiKTeX subfolder `miktex\bin`, or even better, install it in a [local texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Comment: This doesn't work for me in MiKTeX (Windows). I get a one-line mash up of symbols, and no graph.

I placed the dvisvgm.exe in the miktex\bin folder (I'm using MiKTeX 2.8).

How do I enable the evaluation of PostScript specials?

Comment: In order to enable the processing of PS specials, you have to install a recent version of [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/), and add the directory containing `gsdll32.dll` to the PATH environment variable. You can check the availability of PS processing with `dvisvgm -l`. If the `ps` entry is present, everything should work as expected.

Comment: This works! 

Thank-you very much, Martin!

All the best!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear that you've got it working now.

Comment: Hi Martin, I think I spoke a little too soon. The program works if I use the example file, but if I try to use standalone with the following first line
<br /><br />
\documentclass[tikz,crop=true,border=0.5cm]{standalone}
<br /><br />
then I get an error message
<br /><br />
DVI error: no font selected
<br /><br />
and no svg file is produced. Any advice? (Using dvisvgm -l shows that the ps entry is present, so that is not the problem.)

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the fix. However, I tried it and the result was an upside-down graph (not serious as it can be flipped, but I thought you would want the feedback), and some symbols are not rendered properly (negative signs and square root symbols). I switched to MiKTeX 2.9 with the same result. I don't know if it is still a bug in dvisvgm or if I am missing some font files. However, the original MWE run with the new .exe file suffers the same font problems as the current standalone example, although the original MWE is rendered right-side-up in the svg output.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I've sent you an email message so that you will have my email address.

Comment: I'm not getting the `ps` entry although I added the path. My gs version is 9.09.

Comment: Fixed. `svg` created but it's upside down and mirrored. And some characters look strange - like they are missing edges.

Comment: `dvisvgm` is indeed neat. I [built a script](https://github.com/akerbos/scripts/blob/master/tikz2svg) a while ago that uses it to create SVGs from standalone TikZ.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out a tool I just wrote: [tikz2svg](https://juan.benet.ai/blog/2014-03-09-tikz2svg/).

Given `in.tikz` (or stdin):

```
> cat in.tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red!90!black]   ( 90:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[green!80!black] (210:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[blue!90!black] (330:.6) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It outputs:

```
> cat tikz2svg < in.tikz
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="93.472pt" height="86.205pt" viewBox="0 0 93.472 86.205" version="1.1">
<g id="surface1">
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(89.99939%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 76.742188 30.347656 C 76.742188 14.691406 64.050781 2 48.394531 2 C 32.742188 2 20.050781 14.691406 20.050781 30.347656 C 20.050781 46.003906 32.742188 58.695312 48.394531 58.695312 C 64.050781 58.695312 76.742188 46.003906 76.742188 30.347656 Z "/>
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,79.998779%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 62.011719 55.859375 C 62.011719 40.203125 49.324219 27.511719 33.667969 27.511719 C 18.011719 27.511719 5.320312 40.203125 5.320312 55.859375 C 5.320312 71.515625 18.011719 84.207031 33.667969 84.207031 C 49.324219 84.207031 62.011719 71.515625 62.011719 55.859375 Z "/>
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,89.99939%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M 91.472656 55.859375 C 91.472656 40.203125 78.78125 27.511719 63.125 27.511719 C 47.46875 27.511719 34.777344 40.203125 34.777344 55.859375 C 34.777344 71.515625 47.46875 84.207031 63.125 84.207031 C 78.78125 84.207031 91.472656 71.515625 91.472656 55.859375 Z "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

See https://juan.benet.ai/blog/2014-03-09-tikz2svg/

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: is this it? https://gist.github.com/jbenet/9449155

Comment: Lol about that fact that Juan's link is dead. IPFS FTW.

Answer (score 5):

I've written a command line utility that automates the process described in the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51766/163851).

It's called *tikztosvg* and it is distributed under the GPL-3 license at [it's official GitHub repository](https://github.com/GarkGarcia/tikztosvg). Let's say you want to convert the file `example.tikz` to SVG:

```latex
\begin{tikzcd}
    G \arrow[r, "\varphi"] \arrow[d, "\psi"', two heads] & H \\
    \sfrac{G}{\ker \varphi} \arrow[ru, dotted]           &
\end{tikzcd}
```

You could achieve that by running the following command:

```
$ tikztosvg -p tikz-cd -p xfrac example.tikz
```

The results will be stored in the file `example.svg`:

[image: example]

I'd love to have some feedback on it. Issues and PRs are very much welcomed!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you could just provide a simple example, perhaps from the manual to improve the now link-only answer. You should consider to make your solution compatible TeX Live and post it on https://ctan.org. You will reach more users.

Comment: @CampanIgnis It's already compatible with TeX Live! It uses `xelatex` for rendering. I'm not familiarized with Ctan, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @CampanIgnis I've edited my answer to include the example described in the manual page.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant it would be great if it could be shipped with future TeX Live versions or downloadable form ctan while working OOTB.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Sure. I've rewritten it in bash (instead of fish) to make it more accessible. Now the only dependencies are `bash`, `xelatex` and `pdf2svg`. I'll publish it in Ctan as soon as I can.

Comment: The package arrived on ctan: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikztosvg.

Answer (score 4):

I find it very easy to use [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/) instead of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/).

Step 1: Use the [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class and compile the .pdf version of your TikZ picture. You don't have to put in any other class options like 'convert' and the like.
(example:`\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`).

Step 2: Open the compiled pdf with [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/) instead of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/). File > Open > compiled.pdf.
This will open the pdf as an SVG. You can then save it in an SVG format or export it to any other format such as png, jpeg, etc.

Also, when you open the file in [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/), you can edit the individual components of your image. I find this very flexible to use.

Answer (score 1):

In LuaLaTeX, there's an alternative to the accepted answer that is faster (in compilation time).

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

% instead of doing this...
%\documentclass[tikz, convert={outext=.svg,pdf2svg}]{standalone}

% you do the following...
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("wrapup_run", function() os.execute("pdf2svg \jobname.pdf \jobname.svg") print("Converted to SVG.") end, "final callback to convert pdf file")}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

I explained what the `standalone` package does by default at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671818/250119.
You can see it's more efficient because it needs to spawn another `lualatex` process, while this method only requires spawning `pdf2svg`.

On my machine, this method is faster by roughly 0.8 seconds.

---

### Benchmark of different methods to convert PDF to SVG

| Command | Text format | Slowdown |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`pdf2svg b.pdf b.svg`](http://cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) (1) | Path | 1.00 |
| `mutool convert -o b.svg b.pdf && mv b1.svg b.svg` | Path | 1.01 ± 0.10 |
| `pdftocairo -svg b.pdf b.svg` | Path | 1.03 ± 0.07 |
| `dvisvgm --no-specials=ps b.dvi b.svg` | Path | 3.04 ± 0.45 |
| `dvisvgm --no-fonts b.dvi b.svg` | Path | 5.74 ± 0.37 |
| `dvisvgm b.dvi b.svg` | Text | 5.79 ± 0.33 |
| `dvisvgm --font-format=woff b.dvi b.svg` | Text | 5.81 ± 0.37 |
| `pdf2ps -dNoOutputFonts b.pdf b.ps && pstoedit -f plot-svg b.ps b.svg` (2) | Path (buggy) | 8.74 ± 0.49 |
| `dvisvgm --pdf b.pdf b.svg` | Text | 9.98 ± 0.59 |
| `pdf2ps b.pdf b.ps && pstoedit -f plot-svg b.ps b.svg` | Text | 11.00 ± 0.59 |
| `pdf2ps b.pdf b.ps && pstoedit -f fig b.ps b.fig && fig2dev -L svg b.fig b.svg` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22407621/5267751), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290006/5267751)) | Text | 11.05 ± 0.61 |
| `inkscape --export-type=svg b.pdf` | Path | 19.15 ± 1.06 |

Benchmark was done with `hyperfine`.

In summary: `pdf2svg` is the fastest, `inkscape` is the slowest.

Note that in order to preserve hyperlinks, in the original TeX source code, [you need `\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}`](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues/75).

None of the methods support preserving hyperlinks. Hyperlinks are not included in the SVG file.
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750771/inkscape-pdf-to-svg-export-retain-hyperlinks

(1): Note that `pdf2svg` is unmaintained now, http://cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/ recommends using `pdftocairo` instead which is only 3% slower.

(2): Note that `pstoedit` is rather buggy when there is a character with a hole, and the input file has text converted to path --- the hole is filled instead of zeroed out.

### Other methods

- Use `tex2svg` to convert from TeX to SVG with one command. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343943/250119
- Another `pdf2svg`.

  https://github.com/petermr/pdf2svg | https://web.archive.org/web/20200622093615/https://bitbucket.org/petermr/pdf2svg/wiki/Home

  I didn't test this.
- Use `gs` (GhostScript).

  Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18354777/ghostscript-svg-output-device . Unfortunately the device is deprecated.

Comment: Same question on Apple.SE: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66354/is-there-a-free-command-line-program-for-converting-pdf-files-to-svg