# elsarticle with latest version of pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, elsarticle

I want to submit a paper to Elsevier using it's `elsarticle` class. My document uses some commands from the latest version of `pgfplots`. However, Elsevier uses a TeXlive distrubution with `pgfplots v1.2.2`.

Has anyone resolved this issue? Is it possible to upload a later version of pgfplots for their building process?

Comment: I don't think this is a (La)TeX question. You should probably contact Elsevier.

Comment: I suppose the comment of @SvendMortensen is the answer. Alternatively, you can consider image externalization - in this case, you could include the final `pdf` images.

Comment: I think the answer is rather as @ChristianFeuersänger suggested. For this, see [How can I use TikZ to make standalone graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51757/5764)