# Figures for the new Evolve user guide

Tags: tikz-pgf, mercurial

I don't know how many Mercurial users are on this site, but if you do use Mercurial, you may have heard of the Mercurial killer extension, [Evolve](http://evolution.experimentalworks.net/doc/index.html), which is eventually planned to be in Mercurial core.

There is a new user guide out now. You can see it at
[Evolve: User Guide](http://evolution.experimentalworks.net/doc/user-guide.html)

As you can see, this guide has 12 figures. It seems to me these figures are crying out for some TikZ love.

So, I thought it would be nice if the community could get together and create figures for this guide. Once these exist, creating more figures would probably be easier. I realise this is not what this site is customarily used for, but since it is in a good cause (a widely used piece of free software) perhaps people could stretch a point. Once produced, it would not be difficult to merge these figures into the user manual.

I was thinking that we could mark everything community wiki, and each answer could be for one figure.

Here is the [source code repository for Evolve on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/marmoute/mutable-history).

Here [the figures](https://bitbucket.org/marmoute/mutable-history/src/tip/docs/figures/). The figures that correspond to the figures in the user guide are of the form `figure-ug{i}.svg`, where i = 1,...,12.

UPDATE: Looks like I jumped the gun a bit here. It was pointed out to me that the maintainers may not be willing to accept TikZ figures, even if produced. I've written to the mercurial devel mailing list, and I'll update this if and when I hear from them. If they are not willing to accept the figures, there seems little point in pursuing this.

UPDATE 2: As people here predicted, Pierre-Yves was not ehthusiastic about this. Evolve is his baby. Here are some extracts from yesterdays #mercurial IRC channel. Given these comments, it doesn't look likely this is going to happen, though it came up during the chat (details omitted) that another Mercurial developer (smf in the chat transcript below) had independently suggested the same thing, and said he had done some preliminary TikZ work on the diagrams. However, I've not seen this work yet. I'll leave this question open for now, if that is Ok. If not, let me know.

```
12:27 < marmoute> faheem: not super enthousiastic at the tikz idea
12:32 < faheem> marmoute: so i heard via durin42. are you familiar with it?
12:39 < marmoute> faheem: I've some exposure to it. but I fill like it going 
        to be a pretty high entry barrier for contributors. Both from a skill 
        perspective and a build dependency one
12:40 < faheem> marmoute: Ok. The  build dependency bit can be automated,
        though
12:41 < faheem> anyway, the tex.sx people predicted it wouldn't fly.
12:41 < faheem> as you could see from the comments there.
12:42 < marmoute> faheem: the dependency bit can be automated on proper
        operating system with proper dependency management.
12:43 < marmoute> (and I kind of hate when I've to download a fw GB of latex
        package on crappy hotel wifi when I do a dist-upgrade)
12:44 < faheem> marmoute:  is there some problem in using "proper operating
        system with proper dependency management"?
12:44 < smf> faheem: I have a fork of mutable-history that implements TikZ
12:44 < marmoute> [...] I would like to have a a nice and automated way to 
        generated the diagrams. But I feel like we did not saw anything       
        signicantly better than svg.
12:46 < marmoute> I can still be convinces de the tkz is better and less
        troubles. but is has to be amazing
12:46 < faheem> marmoute: tikz is pretty amazing
12:47 < smf> TikZ is da bomb.com
12:48 < faheem> marmoute: tikz is also quite automated. yes, it is a good bit
        of extra overhead
12:51 < marmoute> what could convince me is a easy a lightweight syntax to
        write the kind of diagram we need in evolve. The exchange test is a   
        good benchmark
```

Comment: since it's html, if you were redoing the figures I'd do them in svg (which I suppose you could generate from tikz) so they were scalable text not bitmaps.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle agreed

Comment: The figures in the guide are already in SVG format. I'm not sure I see how this relates to TikZ, (La)TeX, or this site. If the figures were to be redone, any suitable program/language for vector graphics creation could be used.

Comment: @PaulGessler True, any suitable program/language could be used, but I am suggesting TikZ, which I think is the best. Only the best for Mercurial.

Comment: Oh as @PaulGessler says, the figures are SVG already, in that case I'm not sure there is anything to be done.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, if you want to change them, TikZ is nice.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Tikz is far from optimised for producing clean svg for incorporating in a web page. I know there is a tikz to svg conversion possibility but....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was just looking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51757/3406 Is this a problem in practice?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have no idea, but unless the main maintainers of the document are already familiar with tikz (and using tex for the rest of the document) it seems a hard sell to say that tikz is going to do a better job, and be more maintainable in the long term, than inkscape (which is what is used currently) The last thing you need in a document like that is diagrams using fancy tex macros, as 5 years down the line as the software has changed who will update the figures?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about redrawing existing figures for which the Evolve authors have no need.