# saving output as .eps

Tags: diagrams, miktex, epslatex

How to save output of LaTeX file as .eps file rather than .pdf? 
I want to put a figure in LateX file and enter some text in it.
Then I want to save output as .eps format rather than in form of .pdf.
Any suggestions in this regard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `latex` rather than `pdflatex` then

```
dvips -E ...
```

will try to generate an EPS file from the resulting dvi.

Alternatively use `pdflatex` then there are several tools available to convert pdf to EPS (almost all wrappers around ghostscript) imagemagic convert for example.

Comment: You might note that by default the file extension of the output file is still `.ps`. Wouldn't this be better? `dvips -E -o file.eps file.dvi`

Comment: I was under the impression that ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick produce raster from PDF, so that even an EPS would just be a wrapper around raster. True or false? Also, beware: On Windows, the ImageMagick command is now `magick convert` because plain `convert' interferes with a native Windows command. That's why I use GraphicsMagick (command is `gm convert` on Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 6):

You can also [generate the pdf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51766/85946) first, then convert it to eps file in command line

```latex
pdftops -eps filename.pdf
```

If you get

```bash
-bash: pdftops: command not found
```

install `poppler` with

```bash
brew update
brew install poppler
```

Comment: Isn't the `brew` specific to Mac OSX?

Comment: pdftops rasterizes the pdf