# Generate eps from tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, eps, dvi, dvips

Assume the `test.tex` file for an image is as

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] {hello world!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used [the answer given by David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229281/64735) to generate the `.dvi` file by running `latex test.tex` in the terminal, then used the `.dvi` file to generate the `.eps` file by  `dvips -E test.dvi`; however, it shows a message and a warning that

```
dvips: Can't make it EPSF, sorry
Warning:  no %%Page comments generated.
```

Any help on how the issue may be fixed?

Comment: if you look at the top of the generated  file it says `%!PS (but not EPSF because of memory limits)` not at all clear what limit it could be hitting here, but you can use `article` instead of `standalone` standalone doesn't help much as dvips -E will set a tight bounding box in any case

Comment: The top line of my generated file for ```standalone``` document class is ```%!PS-Adobe-2.0```. I changed the class from ```standalone``` to ```article```; the ```.ps``` file is generated; however its border is not correct and has cropped my image. I think this is the issue of ```.ps``` and ```.eps``` in general.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that is the known problem that two pages are created https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/724 . CLAUDE: use \documentclass[tikz]{standalone} that avoids that the dvi has two pages and then dvips can create an eps.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your comment. After adding the ```[tikz]``` parameter to the ```\documentclass``` there is no error; however, there are two issues. First off, the format of the file is ```.ps``` not ```.eps```. Secondly,  when I try to see it by ```evince```, the ```.ps``` file is just a blank page.

Comment: hm, yes. There seem to be more problems.

Comment: `\documentclass[preview,tikz]{standalone}` seems to work, along with dvips -E -o file.eps