# TexWorks, convert to SVG after typesetting?

Tags: windows, texworks

I am using TexWorks on Windows 7.

Can I add an additional step to the typesetting command that converts the PDF file to SVG? I already have pdf2svg installed, and it works from a batch file.

Thanks.

[edit]

Here is the batch file I am currently using:

```
latex Cartesian_coordinates_2D.tex
dvips -E Cartesian_coordinates_2D.dvi
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None Cartesian_coordinates_2D.ps
"E:\Programs Windows\pdf2svg-windows-master\dist-64bits\pdf2svg.exe" Cartesian_coordinates_2D.pdf Cartesian_coordinates_2D.svg
Cartesian_coordinates_2D.pdf
pause
```

Comment: You could use a batch file and include that as compiling script. Do you often switch between compilers for that purpose?

Comment: I just started using Tex. Normally I use a batch file to convert from tex to svg using multiple programs. I am just now experimenting with TexWorks by double clicking on the tex files in Explorer, so I don't really know what I am doing. Should I create a batch file that accepts a file name as an argument? I have multiple tex files.

Comment: The question was whether you switch between `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex` or similar while you compile your graphics.

Comment: Yes, I feed the file into each of these (or similar programs) when I do the conversion. I will update the OP with the contents of my batch file.

Comment: Also, instead of converting to SVG, can I convert to raster PNG?

Comment: Have a look at `standalone` and its option to convert to PNG.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56007/discussion-between-posfan12-and-texnician).

Comment: Related question: [conversion - How can I use TikZ to make standalone (SVG) graphics? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not understand why you have the steps with `tex->dvi->ps->pdf` if you (probably) could use `pdflatex`, here are the typical steps using TeXworks:

1. Open the preferences (tab "Typesetting") and press the plus button within the fieldset "Processing tools"

[image: typesetting]

2. Add your batch file (which must accept one argument: here the basename, so "file" without ".tex")

[image: batch]

3. Your new command is visible in the drop-down menu.

Comment: FYI, the argument name `$basename` works fine for Debian linux, also.

Comment: @Digger It has nothing to do with OS, it's just a TeXworks variable which will work on every TeXworks installation. The only OS dependent thing is the *batch* file.