# Cannot correctly render symbols in latex SVG

Tags: fonts, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to import some diagrams I made using Tikz into Inkscape. However, whilst the text displays fine, the symbols seem to change when they are converted into the SVG. Most notably, '-' turns into '<=', among others. I've attached an example below.

I figured it was likely the fonts, but I've made sure to download all the computer modern fonts, and looking at the embedded fonts in the pdf (CMMI10, CMMI7, CMR7, CMSY7), I definitely have all of them -- so I have no idea why they aren't rendering correctly.

I've attached a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$z^\theta_{t-1}$
\end{document}
```

The correct rendering in texmaker:

[image: Correct Rendering]

Incorrect in Inkscape:

[image: Incorrect rendering]

Comment: I've changed it to be a minimal example now, complete with code. The pdf was generated using texmaker.

Comment: Which method did you use to compile and input the result? Which operating system? When I try your example with `pdflatex` in Ubuntu it works fine, even though I don't have the CM fonts installed (Inkscape substitutes with the default sans serif font, which apparently has the theta character and the correct `-`). You could also try one of the methods at https://superuser.com/questions/315270/generating-svg-from-latex-tikz or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/22407621/.

Comment: I have been using pdflatex in OSX. I ended up getting it working by using the Inkscape "Poppler/Cairo import" versus the Internal import.

Comment: If you want you can post your solution as a self-answer below (with a bit of detail, maybe a screenshot), it might help future visitors.