# Diagram with TikZ or Other in Google Colab

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

What is the best way to insert a diagram generated by TeX e.g. via TikZ or similar, in a Google Colab notebook? Tried inserting code for TikZ but that was not recognised. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe converting to SVG would be an option? See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51757/how-can-i-use-tikz-to-make-standalone-svg-graphics

Comment: Can you import pdf or images with Colab?

Comment: Hi and welcome. What's a ***Google Colab notebook***?

Comment: Well, Colab does let you install stuff with `pip` (https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb), and there is an option for using TikZ directly in a Notebook (https://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic), but it didn't work for me, could be that a complete tex installation is not available in Colab. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/30334730 for SVG, or use the button in the interface to add a PNG.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same question, figured out the rest.  Colab supports apt in addition to pip installs, so it was a matter of figuring out which additional packages were needed to work with the ipython-tikzmagic package Torbjorn recommended.

I found also that I have to specify a "-f svg" option in order for it to detect the image generated by tikz.  I suspect that a small code change to ipython-tikzmagic would fix this, or I chose a latex install that behaves slightly differently than the one ipython-tikzmagic assumes.

Here's an example colab notebook.

[Edit:  Adding notebook commands here per commenter's request.  Cell contents separated by whitespace.  This worked as of 12/1/2020, but likely will at some point break in the future due to packages evolving.]

```
!apt update

!apt install imagemagick

!apt install pdf2svg

!apt install texlive texlive-latex-extra

!pip install git+git://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic.git

%load_ext tikzmagic

%%tikz -S test_output.tikz -f svg
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\filldraw (0.5,0.5) circle (.1);
```

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GNczHdylcfYDFC1HpcloDRJxnmKpCuDO?usp=sharing

Would love to see ipython-tikzmagic to work within markdown.

Comment: Nice! The answer would be even better if you were to say in the text exactly what you needed to install and how, and where to specify `-f svg` (in case you delete that example notebook, or the link dies).

Comment: !apt install imagemagick
!apt install pdf2svg
!apt install texlive texlive-latex-extra
!pip install git+git://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic.git
%load_ext tikzmagic
%%tikz -S test_output.tikz -f svg
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\filldraw (0.5,0.5) circle (.1);

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when I click on "run all" I get something like

```pdf2svg terminated with signal -127
No image generated.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-14695ad3262e> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('tikz', '-S test_output.tikz -f svg', '\\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\n\\filldraw (0.5,0.5) circle (.1);')

]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpxxov9ug9/tikz.svg'```

Comment: @rainb, I reran it and found the same.  Earlier in the notebook, pdf2svg wasn't being installed.  I added an !apt update at the beginning and this resolved the pdf2svg install.  Notebook is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers. For future reference I ran into the issue that the PIP installation of tikzmagic on google colab failed (@time 2023-04-2). [Found a fix on the git repo](https://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic/issues/41#issuecomment-1478820755) . To install with PIP 'recommend:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/mkrphys/ipython-tikzmagic.git
```

Comment: This would be more helpful as an edit to the other answer, you can click "improve this answer" under the existing answer to suggest an edit yourself.