# Like MathJax, can TikZ be used in drupal site(website)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why I am writing this question here that If I came to know that whether TikZ can be used directly on website or not. If you are aware with Drupal websites(Drupal is a content management system(CMS)), in drupal there is a Module called MathJax, hence by that module you can display the mathematical equations. Same way, is it possible that we can use the plugin TikZ tool to our site (through module or plugin), so TikZ code displayed as graphs, diagrams, whatever?

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15039/latex-generated-website-with-tikz-diagrams?rq=1).

Comment: So you are asking for something that does for tikz what mathjax does for mathematics?

Comment: There is something called KaTeX recently but I don't know anything about it. It is claimed to have TikZ support

Comment: Yes perfectly, OR any way, I can display my TikZ code on the website as diagram, I hope there should be some way because, many sites display all physics and mathematical diagrames.

Comment: Well, I am not getting anything in google about KaTex, may be it may be very new. Id there any link about that, I will check it. Thanks

Comment: @MWilnand I checked this question, It is very helpful, it can do what I want to Wordpress, But not sure for Drupal, will  search more whether It can be done or not. Thanks though

Comment: If this is about MathJax support as such, it is definitely off-topic. But I'm not sure if it is, so I'm not sure if it is off-topic or not. But MathJax is definitely ***not*** LaTeX. Nor is it based on TeX.

Comment: You are right, just now I put the comment on Latex community and came to know the same. I will correct in the description. Thanks though.

Comment: I certainly get relevant hits on Google for KaTeX: https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/ https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX

Comment: Yes It is there, just I also checked, might be while I was doing google instead of Katex, after entering 'LaTex' word could have been selected from auto suggestion, therefore I started thinking there is No Katex, hence google is showing Latex, spell similar..