# Using TikZ in a browser like MathJax

Tags: tikz-pgf, mathjax

I'm guessing this has been done in a thread before, but I've just spent two hours reading various threads and cannot get my head around a very basic question.

Long story short:
I'm trying to create dynamic equations/diagrams in a web browser for a homework generator.  So far I've been using MathJax and loving it for the equation side of things.  It's very simple as I just need to include a single line of Javascript code and then I'm good to start coding:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['|','|'], ['\\ 
(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX- AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>

<?
$x = rand(2,5);
echo "x|^2| = ".pow($x,2).", so x = |\pm|$x";
?>
```

And it correctly turns that into the equation form on the browser.

Now, my goal is to do the same sort of thing with `TikZ` so I can create triangles and so forth on the fly using code like:

```
<?
$vertex1 = rand(2,5);
$vertex2 = rand(2,5);
?> 
\documentclass[12pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=north]{$A$}
  -- (<? echo $vertex1; ?>,0) node[anchor=north]{$C$}
  -- (<? echo $vertex1; ?>,<? echo $vertex2; ?>) node[anchor=south]{$B$}
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So my first question, which I think is answered "no" but is worth checking anyhow - is there a simple way to call `TikZ` in Javascript as with MathJax? Because that would be amazing.

If not, how can I get to a place where I can actually use `TikZ` from `HTML/Javascript`?  I believe that some websites show `TikZ` code, but I cannot find any documentation on this (everything just assumes I'm using a LaTeX program that can summon `TikZ` with a simple `\usepackage{tikz}` call, which I don't think MathJax can do).

For now, I'm running my scripts on a localhost my Macbook via MAMP, but eventually I would like to move it to an actual web server - but if it comes down to needing to install it at a root level, I can look into that. Just need some clear explanations since I'm really new to the technical side of LaTeX.

Comment: Which stackexchange site shows tikz output? Amaze me.

Comment: @Johannes_B Oops! Turns out the stackexchange page was just an image of a tikz output.  Not sure if that was itself generated (as I've read some things about being able to run the code and output it as a PNG instead of HTML/CSS?) or just an image created in a program and uploaded, but you are correct, it wasn't what I thought.  I have read of other sites that do it though, unless that source was inaccurate?

Comment: Off-topic, just like this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295894/like-mathjax-can-tikz-be-used-in-drupal-sitewebsite

Comment: I don't thing that there is a javascript interpreter of TikZ (even in [TeXLive.js](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js/) TikZ is missing). So in any case you will need some server compilation. Probably the simplest way will be to use [clsi-sharelatex](https://github.com/sharelatex/clsi-sharelatex) and then to send the code to compile and recover the result using ajax.

Comment: There is something called KaTeX which is capable but I don't know the details

Comment: it is possible to use TikZ animations to create series of SVG files that can be selected by JavaScript, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404600/2891. I am sure there is no JavaScript interpreter for TikZ itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LaTeX generated website with TikZ diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15039/latex-generated-website-with-tikz-diagrams)

Comment: @percusse AFAIK you cannot do this as is with KaTeX, it is a very limited (but much faster) implementation of TeX for the web. It is possible with `amscd.js` and Mathjax, but amscd is also very limited

Comment: @wires Ah, OK. Probably, I've misread somewhere and burned to EPROM prematurely.

Comment: https://github.com/kisonecat/tikzjax runs TikZ in the browser; the Pascal source of e-TeX is compiled to WebAssembly and the core is dumped just after \usepackage{tikz}.  Then https://github.com/kisonecat/dvi2html handles the DVI output.