# Export Latex to an png/pdf file

Tags: pdf, document-classes, output

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compile a latex document into a png image that's as short as possible.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible)

I once found a class on the Internet which allowed to export an latex image to an automatically cropped pdf file. It may even have allowed to automatically to the pdf/png conversion but I am not so sure about that. Basically it worked as

```
\documentclass{???}

\begin{document}
\[ a+b = c \]
\end{document}
```

and latex would produce an pdf file which dimensions exactly match the content.

Comment: You are probably looking for the [standalone](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class.

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate.  Plaisthos: take a look at the question that diabonas linked to.  Does that answer your question?  If so, we'll probably close this question as a duplicate of that one.  If not, please edit your question to explain why that question doesn't address your needs.

Comment: also, if you're using a Mac, you can probably use LaTeXiT for that.

Comment: Closed as duplicate on request of the OP.