# Problem with pdflatex and colored output files: PNG and PDF

Tags: pdf, conversion, png

I need to create PNG and PDF files from the same .tex source using `pdflatex` (Texlive 2010, Ubuntu).

To make PNG files, there's no problem with `dvipng` utility.

But with PDF files (created by the `pdflatex --output-format=pdf` command), I've no colored output, just black text.

This is my code, can I fix this problem? How?

```
\documentclass[dvips]{minimal}

\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{colore}{cmyk}{0.3000,1.0000,1.0000,0.3000}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{colore}{ test text }

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Have a look at [Compile a latex document into a PNG image that's as short as possible.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible/11880#11880).

Comment: Sorry, i'll write better syntax next time :)
PNG Works well, trimmed and colored, but not pdf :(

Answer (score 2):

It's a common mistake to specify the `dvips` or `pdftex` options. This should never be done in the global options nor when loading **graphicx** and **color**.

Only drivers different from these (`dvipdfm`, for instance) should be specified if needed.

Comment: Thank's, but removing dvips from .tex and using dvipdfm on output i've wrong output. 

There's no way to let dvips and color package live together?

Comment: You don't need `dvipdfm` unless you use that program for producing the PDF file. That's the meaning of *if needed*. Don't specify *any* option for the standard drivers such as `dvipng` and `dvips` or for `pdflatex`.