# How can we display fireworks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

Soon we can celebrate the New Year. How can we use TikZ for drawing fireworks? For example like this, photographed by Kurume-Shimin, found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireworks):

[image: Fireworks Aug 5, 2011 in Kurume, Fukuoka, Japan]

Click on [Image search](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=fireworks) for getting further impressions. On the Wikipedia page you can see further effects, just click the image. I would like to post a nice drawing on our [blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/) for celebrating New Year, and as addition to the [TikZ example gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) on this occasion.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219349/make-fireworks-with-only-text

Comment: Inspiration: [Fireworks fractals](http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=fractal+fireworks)

Comment: If the Fireworks fractals link doesn't work for you, try [this one](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=fractal+fireworks) (it should be the same search)

Comment: I wish @Malipivo had finished his project (cf.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161287/34551 ), so that we could have some firework of math equations!

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Here is my take:

**Update**: More "bling bling", more compilation time... (and trying @Stefan's brilliant idea)

**Update 2** Thanks to Stefan, I have seen that the previous version was only working in the QtikZ environment but nowhere(I guess) else. For some reason beyond me, the fadings are still not displayed correctly in Adobe Reader but at least it works (almost) properly in SumatraPDF on Windows. Sorry for the inconvenience and Happy New Year everyone!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{someshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!40);color(4mm)=(pgftransparent!50);color(8mm)=(pgftransparent!70);color(2cm)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{somenodeshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!0);color(2mm)=(pgftransparent!0);color(5mm)=(pgftransparent!99);color(20mm)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{invertshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!100);color(10mm)=(pgftransparent!95);color(16mm)=(pgftransparent!60);color(2cm)=(pgftransparent!0)}

\pgfdeclarefading{fadeit}{\pgfuseshading{someshade}}
\pgfdeclarefading{fadein}{\pgfuseshading{invertshade}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[projectile/.style={decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=0.5pt}}]
\fill[black] (-4,-3) rectangle (6,4);

\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-0.4cm,transparency group]
\pgfsetfading{fadein}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointorigin}}
    \foreach \x in {0,10,..., 360}{\draw[blue!80!white,projectile,line width=1.1pt] (0,0) to [in=90] (10*rand+\x:rand*1mm+2cm);};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=1cm]
   \foreach \x in {0,12,..., 360}{\draw [yellow!5,thick,projectile] (0.7,0) to  (3*rand+\x :1mm*rand+2.2cm)  node%
[circle,inner sep=1mm,shade,shading=somenodeshade,opacity=1,outer sep=0] {};}
{\pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2.5cm}{1cm}}}};\fill[white] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,yshift=-1cm]
\foreach \x in {0,10,..., 360}{\def\r1{rand}\draw [yellow]  ($(0,0)!abs{\r1}!(\x :5mm)$) to [in=90] ($(0,0)!abs{\r1}+0.2!(\x :8mm)$);}
{\pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{3cm}{-1cm}}}};\fill[yellow,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=-1cm,yshift=1.5cm]
   \foreach \x in {0,12,..., 360}{\def\r2{rand}\draw [red,line width=0.5pt]  ($(0,0)!abs{\r2}!(\x :3mm)$) -- ($(0,0)!abs{\r2}+0.1!(\x :7mm)$);}
{\pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-1cm}{1.5cm}}}};\fill[red,opacity=0.6] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the updated code gives (see the history for the previous code)

[image]

Comment: Fading is a very good idea here !

Comment: Same is your coloring scheme. I loved it!

Comment: Incredible, the first one is beautiful and the second one is very realistic! Is fading of projectile paths possible, instead of for example the homogeneous blue?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Let me try.

Comment: I think this is the best one.

Comment: Great fireworks! I have posted it on [our blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/happy-new-year/) with New Year greetings and in the [TiKZ example gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fireworks/).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Thanks a lot. But I have just seen your comment about the viewing issues and it looks quite serious. Apparently, it only works under the QTikZ previewer which is quite strange. I will try to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: @percusse Thanks! I wasn't sure if it's only an issue of reader capabilities, that's why I did not mention it here yet.

Comment: I think this needs still some work. Some randomness and connection to R. Probably, adjust fireworks according to a building. Should we open a new thread for Firework Christmas card?

Comment: In TL2015 and adobe reader X the spots on the (near-)white firework aren't as pretty as in the above image. It looks like the tranpsarency isn't working properly as they have a black halo.  Removing `color(20mm)=(pgftransparent!100)` from line 5, or replacing the 20mm with 5.1mm helps a lot but doesn't fix it

Answer (score 116):

Update 4 : it's better with more rays and I add a decoration (Stephan's idea) but the result is aleatory. I change some arguments.
With some shading in the center (idea from percusse and bloodworks):

```
\documentclass{minimal} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc} 

 \usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathmorphing} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={bent,aspect=.3}]
  \draw[fill=black] (-8,-3) rectangle (8,5); 
  \foreach \colA/\colB/\sx/\sy in {red/yellow/-4/2,blue/green/-2/1,
                                   yellow/red/0/2,green/blue/4/2,yellow/white/3/1.5} 
{% 
   \draw[shading=radial, inner color=white, outer color=black, opacity=.5]  (\sx,\sy) circle (1cm);   
  \pgfmathparse{rnd}   
  \let\ri\pgfmathresult  
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\sx]
      \foreach \i in {0,...,150}{%  
         \pgfmathparse{rnd}
         \global\let\x\pgfmathresult 
         \pgfmathparse{rnd}  
         \global\let\y\pgfmathresult 
         \pgfmathparse{rnd} 
         \let\c\pgfmathresult 
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\col}{50*\c+50} 
           \draw[decorate,\colA!\col!\colB] %
           ($(360*\x:2*\ri*\y+1) +(\sx,\sy)$) to    ($(360*\x:1*\y) + (\sx,\sy)$);} 
  \end{scope}
} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice already! Perhaps adding a path morphing decoration would be nice, such as by `\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={bent,aspect=.3}]` and `\draw[decorate,\colA!\col!\colB]` however modified for bending in one direction (wind effect).

Comment: Yes there are some possible modifications.

Comment: Very nice! Maybe using `\colA` for the `inner color` option would make it even nicer!

Comment: I try but the result was not fine

Answer (score 87):

Happy New Year to all friends in TEX.SX.

This code stands on the ideas from Cmhughes and Bloodworks. I am disappointed that latex isn't allowing me to add sound:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}%
\begin{filecontents*}{beam.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\foreach \radius in {1,2,...,20}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % background rectangle
  \filldraw[black] (-3,-3) rectangle (5,3);
    \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius)};
   \foreach \x in {-2,-.5,2.3,4}{
   \pgfmathrandominteger{\y}{0}{2.9}
   \node[xshift=5*rnd,blue!\pgfmathresult!white,scale={.8*rnd}]at (\x,\y){$\star$};
   }
  \ifnum\radius<4
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius)*4};
  \draw[blue!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=.5pt},ultra thin] (0.5 , -2.9)--(0,0);
\fi
  \ifnum\radius<11
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-1)*10};
  \fill[shading=radial, inner color=white!\pgfmathresult!black, outer color=black, opacity=.8](0,0) circle (\radius mm -2mm);   
   \foreach \angle in {0,10,...,360}
{
 \draw[red!\pgfmathresult!black,,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=.3pt}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius mm)node[white!\pgfmathresult!blue, yshift=-.1mm,scale=.35*rnd]{*};
 }
\fi
%%%
  \ifnum\radius>5
  \ifnum\radius<10
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius)*4};
  \draw[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,red!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=.5pt},ultra thin] (1 , -3.9)--(0,0);
\fi\fi
\ifnum\radius>5
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-6)*7};
 \fill[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,shading=radial, inner color=white!\pgfmathresult!black, outer color=black, opacity=.8](0,0) circle (\radius mm -9mm);
 \foreach \angle in {0,20,...,360}
{
 \draw[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,orange!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=.3pt}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius mm -4mm)node[white!\pgfmathresult!blue, yshift=-.1mm,scale=.5*rnd]{*};
 }
 \foreach \angle in {10,30,...,350}{
 \draw[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,red!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=.5pt}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius mm -5mm)node[red!\pgfmathresult!black, yshift=-.1mm,scale=.5*rnd]{*};
 }
    \foreach \angle in {15,35,...,355}{
 \draw[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,yellow!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=.5pt},opacity=.5] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius mm -6mm)node[white!\pgfmathresult!black, yshift=-.1mm,scale=.5*rnd,opacity=1]{*};
 }
     \foreach \angle in {5,25,...,355}{
 \draw[xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm,green!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=.5pt},opacity=.5] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius mm -3mm)node[orange!\pgfmathresult!black, yshift=-.1mm,scale=.5*rnd,opacity=1]{*};
 }
 \fi
 % yellow firework
  \ifnum\radius>10
  \ifnum\radius<14
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius)*4};
      \draw[xshift=3cm,yshift=1.5cm,blue!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=.5pt},ultra thin] (1 , -4.5)--(0,0);
\fi\fi
   \ifnum\radius>10
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-1)*5};
   \fill[xshift=3cm,yshift=1.5cm,shading=radial, inner color=green!\pgfmathresult!black, outer color=black, opacity=.8](0,0) circle (\radius mm -10mm);
   \foreach \angle in {0,10,...,360}
{
 \draw[xshift=3cm,yshift=1.5cm,yellow!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=.5pt},opacity=.5] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius mm -8mm)node[orange!\pgfmathresult!black, yshift=-.1mm,scale=.8*rnd,opacity=1]{*};
 }
\fi
   % blue green firework
  \ifnum\radius>10
  \ifnum\radius<14
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius)*4};
  \draw[xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=1.5cm,green!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=.5pt},ultra thin] (-1, -4.5)--(0,0);
\fi\fi
   \ifnum\radius>10
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-1)*5};
       \fill[xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=1.5cm,shading=radial, inner color=yellow!\pgfmathresult!black, outer color=black, opacity=.8](0,0) circle (\radius mm -10mm);
   \foreach \angle in {10,20,...,360}
{
 \draw[xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=1.5cm,green!\pgfmathresult!black,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=.5pt},opacity=.5] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius mm -8mm)node[red!\pgfmathresult!black, yshift=-.1mm,scale=.8*rnd,opacity=1]{*};
 }
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}

\end{filecontents*}
%create the beam.pdf.
\immediate\write18{pdflatex beam}
% convert to GIF animation
\immediate\write18{convert -delay 15 -loop 0 -density 200 -alpha remove beam.pdf beam.gif}

\begin{document}
 Look for the beam.gif file in the same directory as this file.
\end{document}
```

Compile it with `pdflatex` and you should have installed `imagemagick` for generating `.gif` file.

[image]

Comment: TikZ rules. Nice one.

Comment: Reminds me of the Death Star while destroying planets. Nice work.

Comment: Great! Very good TikZ animation - impressive!

Comment: what, no sound?  ;-)  Very nice!

Comment: A nice animation but firing at the speed of light makes it less realistic. :-)

Comment: @AdorableCreature: OK As you wish. Brakes applied now. Hope you won't chargesheet me for over speeding `;-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar Excellent work! It's awesome!

Comment: @HK Excellent work! How you know all these things?

Answer (score 60):

Happy New Year everyone!

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes}

\begin{document}

\foreach \radius in {1,2,...,20}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % background rectangle
  \filldraw[black] (-3,-3) rectangle (5,3);
  % skyline
  \filldraw[black!80!blue](-3,-3)--(-3,-2)--(-2.5,-2)--(-2.5,-1)--(-2.25,-1)--(-2.25,-2)--(-2,-2)
                            --(-2,-1)--(-1.75,-0.75)--(-1.5,-1)
                            --(-1.5,-2)--(-1.1,-2)--(-1.1,0)--(-0.5,0)--(-0.5,-2)
                            --(0,-2)--(0,-1.5)--(1,-1.5)--(1.25,-0.5)--(1.5,-1.5)--(1.5,-2)
                            --(2,-2)--(2,0)--(2.5,0)--(2.5,-2)
                            --(3,-2)--(3,-1)--(4,-1)--(4,-2)--(5,-2)--(5,-3)--cycle;
  % moon- what a hack!
  \filldraw[white] (4,2.5) arc (90:-90:20pt);
  \filldraw[black] (3.8,2.5) arc (90:-90:20pt);
  % fireworks
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-1)*10};
  % red firework
  \ifnum\radius<11
      \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses},red!\pgfmathresult!black] (0,0) circle (\radius ex);
  \fi
  % orange firework
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-6)*10};
  \ifnum\radius>5
      \ifnum\radius<16
          \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses},orange!\pgfmathresult!black] (1,1) circle ( \radius ex-5ex);
      \fi
  \fi
  % yellow firework
  \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-11)*10};
  \ifnum\radius>10
      \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses},yellow!\pgfmathresult!black] (2.5,1) circle (\radius ex-10ex);
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

The above code will produce a `pdf` file with each frame. See [How to convert pstricks animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73545/how-to-convert-pstricks-animation-to-gif-file) for the full details of the remaining two (very easy) steps, which were

```
pdfcrop myfile.pdf
convert -delay 20 -loop 0 -density 300 myfile-crop.pdf fireworks.gif
```

Comment: Placing a displaced black disk on a white one seems to be an easier hack to create a crescent.

Comment: @AdorableCreature that's pretty much what I did- hence the, 'what a hack' comment :) happy new year!

Comment: Happy New Year too!

Answer (score 48):

Not quite as smart as the two above but well thats what i have. I (almost) used no commands starting with `pgf`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=black] (-5,-15) rectangle (25,15);
 \foreach \mya in {1,10,20}{
  \pgfmathrandominteger{\myb}{1}{10}
  \draw[shading=radial, inner color=white, outer color=black, opacity=.5](\mya , \myb) circle (5cm);
  \foreach \x in {-3.1,-2,-1.1,0.1,1.2,2.3,3.1}{%
  \foreach \y in {-3.2,-2.1,-1.2,0,1.1,2,3.2}{%
  \draw[red, thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}, rotate around={10:(\mya , \myb)}, opacity=0.7](\mya , \myb)--(\mya+\x, \myb+\y)node[red, yshift=-.1mm]{*};%
  \draw[blue,decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}, rotate around={20:(\mya , \myb)}](\mya , \myb)--(\mya+\x, \myb+\y)node[red, yshift=-.1mm]{*};%
  \draw[red!50!yellow, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}, rotate around={50:(\mya , \myb)}](\mya , \myb)--(\mya+\x,  \myb+\y);
 }
 }
 \draw[decorate, decoration=snake, red, thick] (0 , -13)--(\mya , \myb);
}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It takes a while to compile!

Comment: I can't look at it without the virtual "Piiuuuuuuw" sound in my head :)

Answer (score 44):

Updated and final version:
[image: fireworks!]

The code runs to 856 lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{someshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!40);color(4mm)=(pgftransparent!50);color(8mm)=(pgftransparent!70);color(2cm)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{somenodeshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!0);color(2mm)=(pgftransparent!0);color(5mm)=(pgftransparent!99);color(5.1mm)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{flameshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!20);color(3mm)=(pgftransparent!50);color(8mm)=(pgftransparent!80);color(2cm)=(pgftransparent!100)}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{invertshade}{\pgfpointorigin}{color(0mm)=(pgftransparent!100);color(5mm)=(pgftransparent!95);color(16mm)=(pgftransparent!40);color(3cm)=(pgftransparent!0)}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{romanshade}{4cm}{color(0cm)=(pgftransparent);color(1cm)=(pgftransparent!50);color(2cm)=(pgftransparent)}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{trailshade}{10cm}{color(0cm)=(pgftransparent);color(3cm)=(pgftransparent!0)}
\pgfdeclarefading{fadetrail}{\pgfuseshading{trailshade}}
\pgfdeclarefading{fadeit}{\pgfuseshading{someshade}}
\pgfdeclarefading{fadein}{\pgfuseshading{invertshade}}
\pgfdeclarefading{faderoman}{\pgfuseshading{romanshade}}
\pgfdeclarefading{fadeflame}{\pgfuseshading{flameshade}}
%bursts(rocket/mortar)
\def\burst{
    \pgfgettransform{\mycurrenttransform}
    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{colour}{{\basecolour}{\basecolour!90!black}{\basecolour!80!black}{\basecolour!90!white}{\basecolour!70!\secondcolour}{\basecolour!80!\secondcolour}}
    \node [coordinate] at(0,0) (burstpoint){};
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\smoke}{true}}{
        \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}};\fill[\smokecolour,opacity=.8] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    }{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\centreblob}{true}}{
        \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}\pgftransformscale{.3}}
        \node [circle,minimum width=\centreblobwidth, minimum height=\centreblobwidth, inner sep=0mm,fill=\centreblobcolour,opacity=.5,outer sep=0] at (0,0){};
    }{}
    \foreach \x in {\anglemin,\angletwo,...,\anglemax}{%
        \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{colour}%
        \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}}
        \def\r{3*rand+\x}%
        \def\d{1mm*rand+\burstwidth}%
        \def\inangle{90+rand*30}
        \draw [draw=\c] (burstpoint) to  [out=\r,in=\inangle] (\r:\d) {} node [coordinate, inner sep=0, outer sep =0] (end\x){};        
        \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{end\x}{center}}\pgftransformscale{0.3}}
        \begin{scope}[transparency group]
            \foreach \y in {\bursttwoanglemin,\bursttwoangletwo,...,\bursttwoanglemax}{
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\bursttwo}{true}}{
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{\smoke}{true}}{
                        \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{end\x}{center}}\pgftransformscale{0.3}};\fill[\smokecolour,opacity=.4] ($(end\x)+(-\burstwidth,-\burstwidth)$) rectangle ($(end\x)+(\burstwidth,\burstwidth)$);%shading
                    }{}
                    \draw [draw=\c,projectiletwo,line width=0.5pt]  ($(end\x.center)$) -- ($(end\x.center)+(\y :\bursttwowidthrandom*rand+\bursttwowidth)$);

                }{}
            }
        \end{scope}

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\endblob}{true}}{
            \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{end\x}{center}}\pgftransformscale{\endblobwidth/2cm}}
            \node [circle,minimum width=\endblobwidth, minimum height=\endblobwidth, inner sep=0mm,fill=\endblobcolour,opacity=1,outer sep=0] at (end\x){};
        }{}
    }
}
%roman candle
\def\candle{
    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{colour}{{\basecolour}{\basecolour!90!white}{\basecolour!80!white}{\basecolour!80!green}{\basecolour!80!red}{\basecolour!80!blue}}
    \pgfsetfading{fadein}{\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-3cm}}}
    \node [coordinate] at(0,0)(basepoint){};
    \node [coordinate]at(0,0.5*\candleheight) (smokepoint){};
    \foreach \x in {\candleanglemin,\candleangletwo,...,\candleanglemax}{%
        \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{colour}
        \def\r{rand*\candleheightrandom+\candleheight}
        \def\xx{5*rnd+\x}
        \node[coordinate] at ($(0,0)+(\xx:\r)$) (endpoint){};
        \draw[draw=\c,line width=0.5] (0,0) to [out=\x,in=90] (endpoint);%
    }
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\smoke}{true}}{
        \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgftransformrotate{\candleanglemax-90}\pgftransformxscale{0.3}\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{smokepoint}{center}}};
        \fill[\smokecolour] [draw=none, line width=0.5,smooth cycle] (0,0) to (\candleanglemax+10:\candleheight*2) to ($(\candleanglemin/2+\candleanglemax/2,\candleheight*2)$) to (\candleanglemin-7:\candleheight*2) to (0,0);
    }{}
}
%cloud
\def\cloud{
    \pgfgettransform{\mycurrenttransform}
    \node[coordinate] at(0,0)(cloudpoint){};
    \pgfsetfading{fadeit}{\pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}\pgftransformscale{0.5}\pgftransformyscale{0.3}}
    \node[cloud, cloud puffs=10, cloud puff arc=60,cloud ignores aspect, minimum width=\cloudwidth, minimum height=\cloudheight, align=center, draw=none, fill=\cloudcolour, fill opacity=.4] (cloud) at (cloudpoint) {};
}
%flame
\def\flame{
    \pgfgettransform{\mycurrenttransform}
    \pgfsetfading{fadeflame}{\pgfsettransform{\mycurrenttransform}\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0}{-4.5}}\pgftransformxscale{0.05}\pgftransformyscale{0.08}}%
    \path(0,0) pic{flame};
}
%based on raindrop@  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195642/28808
    \tikzset{%
  flame/.pic={
    code={\tikzset{scale=1/10}
 \clip [preaction={top color=red!80, bottom color=red!40!yellow}]
 (0,0)  .. controls ++(0,-1) and ++(0,1) .. (1,-2)
 arc (360:180:1)
 .. controls ++(0,1) and ++(0,-1) .. (0,0) -- cycle ;
 \foreach \j in {1,3,...,20}
 \shade [top color=red, shift=(270:0), xscale=1-\j/40,yscale=1-\j/80, red!50!yellow, opacity=1/8]
 [rotate=-\j] (0,0)  .. controls ++(0,-1) and ++(0,1) .. (1,-2)
 arc (360:180:1)
 .. controls ++(0,1) and ++(0,-1) .. (0,0) -- cycle;
  }}}
%rocket trail
\pgfdeclaredecoration{irregular fractal line}{init}
{
  \state{init}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance]
  {
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{random*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{(random*\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-0.02)*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}}{.5pt}\pgfusepath{fill};
  }
}
\tikzset{
   trail/.style={decoration={irregular fractal line, amplitude=0.2},
           decorate}
}


\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[projectile/.style={decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=0.5pt}}, projectiletwo/.style={decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=0.2pt}}]
\fill[black] (-6,-5) rectangle (9,8);
\clip (-6,-5) rectangle (9,8);
%rockets with trails of sparks
\def\trailcolour{white}
\def\launchangle{80}
\begin{scope}
    \pgfsetfading{fadetrail}{\pgftransformscale{5}}
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\trailcolour}
    \draw [draw=\trailcolour] {decorate[trail]{decorate[decoration={random steps, segment length=2pt, amplitude=1pt}]{
        (-3cm,-2.6cm) to [out=\launchangle+rand*5, in=300+rand*15] (-3cm,5cm)
     }}};
    \draw [draw=\trailcolour] {decorate[trail]{decorate[decoration={random steps, segment length=2pt, amplitude=1pt}]{
        (5cm,-2.6cm) to [out=\launchangle+rand*5, in=300+rand*15] (5cm,5cm)
     }}};
     \draw [draw=\trailcolour] {decorate[trail]{decorate[decoration={random steps, segment length=2pt, amplitude=1pt}]{
        (1cm,-2.6cm) to [out=\launchangle+rand*5, in=300+rand*15] (1cm,6cm)
     }}};
\end{scope}
\def\basecolour{red}
\def\secondcolour{red!50!yellow}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{true}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\bursttwowidth{2mm}
\def\bursttwowidthrandom{1.5mm}
\def\smokecolour{gray}
\def\burstwidth{1.7cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\endblob{false}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{red}
\def\centreblob{false}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.75cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{yellow}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1cm, yshift=6cm]
    \burst
    \def\anglemin{5}
    \def\angletwo{15}
    \def\anglemax{359}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \def\centreblob{true}
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\basecolour{magenta}
\def\secondcolour{red!40!white}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{false}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\bursttwowidth{2mm}
\def\bursttwowidthrandom{1.5mm}
\def\smokecolour{gray!50!magenta}
\def\burstwidth{1.7cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\endblob{true}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{magenta}
\def\centreblob{false}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.75cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{magenta!50!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-3cm, yshift=5cm]
    \burst
    \def\anglemin{5}
    \def\angletwo{15}
    \def\anglemax{359}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \def\centreblob{true}
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\basecolour{blue}
\def\secondcolour{cyan}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{false}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\bursttwowidth{2mm}
\def\bursttwowidthrandom{1.5mm}
\def\smokecolour{gray!50!blue}
\def\burstwidth{1.7cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\endblob{true}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{cyan}
\def\centreblob{false}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.75cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{blue!50!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm, yshift=5cm]
    \burst
    \def\anglemin{5}
    \def\angletwo{15}
    \def\anglemax{359}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \def\centreblob{true}
    \burst
\end{scope}
%roman candles. Up to 5 candles/colour at 2 positions
%reflections in water: 4 per colour
%red
\tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5}}
\tikzset{romansmokestyle/.style={draw=none}}
\def\basecolour{red}
\def\candleanglemin{80}
\def\candleangletwo{82}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\def\candleheightrandom{5mm}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\smokecolour{red}
\def\cloudwidth{1.5cm}
\def\cloudheight{0.6cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2.1cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.5]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\basecolour{yellow}
\def\candleanglemin{86}
\def\candleangletwo{88}
\def\candleanglemax{96}
\def\candleheight{1.5cm}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\cloudwidth{1.5cm}
\def\cloudheight{0.6cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2.1cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.3]
    \candle
\end{scope}
%reflection
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2.1cm, yshift=-3.8cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{red}
    \def\candleanglemin{280}
    \def\candleangletwo{278}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.3, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{yellow}
    \def\candleanglemin{274}
    \def\candleangletwo{276}
    \def\candleanglemax{264}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
\def\basecolour{red}
\def\candleanglemin{80}
\def\candleangletwo{82}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\def\smoke{true}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\basecolour{yellow}
\def\candleanglemin{86}
\def\candleangletwo{88}
\def\candleanglemax{96}
\def\candleheight{1.5cm}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\cloudwidth{1.5cm}
\def\cloudheight{0.6cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-3cm,opacity=0.5]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\def\basecolour{yellow!50!white}
\def\candleanglemin{88}
\def\candleangletwo{90}
\def\candleanglemax{94}
\def\candleheight{1.2cm}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\cloudwidth{1.2cm}
\def\cloudheight{0.6cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-3cm,opacity=0.9]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm, yshift=-3.6cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{red}
    \def\candleanglemin{280}
    \def\candleangletwo{278}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.3, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{yellow}
    \def\candleanglemin{274}
    \def\candleangletwo{276}
    \def\candleanglemax{264}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
%green
\def\candleanglemin{88}
\def\candleangletwo{89}
\def\candleanglemax{105}
\def\basecolour{green!70!white}
\def\smokecolour{green!50!black}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\def\smoke{true}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-.1cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.5]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{green!20!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-.1cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.3]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-.1cm, yshift=-3.8cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{green}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.3, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{green!20!white}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\candleanglemin{88}
\def\candleangletwo{89}
\def\candleanglemax{105}
\def\basecolour{green!70!white}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{green!20!white}
\def\candleheight{1.5cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm, yshift=-3.6cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{green}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{green!20!white}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.15, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
%pink
\def\candleanglemin{88}
\def\candleangletwo{89}
\def\candleanglemax{105}
\def\basecolour{magenta!70!white}
\def\smokecolour{magenta!50!black}
\def\secondcolour{red!50!white}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\def\smoke{true}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.9cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.5]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{magenta!20!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.9cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.3]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.9cm, yshift=-3.8cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{magenta}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{magenta!70!white}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.15, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\candleanglemin{80}
\def\candleangletwo{81}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{magenta!70!white}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{magenta!20!white}
\def\candleheight{1.5cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm, yshift=-3.6cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{magenta}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{magenta!70!white}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.15, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
%blue
\def\secondcolour{cyan}
\def\candleanglemin{82}
\def\candleangletwo{83}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{blue!70!cyan}
\def\smokecolour{blue!50!black}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\def\smoke{true}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.9cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.5]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{blue!20!cyan}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.9cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.3]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.9cm, yshift=-3.8cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{blue}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{blue!20!cyan}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.15, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\candleanglemin{88}
\def\candleangletwo{89}
\def\candleanglemax{105}
\def\basecolour{blue!70!cyan}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{blue!20!cyan}
\def\candleheight{1.5cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm, yshift=-3.6cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{blue}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{blue!20!cyan}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.15, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
%yellow
\def\candleanglemin{82}
\def\candleangletwo{83}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{yellow}
\def\secondcolour{red}
\def\smokecolour{yellow!80!red}
\def\cloudcolour{yellow!80!red}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\def\smoke{true}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5.9cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.5]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{100}
\def\basecolour{yellow!80!red!20!white}
\def\cloudcolour{yellow!80!red}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5.9cm,yshift=-2.8cm,opacity=0.3]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5.9cm, yshift=-3.8cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{yellow}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{yellow!80!red}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.15, decoration={snake,amplitude=.1mm+rand*0.05mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\candleanglemin{88}
\def\candleangletwo{89}
\def\candleanglemax{105}
\def\basecolour{yellow!80!red}
\def\candleheight{2cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
    \flame
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{false}
\def\candleanglemin{92}
\def\candleangletwo{94}
\def\candleanglemax{98}
\def\basecolour{yellow!80!red!20!white}
\def\candleheight{1.5cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-3cm]
    \candle
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=-3.6cm]
    \def\candleheight{2cm}
    \def\candleheightrandom{0cm}
    \def\basecolour{yellow}
    \def\candleanglemin{272}
    \def\candleangletwo{271}
    \def\candleanglemax{255}
    \def\smoke{false}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.2, decoration={snake,amplitude=.3mm+rand*0.1mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
    \def\basecolour{yellow!80!red}
    \def\candleanglemin{268}
    \def\candleangletwo{266}
    \def\candleanglemax{260}
    \tikzset{romanstyle/.style={line width=0.5,decorate,opacity=0.15, decoration={snake,amplitude=.3mm+rand*0.1mm,segment length=2mm+rand*0.5mm}}}
    \candle
\end{scope}
%mortar bursts 3/colour
%red
\def\basecolour{red!80!yellow}
\def\secondcolour{yellow!80!white}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{false}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\smokecolour{red}
\def\burstwidth{1.2cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\endblob{false}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{red}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{yellow}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2cm, yshift=1cm,opacity=0.6]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.8cm,yshift=1.2cm,opacity=0.3]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\smokecolour{red}
\def\burstwidth{1.3cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{yellow}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2.3cm, yshift=1.3cm]
    \burst
\end{scope}
%green
\def\basecolour{green}
\def\secondcolour{cyan!50!white}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{false}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\smokecolour{green!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.2cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\endblob{false}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{green}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{green!80!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=0, yshift=1cm,opacity=0.6]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=.2cm,yshift=1.2cm,opacity=0.3]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\smokecolour{green!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.3cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{green!80!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-0.3cm, yshift=1.3cm]
    \burst
\end{scope}
%pink
\def\basecolour{magenta}
\def\secondcolour{magenta!20!white}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{false}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\smokecolour{magenta!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.2cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\endblob{false}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{magenta}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{magenta!80!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2cm, yshift=1cm,opacity=0.6]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\burstwidth{1cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2.2cm,yshift=1.2cm,opacity=0.3]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\smokecolour{magenta!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.3cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{magenta!80!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=1.7cm, yshift=0.9cm]
    \burst
\end{scope}
%blue
\def\basecolour{blue}
\def\secondcolour{cyan!80!white}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{false}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\smokecolour{blue!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.2cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\endblob{false}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{blue!80!cyan}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{blue!20!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm, yshift=1cm,opacity=0.6]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\burstwidth{1cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4.2cm,yshift=1.4cm,opacity=0.3]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\smokecolour{blue!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.3cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{blue!80!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=3.8cm, yshift=0.9cm]
    \burst
\end{scope}
%yellow
\def\basecolour{yellow!80!red}
\def\secondcolour{yellow!50!red}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\bursttwo{false}
\def\bursttwoanglemin{0}
\def\bursttwoangletwo{60}
\def\bursttwoanglemax{359}
\def\smokecolour{yellow!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.2cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\endblob{false}
\def\endblobwidth{2mm}
\def\endblobcolour{yellow}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{yellow!80!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, yshift=1.3cm,opacity=0.6]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\burstwidth{1.5cm}
\begin{scope}[xshift=6.1cm,yshift=1.2cm,opacity=0.3]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\smoke{true}
\def\smokecolour{yellow!80!black}
\def\burstwidth{1.3cm}
\def\anglemin{0}
\def\anglemax{359}
\def\angletwo{10}
\def\centreblob{true}
\def\centreblobwidth{0.5cm}
\def\centreblobcolour{yellow!80!white}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5.7cm, yshift=0.9cm]
    \burst
\end{scope}
\def\cloudcolour{red}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-3.3cm, yshift=-1cm]
    \cloud
\end{scope}
\def\cloudcolour{green}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-1.4cm, yshift=-1.2cm]
    \cloud
\end{scope}
\def\cloudcolour{magenta}
\begin{scope}[xshift=.75cm, yshift=-.9cm]
    \cloud
\end{scope}
\def\cloudcolour{blue}
\begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm, yshift=-1cm]
    \cloud
\end{scope}
\def\cloudcolour{yellow}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4.9cm, yshift=-1.1cm]
    \cloud
\end{scope}
\fill[black, opacity=0.6] (-6,-5) rectangle (9,-3.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The only viewers I can persuade this to render in are Evince 3.14/3.18 for Linux, GIMP 2.8 and Gnome print previewer (probably the same code as Evince).  SumatraPDF, Adobe reader X, Inkscape and Evince 2 for windows give the general idea at best but fail to varying extents.  Ghostscript and ImageMagick show one rocket trail, then cry and give up. In fact there's a bug even in this: the reflections in the water should be wavy.

Comment: Although the bounty drew my attention to the question, even if my result deserved it (which I don't believe it does) all the hard work was doen by @percusse.  I just treated it as a chance to learn a bit more TikZ .

Comment: Great! Perhaps some "glow" could be added and having opacity letting things sum up to compensate the fading.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz any form of opacity gradient appears to be the issue withinconsistent handling.  As percusse found years ago, sumatraPDF has the best rendering.  I'll have a look at some glow tonight

Comment: Interestingly evince for linux works just fine.  And compiling this on a chromebook is more than a little slow.

Comment: The final code will appear -- but I'm still working on it

Comment: Thank you for your very nice work! I look forward to your final code. :-) I also like that you provide your code with a public domain license, instead of the default commercial site backlink requiring CC license on top of author attribution that goes without saying.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz my views on code sharing were formed back in the days of usenet when no-one bothered with licensing and just shared freely.  I've learnt a lot from other people sharing code (not least here).  The only thing stopping me from sharing more is the lack of QA/comments/general polish.

Comment: Bounty well deserved. No worries :-)

Comment: This has to be the final version.  Compilation times are back under a minute (since removing a lot of random path decorations), but Evince on a decent desktop takes ~2 minutes to render.  I mainly did this on my commute on a Chromebook (ARM CPU) - LaTeX runs fine on that but the last time I compiled, Evince took >10 minutes to display it.

Comment: I still hope to do some tidying up/commenting on the code.  Eventually I'd like to make it a lot easier to use but as you'll see if you brave the source, I took the chance to experiment with tikz features and syntax. This is also the 1st time I've hit the character limit on an answer - the code is also [on github](https://github.com/ChrisHodgesUK/Tikz-Fireworks) which I'll update when I get round to adding comments

Comment: Coming back to this, Sumatra doesn't work too well on Windows any more -- out of 7 programs that can open pdfs on this machine, only GIMP can display it properly.  Most others give up part way through.

Answer (score 15):

Using my answer here, [Make fireworks with only text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219349/make-fireworks-with-only-text/219362#219362), except with `-`, `\_`, `{$\bullet$}` and `.` as the firework components, instead of actual text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating, xcolor}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{Kdegrees}
\newcounter{KdegreeIncrement}
\newcounter{degrees}

% More than 360 repetitions will max out TeX's memory
% Print error message and end document if more than 360 reps are requested
\newcommand{\textwheelErrorTest}[1]{%
    \ifnum#1 > 360 
        \typeout{%
            ERROR: You asked for #1 repetitions in 
            \noexpand\textwheel, but the maximum is 360.
            I am stopping before TeX exceeds its memory capacity.%
        }%
        \def\erroraction{\end{document}}
    \else
        \def\erroraction{\relax}
    \fi
    \erroraction
}

% For calculating length of string for kerning
\newlength{\strlen}
\newlength\biaslength
\def\biasfrac{.0}% 0 to 1
\biaslength=0pt% \ge 0pt (0pt produces circular symmetry
\def\biasstrut{\rule[-\biasfrac\biaslength]{0pt}{\biaslength}}
% #1 text to repeat, #2 color of text, #3 number of times to repeat it
\newcommand{\textwheel}[5]{\leavevmode\smash{%
    \gdef\innercolor{#2}%
    \gdef\outercolor{#3}%
    \textwheelErrorTest{#4}%
    \def\FadeL{#5}%
    %
    \setcounter{KdegreeIncrement}{360000}%
    \setcounter{Kdegrees}{0}%
    \divide\value{KdegreeIncrement} by #4%
    \settowidth{\strlen}{#1}%
    \ifdim\FadeL=0pt\def\FadeL{\the\strlen}\fi%
    %
    \loop
      \setcounter{degrees}{\value{Kdegrees}}%
      \divide\value{degrees} by 1000\relax%
      \ifnum\value{degrees}<90
        \rlap{\rotatebox[origin=l]{\value{degrees}}{%
         \biasstrut\color{#2}\smash{\FadeAfter{\FadeL}{#1}}}%
        }%
      \else
        \ifnum\value{degrees}<270%
          \kern+\biaslength%
          \llap{\rotatebox[origin=l]{\value{degrees}}{%
           \biasstrut\color{#2}\smash{\FadeAfter{\FadeL}{#1}}}%
          }%
          \kern-\biaslength%
        \else
          \rlap{\rotatebox[origin=l]{\value{degrees}}{%
           \biasstrut\color{#2}\smash{\FadeAfter{\FadeL}{#1}}}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
    \addtocounter{Kdegrees}{\value{KdegreeIncrement}}%
    \ifnum\value{Kdegrees} < 359000%
    \repeat%
}}
%%%
\usepackage{xcolor,ifthen}
\newcounter{tmpcounter}
\newlength\cumlength
\newlength\critlength
\newlength\tmplength
\newcount\mynum
\newcount\myden
\makeatletter
\newcommand\FadeAfter[2]{%
  \critlength=#1\relax\cumlength=0pt\relax%
  \def\cumstring{}\fahelp{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\fahelp[2]{\prefahelper#2 \relax\fahelper#2\relax}
\def\prefahelper#1 #2\relax{\gdef\wordremaining{#1}}
\def\fahelper#1#2\relax{%
  \global\protected@edef\cumstring{\cumstring#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\wordremaining}}{%
    \global\protected@edef\cumstring{\cumstring\ }}{}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\cumstring}%
  \tmplength=.01\critlength\relax%
  \mynum=\wd0\relax%
  \myden=\tmplength\relax%
  \divide\mynum by\myden%
  \setcounter{tmpcounter}{\numexpr100-\the\mynum}%
  \ifnum\thetmpcounter<0\setcounter{tmpcounter}{0}\fi%
  \textcolor{\innercolor!\thetmpcounter!\outercolor!90}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\wordremaining}}{\ }{}%
    \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fahelp{\critlength}{#2}\fi%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
% CAN EXPERIMENT WITH ASYMMETRIC BIAS WITH THESE TWO PARAMETERS
%\def\biasfrac{.4}% 0 to 1 ROTATES THE ASYMMETRY OF \biaslength
%\biaslength=8pt% \ge 0pt (0pt produces circular symmetry)

\pagecolor{black}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
%
\vspace{4cm}

\hspace{3.15cm}
\biaslength1pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\XT{\textwheel{..}{blue}{cyan}{4}{0.4cm}}
\biaslength0pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\ST{\textwheel{\_\_\_\_\_\XT}{yellow!60!orange}{green!60!orange}{13}{0.6cm}}
\biaslength6pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\textwheel{{$\bullet$}--------------------------------------------\ST}{red}{blue}{17}{7cm}

\vspace{3cm}

\hspace{0cm}
\biaslength1pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\XT{\textwheel{...}{blue!50!red}{cyan}{3}{0.6cm}}
\biaslength0pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\ST{\textwheel{\_\_\_\_\XT}{yellow!60!orange}{red}{11}{0.6cm}}
\biaslength6pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\textwheel{{$\bullet$}-------------------------------\ST}{yellow}{blue}{13}{5cm}


\vspace{10cm}

\hspace{9cm}
\biaslength1pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\XT{\textwheel{..}{blue}{cyan}{4}{0.4cm}}
\biaslength0pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\ST{\textwheel{\_\_\_\XT}{yellow!60!orange}{green!60!orange}{13}{0.6cm}}
\biaslength6pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\textwheel{{$\bullet$}-----------------------------------\ST}{red}{blue}{23}{7cm}

\vspace{-11pt}\hspace{9cm}
\biaslength1pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\XT{\textwheel{..}{blue}{cyan}{3}{0.4cm}}
\biaslength0pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\ST{\textwheel{\_\_\_\_\XT}{yellow!60!orange}{green!60!orange}{11}{0.6cm}}
\biaslength6pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\textwheel{{$\bullet$}------------------------\ST}{red}{blue}{17}{5cm}

\vspace{-11pt}\hspace{9cm}
\biaslength1pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\XT{\textwheel{..}{blue}{cyan}{3}{0.4cm}}
\biaslength0pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\savestack\ST{\textwheel{\_\_\_\_\_\XT}{yellow!60!orange}{green!60!orange}{11}{0.6cm}}
\biaslength6pt\def\biasfrac{-.1}
\textwheel{{$\bullet$}------------\ST}{red}{blue}{7}{3cm}


\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second set of fireworks are laid concentrically, to give a slightly different effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that nice alternative solution! I enjoy it, even though I gave the bounty to a TikZ solution. Nice work with `stackengine`, I also used that package to show a solution in my LaTeX cookbook.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Thanks for your kind words.  It is a fun problem.

Answer (score 11):

Math symbol fireworks (edit: I've added a random positioning):

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: convert: {density: 160, otheroptions: -dispose previous -delay 10 -loop 10, format: gif}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{.05em}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes}
% customized decorations
\newcommand{\decorazione}[4]{% 
    \pgfdeclaredecoration{#1}{initial}{%
        \state{initial}[width=30pt]
        {\pgfnode{circle}{center}{\Huge\textcolor{#2}{\contour{#3}{#4}}}{}{}}
        \state{final}[width=30pt]
        {\pgfnode{circle}{center}{\Huge\textcolor{#2}{\contour{#3}{#4}}}{}{}}
}}
\decorazione{sommatoria}{red}{yellow}{$\sum$}
\decorazione{minore}{white}{red}{$\le$}
\decorazione{integrale}{green}{white}{$\int$}
\decorazione{unione}{yellow}{green}{$\bigcap$}
\decorazione{stella}{red}{yellow}{$\star$}
\decorazione{radice}{white}{red}{$\sqrt{}$}
\decorazione{produttoria}{green}{white}{$\prod{}$}
\decorazione{frecciacirc}{yellow}{green}{$\circlearrowleft$}
\decorazione{perogni}{red}{yellow}{$\forall$}
\decorazione{esiste}{white}{red}{$\exists$}
\decorazione{triangolo}{green}{white}{$\triangleleft$}
\decorazione{freccia}{yellow}{green}{$\Rightarrow$}

\newcommand{\cerchio}[2]{\path[decorate, decoration=#1,inner sep=0,font={\bfseries\Huge}] (#1) circle (#2)}

\begin{document}
    % tikzpicture out of the loop to set coordinates
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (30,20);
    \foreach \tema in {sommatoria, minore, integrale, unione,%
        stella, radice}{%
        \path (rnd*20+5,rnd*10+5) coordinate (\tema);
        \cerchio{\tema}{.5};    
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % main loop 
    \foreach \raggio in {1,1.5,...,4}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (30,20);
        \foreach \tema in {sommatoria, minore, integrale, unione,%
            stella, radice}{%
            \cerchio{\tema}{\raggio};   
        }   
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    % tikzpicture out of the loop to set coordinates
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (30,20);
    \foreach \tema in {produttoria, frecciacirc,%
        perogni, esiste, triangolo, freccia}{%
        \path (rnd*20+5,rnd*10+5) coordinate (\tema);
        \cerchio{\tema}{.5};    
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % main loop 
    \foreach \raggio in {1,1.5,...,4}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle (30,20);
        \foreach \tema in {produttoria, frecciacirc,%
            perogni, esiste, triangolo, freccia}{%
            \cerchio{\tema}{\raggio};   
        }   
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

In order to get the `.gif` file use this ImageMagick command:

```
convert -alpha remove -density 160 -dispose previous -delay 10 -loop 10 "file.pdf" -quality 100 "file.gif"
```

or an `arara` rule like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339227/101651).

Comment: Cool! Let us have formulas explode. :-)

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I was thinking of how to do LaTeX-related fireworks... and this is the result!

Comment: I preferred the more graphical solution, but thank you very much for that great idea!

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Don't worry, I'll do something TeXnically more sophisticated when I'm more experienced. Maybe you can answer my duck question, instead! Hahaha!