# Can I have a glow around a box in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

What I was wondering is, if I can have a glow effect for a box I am drawing with TikZ. Neither search here nor the (excellent) TikZ manual returned any results. There is a circular glow option, but I don't think that helps in my case, or does it!?

Any input is appreciated :).

**Edit**: I figured that these blurred shadows seem to be a fairly special PDF feature which is supported by few PDF viewers only (actually Acrobat Reader 9 for Linux was the only one that worked for me).

[image: Acrobat Reader] [image: Evince] [image: pdf.js]
(size of the blue box is the same)

Comment: I think the `circular glow` is exactly what you want. It's just a matter of defining the correct color for it. Perhaps you would need to apply some fading, but otherwise it seems good.

Comment: I see some glows in [How can we display fireworks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39485/5764)

Comment: @Werner: Yes, but they are all circular glows. This question is about having a glow around a box [rectangle].

Comment: This is seemingly only possible if you know PostScript coding (which I don't) then you can use `\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading`. I tried a little but I can't modify the colors (e.g. stuck at yellow).

Comment: Don;t be fooled by the name `circular glow`. It works just as well on a rectangle: `\tikz\node[circular glow={fill=red}, fill=blue] {x};` works fine.

Comment: @wh1t3: I can't confirm that :(. The shadow is circular for me with your example compiled with pdflatex and shown using Acrobat Reader for Linux.

Comment: @Johannes: I just tried it at home and I get a circular shadow there as well. At work it was rectangular though... Let me see if I can figure out the difference on Monday.

Comment: @Johannes: I just tested it, you are correct. It was the reader I use at work that was fooling me, in acrobat it shows circular indeed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This MWE is probably closer to your question:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\shadowradius{3pt}
%
\newcommand\drawshadowbis[1]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
        \fill[inner color=red,outer color=red!10!white] ($(#1.south west)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[inner color=red,outer color=red!10!white] ($(#1.north west)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[inner color=red,outer color=red!10!white] ($(#1.south east)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[inner color=red,outer color=red!10!white] ($(#1.north east)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[ top color=red, bottom color=red!10!white] ($(#1.south west)+((0,-\shadowradius)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)$);
        \fill[left color=red,right color=red!10!white] ($(#1.south east)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+((\shadowradius,0)$);
        \fill[bottom color=red,top color=red!10!white] ($(#1.north west)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+((0,\shadowradius)$);
        \fill[right color=red,left color=red!10!white] ($(#1.south west)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(-\shadowradius,0)$);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
%
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [fill=blue,rectangle,rounded corners=0pt,draw=blue, ultra thick, text=white] (box) {Test!!!};
   \drawshadowbis{box}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

By modifying the Caramdir's code in this thread: [Faded drop-shadow using tikz-based rounded rectangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/faded-drop-shadow-using-tikz-based-rounded-rectangle), I got this:

[image]

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\shadowradius{3pt}
%
\newcommand\drawshadowbis[1]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
        \fill[inner color=blue,outer color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.south west)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[inner color=blue,outer color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.north west)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[inner color=blue,outer color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.south east)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[inner color=blue,outer color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.north east)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \fill[ top color=blue, bottom color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.south west)+((0,-\shadowradius)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)$);
        \fill[left color=blue,right color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.south east)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+((\shadowradius,0)$);
        \fill[bottom color=blue,top color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.north west)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+((0,\shadowradius)$);
        \fill[right color=blue,left color=blue!10!black] ($(#1.south west)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(-\shadowradius,0)$);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}
%
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [fill=blue,rectangle,rounded corners=0pt,draw=blue, ultra thick, text=white] (box) {Test!!!};
   \drawshadowbis{box}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```