# Rotate fading in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

In `tikz` I want to draw a narrow long rectangle which is faded at the top and at the bottom. This is supposed to represent a laser beam.

I define a `tikz` fading and it works fine as long as the beam is horizontal. When I rotate the rectangle the fading does not produce the beam as before.  I tried to use the fading transform option to also rotate the fading beam but it did not work.  Since I want to draw several beam with different rotations in one picture I thought I should avoid a canvas transform.

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzfading[name=middle,
            top color=transparent!100,
            bottom color=transparent!100,
            middle color=transparent!20]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[path fading=middle, red] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.2);
\fill[rotate=-20, path fading=middle, red] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.2);
\fill[rotate=20, path fading=middle, fading transform={rotate=20}, red] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.2);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I get the correct fading for the rotated beams?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Related question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59524/how-can-i-slant-the-rectangular-glow-box-with-lighting-effect-in-tikz

Comment: Your question inspired me to ask for a more generalized solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80171/faded-or-blurred-lines and got a nice answer from @PaulGaborit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply a canvas transformation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzfading[name=middle,
            top color=transparent!100,
            bottom color=transparent!100,
            middle color=transparent!20]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[path fading=middle, red] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.2);
\foreach \angle in {20,40,...,340}
  \fill[transform canvas={rotate=-\angle},path fading=middle, red] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Paul Gaborit** mentions in a comment, a canvas transformation requires great care; the following quote is taken from the `pgf` manual:

> Just as important, when you use canvas transformations `pgf` looses
>   track of positions of nodes and of picture sizes since it does not
>   take the effect of canvas transformations into account when it
>   computes coordinates of nodes (you not, however, rely on this; it may
>   change in the future).

Comment: Note: with `canvas transform`, you lose the automatic calculation of the bounding box.

Comment: @PaulGaborit yes; I have included a note about this in my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The fading effect is applied to the bounding box of your path. With simple `rotate`, the bounding box is always aligned to the original canvas.
With a `canvas transform`, you rotate your path *and* the canvas but you lose the automatic calculation of the bounding box. So you must use two operations:

1. a simple `rotate` to use your path without drawing to update the bounding box.
2. a `canvas transform` rotation to draw your path with rotated fading.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzfading[name=middle,
            top color=transparent!100,
            bottom color=transparent!100,
            middle color=transparent!20]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[path fading=middle, red] (0,0) rectangle (4,0.2);

% update bounding box
\begin{scope}[rotate=45]
  \path (0,-2) rectangle ++(4,.2);
\end{scope}
% draw with (canvas) rotated fading
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=45}]
  \fill[path fading=middle,orange] (0,-2) rectangle ++(4,.2);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```