# TikZ: Drawing a cylinder with a hole the bottom

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I am trying to draw something like this cylinder: [image: cylinder with water flowing out through a hole]. Here is my attempt:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{snakes,shapes,decorations.text}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
   %\draw (-4,-4) grid (4,4);

   \draw (0,0) node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=1.4,
    minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2.5cm,
    shape border rotate=90,
    cylinder uses custom fill,
    cylinder body fill=blue!30,
    cylinder end  fill=blue!10, opacity=.4,anchor=north]
   (A) {};

    \draw [dashed] (1.23,-2.87) arc[x radius=1.24, y radius=1/3, start angle=0, end angle=180];

    \draw [dashed] (0,-2.8) ellipse[x radius=0.3, y radius=1/12, start angle=0, end angle=180];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

which produces[image: this]. 
  The arc drawn along the bottom doesn't exactly match the top of the cylinder, and neither does the dashed ellipse in the middle. How can I match this better? How would I be able to add the effect of fluid flowing out of the hole?

[image]

Comment: By specifying the height and width, aspect is used instead to modify the default short radius. So in this case the y radius should be 1.4(.125cm) where .125cm was the default used in all my test runs.

Comment: Very refreshing to see someone who has actually tried to draw the thing! Well done, nice question, and we should refer other users to this :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the predefined `cylinder` shape, I 'd just use arcs and an army of [Mark Wibrow's droplets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195642/3954) for the water:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4pt]{standalone}

\pgfdeclareradialshading[droplet color]{droplet}{\pgfqpoint{-10bp}{-10bp}}{%
 color(0bp)=(droplet color!50!white);
 color(9bp)=(droplet color!75!white);
 color(18bp)=(droplet color!85!black);
 color(25bp)=(droplet color);
 color(50bp)=(droplet color!50!white)}

\colorlet{droplet color}{blue!50!cyan!80}
\tikzset{%
  raindrop/.pic={
    code={\tikzset{scale=1/10}
 \shade [shading=droplet]
 (0,0)  .. controls ++(0,-1) and ++(0,1) .. (1,-2)
 arc (360:180:1)
 .. controls ++(0,1) and ++(0,-1) .. (0,0) -- cycle;
  }}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
\begin{scope}[yshift=-6pt]
\foreach \Coord in {{(2,0)},{(2.3,-0.25)},{(2.2,-0.3)},{(2.2,-0.4)}%,
  ,{(1.8,0)},{(1.7,-0.25)},{(2,-0.3)},{(1.8,-0.4)}%
  ,{(1.7,-0.2)},{(1.9,-0.5)},{(2,-0.4)},{(1.9,-0.3)}%
  ,{(2.3,-0.2)},{(2.1,-0.5)},{(2,-0.3)},{(2.1,-0.3)}%
  ,{(2.3,-0.1)},{(2.1,-0.2)},{(2,-0.15)},{(2.1,-0.05)}%
  ,{(1.7,-0.1)},{(1.9,-0.25)},{(2,-0.1)},{(1.9,-0.15)}%
  } 
  \path \Coord pic {raindrop};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=4pt]
\foreach \Coord in {{(2,0)},{(2.3,-0.25)},{(2.2,-0.3)},{(2.2,-0.4)}%,
  ,{(1.8,0)},{(1.7,-0.25)},{(2,-0.3)},{(1.8,-0.4)}%
  ,{(1.7,-0.2)},{(1.9,-0.5)},{(2,-0.4)},{(1.9,-0.3)}%
  ,{(2.3,-0.2)},{(2.1,-0.5)},{(2,-0.3)},{(2.1,-0.3)}%
  ,{(2.3,-0.1)},{(2.1,-0.2)},{(2,-0.15)},{(2.1,-0.05)}%
  ,{(1.7,-0.1)},{(1.9,-0.25)},{(2,-0.1)},{(1.9,-0.15)}%
  ,{(2.2,0)},{(1.7,-0.1)},{(2,0)},{(1.9,-0.1)}%
  } 
  \path \Coord pic {raindrop};
\end{scope}
\filldraw[draw=black,ultra thick,fill=droplet color!20]
 (0,3) arc[x radius=2, y radius=0.4, start angle=180, end angle=0]
 (4,3) arc[x radius=2, y radius=0.4, start angle=0, end angle=-180];
\filldraw[ultra thick,fill=droplet color!70,opacity=1,fill opacity=0.7]
  (0,3) -- 
  (0,0) 
  arc[x radius=2, y radius=0.4, start angle=-180, end angle=0] --
   (4,3)
  arc[x radius=2, y radius=0.4, start angle=0, end angle=-180];
\draw[dashed] 
  (0,0) arc[x radius=2, y radius=0.4, start angle=180, end angle=0]
  (1.5,0) arc[x radius=0.5, y radius=0.12, start angle=180, end angle=0]
  (1.5,0) arc[x radius=0.5, y radius=0.12, start angle=-180, end angle=0];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry that my own drawing was very unclear, but I am trying to draw a cylinder. I like the way your tikZ image looks and I will play with this code. Thank you.

Comment: @julesjanker You're welcome. No problem. I added a version with a cylinder.

Answer (score 2):

When you specify the width and height, the default value for the (in this case) y radius appears to be a constant 0.125cm.  This is then scaled by the aspect parameter.

[image: cylinder aspect]

```
    \documentclass[border=.1in]{standalone}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{snakes,shapes,decorations.text}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
   %\draw (-4,-4) grid (4,4);

   \draw (0,0) node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=1.4,
    minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2.5cm,
    shape border rotate=90,
    cylinder uses custom fill,
    cylinder body fill=blue!30,
    cylinder end  fill=blue!10, opacity=.4,anchor=north]
   (A) {};

    \draw [dashed] (1.25,-2.825) arc[x radius=1.25, y radius=.175, start angle=0, end angle=180];

    \draw [dashed] (0,-2.825) ellipse[x radius=0.3, y radius=.042, start angle=0, end angle=180];

    %demo
    \draw (4,0) node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,aspect=1,
    minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2.5cm,
    shape border rotate=90,
    cylinder uses custom fill,
    cylinder body fill=blue!30,
    cylinder end  fill=blue!10, opacity=.4,anchor=north]
   {};
  \draw (4,0) node[cylinder,draw=black,thick,
    minimum height=1cm,minimum width=1cm,
    shape border rotate=90,
    cylinder uses custom fill,
    cylinder body fill=blue!30,
    cylinder end  fill=blue!10, opacity=.4,anchor=north]
   {};
  \draw (4,0) node[draw=red,
    minimum height=3cm,minimum width=2.5cm,
    shape border rotate=90,anchor=north]
   {aspect demo};
  \draw[green] (4,0) -- (4,-.25) (2.75,-.125) -- (5.25,-.125);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```