# How to draw a water droplet in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

Hey guys I am working in an infographic and I am trying to do it in LaTeX. In it I want to use the shape of a water droplet to show the water consumption. the final product should be something like this:

[image]

Then I want to draw the water droplet shape to be able to use it like that in a table.

Any ideas?

Comment: A half circle and a tangential 'cone' above it?

Comment: Actually I meant a 'semi-circle' (half circle is German style of English  ;-))

Comment: There is too others drops at this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195639/drawing-water-droplets-with-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses the tangent coordinate system and is actually a modified example from the `pgfmanual`, see on top of page 137 of current `pgfmanual`.

The `\coordinate (a)` statement defines the top of the 'cone' and the tangent system calculates the tangent lines and intersection of the tangent lines from (a) to the circle.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\droplet}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,1.5);% Change 1.5 to change the shape of the droplet
    \node [circle,draw,fill=blue,blue] (c) at (0,0) [minimum size=40pt] {$c$};
    \draw[blue,fill] (a) -- (tangent cs:node=c,point={(a)},solution=1) --
    (c.center) -- (tangent cs:node=c,point={(a)},solution=2) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\droplet\quad\droplet

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for, thanks @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @CamiloRamirez: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!