# Draw pill tablet capsule with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw two icons (pill and capsule), and these icons can repeat and resize.

Minimal working code from *[How to draw a water droplet in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400017/how-to-draw-a-water-droplet-in-latex)*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\droplet}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,1.5);% Change 1.5 to change the shape of the droplet
    \node [circle,draw,fill=blue,blue] (c) at (0,0) [minimum size=40pt] {$c$};
    \draw[blue,fill] (a) -- (tangent cs:node=c,point={(a)},solution=1) --
    (c.center) -- (tangent cs:node=c,point={(a)},solution=2) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\droplet \quad \droplet

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Two icons can be together or alone, and repeat and resize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following has some (hopefully) self-explaining pgfkeys that control their dimensions in order to make it easier to scale them. Do not consume them in combination with alcohol or when maneuvering heavy machinery. ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{00}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-45,tdplot_main_coords,pill radius/.initial=1,
pill length/.initial=3]
 \draw[top color=red!10,bottom color=red!80!black,middle color=red,shading angle=90-45] 
  plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180] 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*cos(\x)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*sin(\x)},0)
  -- plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi] 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*cos(\x)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*sin(\x)},
 {-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill length}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius})+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*sin(\x)}) -- cycle;
 \draw[top color=blue!10,bottom color=blue!80!black,middle color=blue,
 shading angle=90-45] 
  plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180] 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*cos(\x)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*sin(\x)},0)
  -- plot[variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi] 
  ({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*cos(\x)},{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*sin(-\x)},
 {(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill length}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius})-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/pill radius}*sin(\x)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[gap width/.initial=1mm,diameter/.initial=1cm]
 \fill[blue!20] (45:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter})
 arc(45:225:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}) -- 
 cycle; 
 \fill[blue!50] (45:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter})
 arc(45:-135:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}) -- 
 cycle; 
 \fill[blue!30] (0,0)
 circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/gap width}];
 \fill[blue!50] (45:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}) -- 
 ++ ({-sqrt(2)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/gap width}},0) -- 
 ++ (-135:{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/gap width}})
 -- (225:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}) -- cycle;
\fill[blue!20] (45:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}) -- 
 ++ (0,{-sqrt(2)*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/gap width}}) -- 
 ++ (-135:{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/gap width}})
 -- (225:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/diameter}) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your icon is super, can you edit your code that can copy and resize this icon? Thank so much. and add more circle table icon

Comment: @latexforti You can resize it e.g. by saying `scale=0.5` and the tablet will probably come in a bit.

Comment: can you use "documentclass{article}"? thanks

Comment: @latexforti Done