# A sad duck with TikZ (or TikZducks?)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzducks, tikzlings

I am working on my homework, which includes a little website.

I like the `tikzducks` package very much, so I decided to add some illustrations there using the svg files generated from `\duck` command.

However, right now I am working on error pages (404 page, etc.). I need a *sad* duck to illustrate the page. But apparently it is not yet available in `tikzducks`.

So how to have a sad duck based on `tikzducks`' `\duck`?

Sorry for not providing a minimal example, but I just can't do it – my imagination is not as good as samcarter's.

`tikzlings`-based answers are also welcome, but `tikzducks` would be prefered for better consistency.

---

**Edit** – `\duck[grumpy]` is good enough for me. However, if you have any ideas, your answer is very appreciated.

Comment: is the grumpy duck not suitable?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oops, I somehow passed that without carefully looking at it. Probably I should close this question for now.

Comment: you don't need to vote to close your own question. But you can also wait if someone comes along with some better idea. Or answer your own question if you thing the grumpy duck is good.

Comment: sad and grumpy is different... I vote for *not* closing this question

Comment: The grumpy duck is a perhaps a little subtle; how about a crying duck? A teardrop would be easy enough to add (I may have a play later if I get time, but won't mind at all if someone beats me to it)

Comment: @ChrisH Maybe [these droplets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/195642) could be used.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following code was passed to me:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\pagecolor{gray!20!white}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[grumpy,eye=yellow!70!brown]
    \fill[white!85!yellow] (0.9121,1.5426) .. controls (0.9357,1.6075) and (0.9015,1.6397) .. (0.8552,1.6566) .. controls (0.8088,1.6735) and (0.7652,1.6477) .. (0.7442,1.6038) .. controls (0.7205,1.5388) and (0.7390,1.4725) .. (0.7853,1.4557) .. controls (0.8317,1.4388) and (0.8885,1.4777) .. (0.9121,1.5426) -- cycle (0.6199,1.6197) .. controls (0.6415,1.6790) and (0.6260,1.7156) .. (0.5852,1.7304) .. controls (0.5443,1.7453) and (0.4937,1.7328) .. (0.4721,1.6735) .. controls (0.4505,1.6141) and (0.4661,1.5540) .. (0.5069,1.5391) .. controls (0.5477,1.5243) and (0.5983,1.5603) .. (0.6199,1.6197) -- cycle;
    \fill[black, rotate=-20] (0.26,1.7575) ellipse (0.0357 and 0.0714);
    \fill[black, rotate=-20] (-0.03,1.73) ellipse (0.0286 and 0.0643);
    \fill[yellow!30!brown] (0.9778,1.6871) .. controls (0.9011,1.6753) and (0.8740,1.7030) .. (0.8531,1.7606) .. controls (0.8034,1.6833) and (0.9421,1.6177) .. (0.9778,1.6871) -- cycle (0.6229,1.8394) .. controls (0.5901,1.7822) and (0.5420,1.7734) .. (0.4966,1.8048) .. controls (0.5213,1.7300) and (0.6310,1.7565) .. (0.6229,1.8394) -- cycle;       
    \fill[cyan!50!white] (0.9026,1.3929) .. controls (0.9135,1.3706) and (0.8889,1.3471) .. (0.8719,1.3471) .. controls (0.8549,1.3471) and (0.8303,1.3706) .. (0.8412,1.3929) .. controls (0.8519,1.4148) and (0.8549,1.4150) .. (0.8719,1.4388) .. controls (0.8827,1.4099) and (0.8904,1.4182) .. (0.9026,1.3929) -- cycle (0.9499,1.2931) .. controls (0.9608,1.2707) and (0.9362,1.2472) .. (0.9192,1.2472) .. controls (0.9022,1.2472) and (0.8776,1.2708) .. (0.8885,1.2931) .. controls (0.8992,1.3150) and (0.9022,1.3151) .. (0.9192,1.3389) .. controls (0.9300,1.3100) and (0.9377,1.3184) .. (0.9499,1.2931) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

I hear some rumours that it will find its way into the tickducks package at some time.

Comment: `\duck[crying]`?

Comment: This is very nice :-)

Comment: (+25) I am very sad :-(