# PDF viewer for flip book animation

Tags: beamer, viewers

I have 100 PDF slides (created with Beamer) which when flipped through yield a small animation. I'm now looking for a PDF viewer which displays such an animation nicely. A bad example (in this respect) is evince which when you keep the right-key pressed freezes and only updates once you let the key go. Okular is more or less fine, but I wonder whether there is any viewer which allows me to set the frame-rate and would be a bit more reliable when it comes to buffering (Okular sometimes lags a bit).

I have both Linux (preferred) and Windows available. The PDF viewer has to be freely downloadable.

Comment: There's always `acroread`. Though if you think Okular lags ...

Comment: basically you have a video made of pdf slides that you want to play at a certain framerate? Here in the office, I have only Adobe Acrobat X. It lets you specify a frame rate for fullscreen mode in whole seconds (so the fastest is one slide per second)

Comment: If you want a uniform framerate, let beamer do the job. With `\transduration<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨number of seconds⟩}` you can specify the time a slide is displayed. For the fasted transition possible, use `\transduration{0.00}` which makes it only dependent on how fast the viewer can show the frames. Work not in all viewers, but for example in acrobat.

Answer (score 2):

How about, instead of relying on a PDF viewer to page through your animation, you compile your animation into a different format that is fairly universal - animated GIF.

Here's an example:

1. Consider the following animation - 20 pages - taken from [How can we display fireworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88784/5764):

   ```
   \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes}

   \begin{document}

   \foreach \radius in {1,2,...,20}
   {
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     % background rectangle
     \filldraw[black] (-3,-3) rectangle (5,3);
     % skyline
     \filldraw[black!80!blue](-3,-3)--(-3,-2)--(-2.5,-2)--(-2.5,-1)--(-2.25,-1)--(-2.25,-2)--(-2,-2)
                               --(-2,-1)--(-1.75,-0.75)--(-1.5,-1)
                               --(-1.5,-2)--(-1.1,-2)--(-1.1,0)--(-0.5,0)--(-0.5,-2)
                               --(0,-2)--(0,-1.5)--(1,-1.5)--(1.25,-0.5)--(1.5,-1.5)--(1.5,-2)
                               --(2,-2)--(2,0)--(2.5,0)--(2.5,-2)
                               --(3,-2)--(3,-1)--(4,-1)--(4,-2)--(5,-2)--(5,-3)--cycle;
     % moon- what a hack!
     \filldraw[white] (4,2.5) arc (90:-90:20pt);
     \filldraw[black] (3.8,2.5) arc (90:-90:20pt);
     % fireworks
     \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-1)*10};
     % red firework
     \ifnum\radius<11
         \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses},red!\pgfmathresult!black] (0,0) circle (\radius ex);
     \fi
     % orange firework
     \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-6)*10};
     \ifnum\radius>5
         \ifnum\radius<16
             \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses},orange!\pgfmathresult!black] (1,1) circle ( \radius ex-5ex);
         \fi
     \fi
     % yellow firework
     \pgfmathparse{100-(\radius-11)*10};
     \ifnum\radius>10
         \draw[decorate,decoration={crosses},yellow!\pgfmathresult!black] (2.5,1) circle (\radius ex-10ex);
     \fi
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Compile this code to produce `fireworks.pdf`.
3. Convert `fireworks.pdf` to an animated GIF via [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) using

   ```
   convert -delay 20 -loop 0 -density 300 fireworks.pdf fireworks.gif
   ```

   Of course, adjust the `delay` (which is the frame rate in miliseconds), `loop` and `density` to suit your needs. There are other parameters you may also require. See [How to convert `pstricks` animation to GIF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73545/5764)
4. Display it using your regular browser or image viewer...

   [image]