# My computer getting high frequency of freeze as number of compilations of latex file increases

Tags: compiling

As I stated in the title, my computer has been getting bad and I bet one of the reasons is compiling latex files many times.

Even I reinstalled the operating system, seemingly the frequency of freeze has not been fixed.

I use unix-like OS.

I use latex in isolated environment,not using dropBox nor OneDrive.

I compile latex file using `pdflatex test.tex`

I use latex with vscode.

I did the performance test using the command `sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run`

and got the below result.
[image]

Any other persons who encountering this problem?

How do I resolve this freeze problem?

Should I post this question in other community or can I still have posted it here?

Comment: You might want to include some information about what OS you are using, which latex you are using, editor. Is this only regarding LaTeX? Is DropBox or OneDrive involved. As stated, details matter

Comment: The only problems I can fathom to cause a freeze by running LaTeX are memory-related --- if you run very big projects with a machine with very little memory. It would be quite surprising though; TeX an LaTeX used to compile my thesis in machines where memory was counted in kilobytes...

Comment: Can you make your machine freeze by working it hard doing something different? If you don't do much else, maybe download a [benchmarking/stress-testing program](https://askubuntu.com/q/634513/178354) (discussion is filed under Ubuntu but is more broadly applicable); this should help you figure out whether using memory hard, doing some intensive processing, etc. might be the cause.  I'm wondering about hardware/overheating issues, especially if you're doing something as [silly as I've been known to do in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347014/28808)

Comment: pdflatex doesn't do any dynamic memory allocation so what you describes sounds very strange. Are you sure it's not your editor?

Comment: One thing I have found is that if a compilation hangs (with errors), sometimes "stopping" the compilation does not kill the process.  Thus, you can end up with several/numerous versions of the compiler executing a failed compilation simultaneously.  This can slow down the computer greatly.  You have to check your task manager to see if such a situation is happening.  In my case, that means looking for multiple version of `pdflatex` running.