# TeX rendering in a Java application

Tags: rendering, java

I want to render math formulas in my Java GUI application. I am looking for a library made for computer use, not web use, which can render TeX. I have already tried jLatexMath, but it's very slow when I use it in my application.

If there are any other/better, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I can think of three libraries that might somehow help or inspire you: [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/), [SnuggleTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) and [JLaTeXMath](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/).

Comment: I am using jLatexMath in one of my own projects, and the first time I got it to display equations I also thought it was very slow, until I realized this was only true for the first invocation of jLatexMath. For every start of your application, the first rendering will be slow but subsequent renderings are fast.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image: Info] **Friendly note:** most of the conversion process involves input parsing, evaluation, font loading, rendering and output so that I wouldn't expect a nearly real-time conversion.

That said, let's go to business. `:)`

[image: Info] **Warning:** boring non-TeX technical Java stuff ahead. `:)`

I had a quick look at both [SnuggleTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) and [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/) to come up with this answer. Sorry, I didn't have time to come up with a better example.

The first one, [SnuggleTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/), is described as "a free and open-source Java library for converting fragments of LaTeX to XML (usually XHTML + MathML)." The second one, [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/), is described as "a complete MathML rendering solution." What I actually did was to redirect one's output to the other's input.

First, with [SnuggleTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/), you can obtain the needed code from the [minimal example](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/snuggletex/documentation/minimal-example.html) in its own homepage:

```java
/* Create vanilla SnuggleEngine and new SnuggleSession */
SnuggleEngine engine = new SnuggleEngine();
SnuggleSession session = engine.createSession();

/* Parse some very basic Math Mode input */
SnuggleInput input = new SnuggleInput("$$ x+2=3 $$");
session.parseInput(input);

/* Convert the results to an XML String, which in this case will
 * be a single MathML <math>...</math> element. */
String xmlString = session.buildXMLString();
```

Now you have the MathML representation of your LaTeX input. Let's check [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/), from its [API](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jeuclid/converter/Converter.html), and there's the `Converter` class with the following method:

```java
BufferedImage render(Node node, LayoutContext context)
```

Then you can use `net.sourceforge.jeuclid.MathMLParserSupport` to parse your XML string to `org.w3c.dom.Document`. Calling the `render` method with the correct parameters will give you a `BufferedImage` representing your input.

My attempt:

[image: My code]

It took around 1.4 secs to render this image.

I didn't like the output, but to be honest, I just wrote this app in 2 minutes as a `[cough... cough... bad...]` proof of concept. `:)` I'm almost sure the rendering quality can be improved, but I'm quite busy right now. Anyway, I think you can try something similar and then decide if this approach is worth a shot. `:)`

**Update:** It seems [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/) has a [`JMathComponent`](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/jeuclid/swing/JMathComponent.html) in order to display MathML content in a `Component`.

Comment: What is the minimum library to include to go from the MathML output to a PNG image? I don't require any other conversions and would like to keep the software as light as possible. So for just converting MathML to an image file using JEuclid do I just need to include the core and nothing else?

Comment: @Ozzy: according to JEuclid's [usage page](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/usage.html), the minimal distribution covers `.png` output, so it's certainly safe to use it. `:)`

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to call mimetex.cgi (available here: http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html) from Java.

I do not pretend that this solution is "better" than the ones previously given. The purpose is just to give alternatives.

Example of result:

[image]

Code leading to this result:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Exemple106_MimetexInterface {

private static String MIMETEX_EXE = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\mimetex\\mimetex.cgi";

final private static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

/**
 * Convert LaTeX code to GIF
 *
 * @param latexString LaTeX code
 * @return GIF image, under byte[] format
 */
public static byte[] getLaTeXImage(String latexString) {
    byte[] imageData = null;
    try {
        // mimetex is asked (on the command line) to convert
        // the LaTeX expression to .gif on standard output:
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(MIMETEX_EXE + " -d \"" + latexString + "\"");
        // get the output stream of the process:
        BufferedInputStream bis = (BufferedInputStream) proc.getInputStream();
        // read output process by bytes blocks (size: BUFFER_SIZE)
        // and stores the result in a byte[] Arraylist:
        int bytesRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        ArrayList<byte[]> al = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            al.add(buffer.clone());
        }
        // convert the Arraylist in an unique array:
        int nbOfArrays = al.size();
        if (nbOfArrays == 1) {
            imageData = buffer;
        } else {
            imageData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE * nbOfArrays];
            byte[] temp;
            for (int k = 0; k < nbOfArrays; k++) {
                temp = al.get(k);
                for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
                    imageData[BUFFER_SIZE * k + i] = temp[i];
                }
            }
        }
        bis.close();
        proc.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageData;
}

/**
 * demonstration main
 *
 * @param args command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    String LATEX_EXPRESSION_1 = "4$A=\\(\\array{3,c.cccBCCC$&1&2&3\\\\\\hdash~1&a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\\\2&a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\\\3&a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}}\\) ";
    byte[] imageData1 = getLaTeXImage(LATEX_EXPRESSION_1);
    JLabel button1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageData1));
    jframe.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    String LATEX_EXPRESSION_2 = "4$\\array{rccclBCB$&f&\\longr[75]^{\\alpha:{-1$f\\rightar~g}}&g\\\\3$\\gamma&\\longd[50]&&\\longd[50]&3$\\gamma\\\\&u&\\longr[75]_\\beta&v}";
    byte[] imageData2 = getLaTeXImage(LATEX_EXPRESSION_2);
    JLabel button2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageData2));
    jframe.add(button2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    String LATEX_EXPRESSION_3 = "4$\\hspace{5}\\unitlength{1}\\picture(175,100){~(50,50){\\circle(100)}(1,50){\\overbrace{\\line(46)}^{4$\\;\\;a}}(52,50) {\\line(125)}~(50,52;115;2){\\mid}~(52,55){\\longleftar[60]}(130,56){\\longrightar[35]}~(116,58){r}~(c85,50;80;2){\\bullet} (c85,36){3$-q}~(c165,36){3$q}(42,30){\\underbrace{\\line(32)}_{1$a^2/r\\;\\;\\;}}~}";
    byte[] imageData3 = getLaTeXImage(LATEX_EXPRESSION_3);
    JLabel button3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageData3));
    jframe.add(button3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jframe.pack();
    jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Nicolas

Answer (score 5):

Another solution to create a PNG image from LaTeX **provided that LaTeX (for instance: MiKTeX) is installed on the computer**...

LaTeX standalone package allows the creation of a PNG output file, the size of which exactly corresponds to the size of the formula or of the text.

So, we just have to call LaTeX from Java, and get the PNG output file.

**1. Prerequisites**

a) LaTeX shall be installed on the computer
... with all packages necessary for the formula (in the below example: amsfonts and amsmath)
... with standalone package

GhostScript shall be installed (necessary for standalone package)
The directory containing gswin32c.exe shall be added to PATH.
On my computer: C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.10\bin

ImageMagick shall be installed (necessary for standalone package)
convert.exe shall be renamed as imgconvert.exe
The directory containing imgconvert.exe shall be added to PATH.
On my computer: C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.8-9

**2. Check that LaTeX (with standalone package) succeeds in generating the PNG file (no Java at this stage).**

Reference : [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible)

LaTeX file, called New21.tex (for instance):

```
\documentclass[border=0.50001bp,convert={convertexe={imgconvert},outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{l}

\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_+^*\ \exists\eta>0\ |x-x_0|\leq\eta\Longrightarrow|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq\varepsilon\\

\det\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&\ddots&&\vdots\\\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\a_{n1}&\cdots&\cdots&a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n}\varepsilon(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\sigma(k)}\\

{\sideset{_\alpha^\beta}{_\gamma^\delta}{\mathop{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}}}}\\

\int_0^\infty{x^{2n} e^{-a x^2}\,dx} = \frac{2n-1}{2a} \int_0^\infty{x^{2(n-1)} e^{-a x^2}\,dx} = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^{n+1}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^{2n+1}}}\\

\int_a^b{f(x)\,dx} = (b - a) \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{m = 1}^{2^n  - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{m + 1} } } 2^{ - n} f(a + m\left( {b - a} \right)2^{-n} )\\

\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(\alpha x) \sin^n(\beta x) dx = \textstyle{\left \{ \begin{array}{cc} (-1)^{(n+1)/2} (-1)^m \frac{2 \pi}{2^n} \binom{n}{m} & n \mbox{ odd},\ \alpha = \beta (2m-n) \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \\ \end{array} \right .}\\

L = \int_a^b \sqrt{ \left|\sum_{i,j=1}^ng_{ij}(\gamma(t))\left(\frac{d}{dt}x^i\circ\gamma(t)\right)\left(\frac{d}{dt}x^j\circ\gamma(t)\right)\right|}\,dt\\

\begin{array}{rl} s &= \int_a^b\left\|\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}\,(u(t),v(t))\right\|\,dt \\ &= \int_a^b \sqrt{u'(t)^2\,\vec{r}_u\cdot\vec{r}_u + 2u'(t)v'(t)\, \vec{r}_u\cdot\vec{r}_v+ v'(t)^2\,\vec{r}_v\cdot\vec{r}_v}\,\,\, dt. \end{array}\\

\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Command line:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape New21.tex
```

This should generate a file New21.png containing the below picture:
[image]

**3. Generation of the PNG file from Java, through a call to LaTeX**

Code:

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

class StreamPrinter implements Runnable {

    // Source: http://labs.excilys.com/2012/06/26/runtime-exec-pour-les-nuls-et-processbuilder/
    private final InputStream inputStream;

    private boolean print;

    StreamPrinter(InputStream inputStream, boolean print) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.print = print;
    }

    private BufferedReader getBufferedReader(InputStream is) {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br = getBufferedReader(inputStream);
        String ligne = "";
        try {
            while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (print) {
                    System.out.println(ligne);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Exemple141_LaTeX_to_PNG_using_installed_LaTeX_distribution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String TEMP_DIRECTORY = "D:\\_tmp";
        String TEMP_TEX_FILE_NAME = "New22"; // for New22.tex

        // 1. Prepare the .tex file
        String newLineWithSeparation = System.getProperty("line.separator")+System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String math = "";
        math += "\\documentclass[border=0.50001bp,convert={convertexe={imgconvert},outext=.png}]{standalone}" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\usepackage{amsfonts}" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\usepackage{amsmath}" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\begin{document}" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "$\\begin{array}{l}" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\forall\\varepsilon\\in\\mathbb{R}_+^*\\ \\exists\\eta>0\\ |x-x_0|\\leq\\eta\\Longrightarrow|f(x)-f(x_0)|\\leq\\varepsilon\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\det\\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\\cdots&a_{1n}\\\\a_{21}&\\ddots&&\\vdots\\\\\\vdots&&\\ddots&\\vdots\\\\a_{n1}&\\cdots&\\cdots&a_{nn}\\end{bmatrix}\\overset{\\mathrm{def}}{=}\\sum_{\\sigma\\in\\mathfrak{S}_n}\\varepsilon(\\sigma)\\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\\sigma(k)}\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "{\\sideset{_\\alpha^\\beta}{_\\gamma^\\delta}{\\mathop{\\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\\\c&d\\end{pmatrix}}}}\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\int_0^\\infty{x^{2n} e^{-a x^2}\\,dx} = \\frac{2n-1}{2a} \\int_0^\\infty{x^{2(n-1)} e^{-a x^2}\\,dx} = \\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^{n+1}} \\sqrt{\\frac{\\pi}{a^{2n+1}}}\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\int_a^b{f(x)\\,dx} = (b - a) \\sum\\limits_{n = 1}^\\infty  {\\sum\\limits_{m = 1}^{2^n  - 1} {\\left( { - 1} \\right)^{m + 1} } } 2^{ - n} f(a + m\\left( {b - a} \\right)2^{-n} )\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\int_{-\\pi}^{\\pi} \\sin(\\alpha x) \\sin^n(\\beta x) dx = \\textstyle{\\left \\{ \\begin{array}{cc} (-1)^{(n+1)/2} (-1)^m \\frac{2 \\pi}{2^n} \\binom{n}{m} & n \\mbox{ odd},\\ \\alpha = \\beta (2m-n) \\\\ 0 & \\mbox{otherwise} \\\\ \\end{array} \\right .}\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "L = \\int_a^b \\sqrt{ \\left|\\sum_{i,j=1}^ng_{ij}(\\gamma(t))\\left(\\frac{d}{dt}x^i\\circ\\gamma(t)\\right)\\left(\\frac{d}{dt}x^j\\circ\\gamma(t)\\right)\\right|}\\,dt\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\begin{array}{rl} s &= \\int_a^b\\left\\|\\frac{d}{dt}\\vec{r}\\,(u(t),v(t))\\right\\|\\,dt \\\\ &= \\int_a^b \\sqrt{u'(t)^2\\,\\vec{r}_u\\cdot\\vec{r}_u + 2u'(t)v'(t)\\, \\vec{r}_u\\cdot\\vec{r}_v+ v'(t)^2\\,\\vec{r}_v\\cdot\\vec{r}_v}\\,\\,\\, dt. \\end{array}\\\\" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\end{array}$" + newLineWithSeparation;
        math += "\\end{document}";

        // 2. Create the .tex file
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(TEMP_DIRECTORY + "\\" + TEMP_TEX_FILE_NAME + ".tex", false);
            writer.write(math, 0, math.length());
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // 3. Execute LaTeX from command line  to generate picture
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("pdflatex", "-shell-escape", TEMP_TEX_FILE_NAME + ".tex");
        pb.directory(new File(TEMP_DIRECTORY));
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            StreamPrinter fluxSortie = new StreamPrinter(p.getInputStream(), false);
            StreamPrinter fluxErreur = new StreamPrinter(p.getErrorStream(), false);
            new Thread(fluxSortie).start();
            new Thread(fluxErreur).start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // 4. Display picture
        JFrame maFrame = new JFrame();
        maFrame.setResizable(false);
        maFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        maFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        maFrame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(TEMP_DIRECTORY + "\\" + TEMP_TEX_FILE_NAME + ".png")));
        maFrame.pack();
        maFrame.setVisible(true);

        // 5. Delete files
        for (File file : (new File(TEMP_DIRECTORY).listFiles())) {
            if (file.getName().startsWith(TEMP_TEX_FILE_NAME + ".")) {
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code should create the below frame:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using Java's `Runtime` class you can execute external processes, so you can easily generate some LaTeX input file that contains the LaTeX expressions, execute `pdflatex` on the input file, possibly use `Runrime` to convert the `pdf` output to a different format (with `gs`) and open the resulting picture.

If you know `Java` this should be easy to implement. I don't have time to do this myself, but I'm confident this shouldn't take more than an hour or so.

Answer (score 2):

[KeenType](https://gitlab.com/DaveJarvis/KeenType) is a modernized version of [NTS](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/nts) that provides a way to generate an SVG document from a plain TeX document. KeenType replaces KeenTeX, which was a fork of the [JMathTeX](https://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/) project.

Usage:

```java
final var str = "$\\sigma=\\sqrt{\\sum\\limits_{i=1}^{k} p_i(x_i-\\mu)^2}$";
final var typesetter = new KeenType();
final var svg = typesetter.toSvg( str );
```

On my machine, KeenType can render 1,000 simple equations in less than 2 seconds.

The SVG can be rendered as a `BufferedImage` using a pure Java SVG rasterizer, such as [EchoSVG](https://github.com/css4j/echosvg/). Here's the output in [KeenWrite](https://keenwrite.com/), my Java-based Markdown editor:

[image: KeenType]

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about Java programming, but I am pretty sure that there are free applications that use JLaTeXMath to render LaTeX that you can try and look at.  I have pretty good experience with [Geogebra](http://geogebra.org/).  The rendering in Geogebra is pretty fast (generally does not seem to slow the application down in any way), and the output is rather nice, I think.  It is a free software, so you can download the source code and see how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at DataMelt http://jwork.org/dmelt
You can create PNG files from Latex equations using the Java class jhplot.HLatexEq

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [JavaTeX](http://javatex.sourceforge.net/)? If that doesn't solve your problem, can you describe the features you're looking for and other constraints?

Comment: This is a program, but I am looking for a Java library. I want to give a String, and receive anything I can draw on a JPanel or any other JComponent, preferably a BufferedImage. (This is why I asked this question on SO, they probably know a lot more about this kind of stuff.)

Comment: The source is available on sourceforge. You should be able to extract the functionality to a library.

Comment: JavaTeX is [NTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Typesetting_System) combined with a dvi viewer. That's nice, but also a 10 year old dead end.

Answer (score 0):

SnuggleTeX is used by RTextDoc [RTextDoc](http://jwork.org/rtextdoc) text editor to convert Latex to HTML