# Producing LaTeX output in Java

Tags: java

Is there a Java library for producing LaTeX output from Java?
I want a methos, where the argument will be the String and the output will be PDF.

Comment: Possibly related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41609/tex-rendering-in-a-java-application

Comment: See also https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath