# producing latex strings from java

Tags: java

Basically I have a string such as

```
String latex = "\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\\title{First document}
\\author{me}

\\begin{document}

\\maketitle

\\begin{abstract}
XXX
\\end{abstract}

YYY 

\\end{document}"
```

How can I get java to render this for me?

Comment: this seems to be a purely Java question so off topic here. You just need to write that to a file and then call out to the shell to run pdflatex on the file.

Comment: There are libraries such as `jlatexmath` but mostly limited to math as far as I'm aware. If you're looking for a complete support it would probably be easier to call another process (one of the engines) to do the job and then show the results as PDF, image or whatever you need. Also see [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41609/204490)