# What document class should I use for a variable size image generator

Tags: math-mode, document-classes

Currently, whenever I want to make a math image, I head over to my Wikipedia Sandbox and use the WP math tag(which uses TeX). I then copy the image from the preview.

I have TeXmaker (from USBTeX), and I'd like to use it more often. The issue is, I can't find a way to create a page that is cropped to the size of the content. So The most I can do is use `\documentclass[]{slides}` and crop it with Paint--clearly inefficient.

What would be nice would be something which autosizes each page based on its contents. Does something like this exist??

Comment: Related question: [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/11880#11880)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`standalone` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) does this out-of-the-box, creating a cropped version of the document content. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}% http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone
\begin{document}
$E=mc^2$
\end{document}
```

Setting a border (of whitespace) around the cropped output is as simple as supplying the option `[border=<len>]` to the document class (where `<len>` is any known TeX dimension). See the [`standalone` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) for more options.

If you enjoy pagination and would like to create "a bunch at a time", you could use the `multi` option/key-value from `standalone` (example below from Martin Scharrer) or the [`preview` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/preview) and wrap each "page" inside a `preview` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[multi=math,border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}% always a good idea when using math
\begin{document}
\begin{math}
  E=mc^2
\end{math}

\begin{math}
  \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% http://ctan.org/pkg/preview
\begin{document}
% PAGE 1
\begin{preview}
$E=mc^2$
\end{preview}

% PAGE 2
\begin{preview}
$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Check out the [`preview` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/preview/preview.pdf) for more options.

Comment: Great, thanks! This will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Werner, you don't seem to know the `multi` option of the `standalone` class yet. It got introduces with v1.0. It allows for multiple pages as well.