# How to change the page height on current page so as to include each section in one page?

Tags: page-breaking

I consider posting some materials as `.jpg` file on my blog which produced from a `.tex` document.

This document includes lots of sections which is about 1500-2300 words. I need neither header nor page number. I can also accept the endnotes.

I want each `.jpg` file corresponded with just a whole section, as shown by follow images. (The images were transformed from a `.pdf` file.)

---

page i (also section 1)

[image]

---

page ii (also section 2)

[image]

---

page iii (also section 3)

[image]

---

But, I failed on trying to change the page's height on each page. It is seem that the entire document could set only a fixed page size. I think maybe the requirement can be implemented by

1. On the beginning of every section, put a `\newpage` command.
2. Set a sufficient page height value (as we known, the page size of a `.tex` file can be several meter long).
3. Typeset the file, record (using some technique) the total length of `vbox` at the end of current page.
4. Use the record value to set a new page height.
5. typeset again, but just typeset the section I needed.

Does above said describe a right way? Could someone tell me how to implement it automatically?

Or is there a more convenient way to achieve the result?

---

EDIT:

Hi Chris H, the `preview` package suppressed the setting of`\lineskiplimit` or/and `\lineskip`. Try the code below

```
documentclass{book}

\usepackage[

active, %if annotate the line obtain fig 1

tightpage]{preview}\setlength{\PreviewBorder}{9pt}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{9pt}\setlength{\lineskip}{9pt}

\begin{preview}

\begin{flushleft}

\fbox{It attempt to compare nil with number}

\fbox{It attempt to compare nil with number}

\end{flushleft}

\end{preview}

\end{document}
```

obtain fig 2.

fig 1

[image]

fig 2

[image]

So, the substances in each section would be inappropriate.

Comment: It may be possible to set an arbitrarily long page size (whatever the maximum is), then use `pdfcrop` (or imagemagick, which you may well be using anyway for the pdf-jpg conversion, to crop the resulting pdf).  Unfortunately the `standalone` documentclass ignores `\newpage`, otherwise it would be your friend here.

Comment: @ChrisH your strategy appears sound, but why then `standalone`? One only needs to remove the footline with the page numbers with `\pagestyle{empty}` and `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the first page (article class). Then one can use `pdfcrop` and finally `gs` with its `jpeg` device (or rather `png16m` or variants for `.png` images). [only trouble will be with footnotes...]

Comment: @jfbu I've refined it to just use `preview`.  I hadn't considered footnotes, I must admit - I don't know if they're an issue here.  One advantage of `preview` is that it's a simpler workflow than going thorugh `pdfcrop` as well (generating the "right" pdf then converting it seems more elegant than having to optically crop it.

Comment: @ChrisH yes and I upvoted. But `preview` requires more manual mark-up than `\clearpage`. (and I don't know if it acts as an environment, in that case it would create a group, which could be annoying. But I should check the doc first).

Comment: @jfbu do you know how quickly/happily pdfcrop would handle a *very* long page?  I can't test it here without some effort in sorting issues with paths and various software versions.  Standalone also has a .png option (which I only discovered while reading the documentation to write the answer to this Q - then I didn't use it)

Comment: @ChrisH I just tried `pdfcrop` on a file with `\usepackage[paperheight=200cm]{geometry}`, the first page with `40` lipsum paragraphs and a footnote, the second with only a word. And page numbers removed. `pdfcrop` handled that instantly. I don't know for real-life situations... and by the way, `preview` does create groups.

Comment: Thanks @jfbu, your alternative solution deserves as much attention as my answer - it's worth my vote at least if you put in it an answer and let the OP choose the more suitable solution.

Comment: @ChrisH your method with `preview` has the advantages you mentioned about a faster workflow once the mark-up is done; let's see what the OP says, if he is satisfied with it, that's the answer!

Comment: @jfbu Hi, I have edited the question again. There have some problems with `preview` package (the adjoining lines are too closed). Would you care for pasting your answer via "standalone" package on?

Comment: @user41022 will you have footnotes and do you need a footer with page numbers?

Comment: @jfbu I need neither header nor page number. I can also accept the endnotes. (But I meet some problems with `mpfootnote` and `footnote` counter. Even I load the `endnotes` package, it will still be a problem. Could you tell me how to make the `mpfootnote` counter cooperated with `footnote` counter? See my another question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145304/improper-symbol-mark-of-footnote-in-minipage-environment)

Comment: @user41022 I don't know about `mpfootnote`. I have added an answer with the workflow sketched in  previous comments. It uses neither `standalone` nor `preview`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need a footer and are ok with footnotes relegated to the end of the document via `endnotes` then a simple modification of your proposed workflow could fit the bill.

1. `\usepackage [paperheight=50cm, textheight=48cm, paperwidth=21cm]{geometry}` or whatever is enough instead of `50cm, 48cm`. Or only `paperheight` and `vscale=0.95` for example. The `21cm` if for `A4` paper width. Adjust as desired.
2. `\pagestyle{empty}` in the preamble and `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the first page (if using `article` class).
3. End each section with a `\clearpage`. Do not make footnotes, or use rather `endnotes` package.
4. Either:

   - use `latex myfile.tex` + `dvipng -Ttight myfile.dvi` to generate one `png` per page, with tight bounding box. Use for example `-D200` to get twice as many pixels (per dimension, so `2x2=4` as many pixels, really) than the default (which I believe is `100` pixels per inch of the original; but `dvipng` does not store the real pixel dimensions in the produced file [last time I checked about a year ago] and browsers display with pixels on the final device so the higher resolution the final device, the smaller the image appears [last time I checked about a year ago])
   - or use `pdflatex myfile.tex` (or anything with `pdf` output) then `pdfcrop myfile.pdf` to get `myfile-crop.pdf` then something such as `gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -dDownScaleFactor=3 -o myfile%02d.png myfile-crop.pdf` to generate `png` files with colors. Use `pnggray` (but not `pngmono`) if you don't need colors. Use `gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -o myfile%02d.png myfile-crop.pdf` for generating `jpeg` pictures instead. Additional relevant switches for `jpeg` are `-r` for the resolution in dots per inch (default `72`) and `-dJPEGQ=N` (integer from 0 to 100, default 75) for the quality. I never use `jpeg` so I can't say more on it!

All of the above is a bit theoretical, if it doesn't work, do complain!

Answer (score 3):

My previous comment considered using the `standalone` documentclass.  That uses the `preview` package.  Going directly to `preview` gives a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\section{Intro}
\lipsum[1]
\end{preview}
\newpage
\begin{preview}
\section{Another section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `tightpage` option does the cropping for you as well.

EDIT:Here's where I derived this answer from:https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51627/28808

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very good. It solved my problem except that source file need many revisions. Even so, it is great. @jfbu Thanks for your attention. I don't understand your said clearly. Would you mind taking some time to write down a answer?

Comment: I think @jfbu might have a better solution for you, but I wonder if you could find/replace all your `\section{`s with `\end{preview}\newpage\begin{preview}\section{`, then you'd just have to fix the first and last.

Comment: There have some shortcoming on `preview` package. See my edited post.