# Improper symbol mark of footnote in minipage environment

Tags: footnotes, minipage, footmisc

I think that the `footmisc` package has predefined the `sympol` mark series, but in minipage environment they become invalid. See below

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[symbol*,stable]{footmisc}

\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{3in}

Here the text in environment\footnote{the footnote in minipage}

\end{minipage}

\vfil

\parbox{3in}{Here the text in parbox\footnotemark}

\footnotetext{the footnote in parbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How could I get the symbolical footnotemark in `minipage`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`minipage`s have their own footnote counter, which is called `mpfootnote`.

When you use the option `symbol*` loading the package `footmisc`, it affects only the normal `footnote` counter.

So, if you want the same behavior for `minipage`s, you have to add the line

```
\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
```

in your preamble.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[symbol*,stable]{footmisc}

\usepackage[paperheight=5cm,showframe]{geometry}

\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{3in}

Here the text in environment\footnote{the footnote in minipage}

\end{minipage}

\vfil

\parbox{3in}{Here the text in parbox\footnotemark}

\footnotetext{the footnote in parbox}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

### EDIT

In response to your comment, if you want

1. The `mpfootnote` counter not to be reset at each `minipage`
2. The `mpfootnote` counter to share its value with the `footnote` counter

you can do the following:

1. Insert

   ```
   \setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
   ```

   just after the beginning of each `minipage`, e.g.

   ```
   \begin{minipage}{3in}
   \setcounter{mpfootnote}{\value{footnote}}
   ```
2. Insert

   ```
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}}
   ```

   just before the end of each `minipage`, that is

   ```
   \setcounter{footnote}{\value{mpfootnote}}
   \end{minipage}
   ```

Comment: @user41022 You're welcome.

Comment: Oh, the code above produce another question: how to make the `mpfootnote` counter "synchronize" with `footnote` counter? I mean that if the `mpfootnote` counter equal n, then the `footnote` counter followed equal n+1; vice versa.

Comment: @user41022 See the edit.