# How to change footnote to symbol in table in minipage without special package?

Tags: footnotes

Based on [How to change symbol for footnote in minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/how-to-change-symbol-for-footnote-in-minipage) and [Symbols instead of numbers as footnote markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers) I expected this code to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}

        \renewcommand*{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
       \begin{tabular}{ll}
       \hline
        foo & bar\footnote[1]{buzz} \\
        foobar & barfoo \\
        \hline
       \end{tabular}

      \end{minipage}
  \end{document}
```

However, I don't get any footnote symbol at all.

[image]

It feels like I have made some silly mistake but I can't figure it out. What have I missed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improper symbol mark of footnote in minipage environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145304/improper-symbol-mark-of-footnote-in-minipage-environment)

Comment: In fact I don't think it's a duplicate because the table seems to add another twist to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex
```

You have to redefine the minipage footnote, not the footnote:

```
\documentclass{article}        

  \begin{document}
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \renewcommand*{\thempfootnote}{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
       \begin{tabular}{ll}
       \hline
        foo & bar\footnote[1]{buzz} \\
        foobar & barfoo \\
        \hline
       \end{tabular}
      \end{minipage}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not know, what the `[1]` is doing, but I left it in, as I assume the OP is needing it.

Comment: I looked further at it and turns out we have to use [1] there because it seems inside the table in fact the footnote counter is  used and not the minipage footnote counter. If two footnotes is needed use [2] for the second or another approach is to sync the two counters which I also tried. I feel dirty all over... :)

Comment: According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/829/145453), [num] is the number of the symbol of choice such as asterisk, dagger, etc. For example, `\footnote[3]{buzz}` denotes the "double dagger".