# NewDocumentEnvironment with tcolorboxes and conditional typesetting

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, xparse

For the homeworks of my course I would like to create an `Exercise` environment for the  statement of problems (continuing with the idea presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510707/tcolorbox-and-footnote-marks)) and another `Answer` environment, which will only be typeset if the `AnsReq` `\newif` is `true`. Here goes a (no so minimal) MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp} %No indent wanted

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{boxsep=0pt,tcbox raise base}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter] {Exercise}[1][]{%
  before upper={
    \renewcommand\thempfootnote{\fnsymbol{mpfootnote}}
    {\makebox[2em][l]{\large\bf\thetcbcounter.~}}
    },#1
  }

\newif\ifAnsReq                     %If it's true, then typeset answers 
\NewDocumentEnvironment { Answer }
  { +b }
  { \ifAnsReq
    \tcbox[colupper=blue!50!black]{\sc Answer:}\par
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,colframe=white]
      {#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \fi
  }
  {}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,quotes,arrows.meta,positioning}
\tikzset{baseline=(current bounding box.center),>=Latex,
  ampersand replacement=\&,                                %Must use this!
  }

\begin{document}
\AnsReqtrue %comment if don't want to typeset the answer

\begin{Exercise}[label={ej:1}]
  An exercise\footnote{This is the footnote} with a footnote.
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer}
  The answer:
  \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix[
        every node/.style={
        circle,draw,fill,inner sep=1.5pt},
        row sep=2.5em,
        column sep=2.5em
      ] {
        \node (one)  {}; \& \node (two) {}; \\
        };
        \path (one) edge (two);
        \node[left=0pt of one] {$1$};
        \node[right=0pt of two] {$2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \]
\end{Answer} 

\begin{Exercise}
    Another exercise (see \textbf{exercise \ref{ej:1}}).
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Answer} I don't know anything about \TeX! \end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

The typeset without `Answer`:
[image: No answer typeset]

Setting `AnsReq` to `true` answers are printed:
[image: Answers typeset]
Although the code shown performs the proposed task, I think it has some drawback, for example, the `ampersand replacement` option in a`tikz` matrix is necessary (see, for example: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer/15096#15096)). I would like to know if it is possible to develop these ideas in a more elegant way and without the mentioned inconveniences.

Comment: It is hard to answer this because it is not so clear what "in a more elegant way" means. One thing you could do is to make the `ampersand replacement` local, i.e. only apply it to the answer, and so avoid using it globally.

Comment: Do you need to toggle the value of `\ifAnsReq` in the document or is it a global value?

Comment: Hello @Schrödinger's cat and @egreg! Your comments are welcome.  Maybe I'm just looking for the feeling of "being doing things right". I guess the idea of writing exercises and answers in the same document should be very common in teaching work and I was wondering if there will be a kind of "standard way" to implement it in the TeX/LaTeX world. By the way, it would be possible to write a conditional Answer environment without the need of "wrapping" its body, and therefore avoiding the use of "ampersand replacement"?

Comment: egreg: `\ifAnsReq` is local to my homeworks and exams documents.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat: Sometimes I need to enunciate exercises that contains tikz matrices, so the "ampersand replacement" must be global.

Comment: BTW: you are aware of https://ctan.org/topic/exercise and https://ctan.org/topic/exam , arent't you? I'd use https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim but I'm biased…

Comment: @clemens: I have dived superficially into `exam` package. I had no idea of the existence of an `exercise` package (and I wonder why I haven't looked for it before). Thank you very much for your hint. However, I doubt that any of them can adapt to my "typographical whims", but I did say that I wanted to find a standard way to carry out these tasks...

Comment: Wow! I'd realized that you are the author of `xsim`. I promise you (and me) that I will take a look at this.

Comment: @Patone I haven't linked to the `exam` and `exercise` packages but to the topics on CTAN. There are a lot more packages...

Comment: @clemens: Yes, I realized that. Anyway, I'm reading the `xsim` documentation right now, it looks very close to what I was looking for. I have to keep you updated on my progress.