# Package to fit pages around chapters

Tags: geometry

Is there a package that would adjust the geometry of each page of a LaTeX document to contain all material up to the next explicit pagebreak? (ideally this would make pages contain entire sections, or semantic units, or so) 
Of course this would be strictly for on-screen reading (possibly very long pages with uneven length but fixed width), but it could be interesting to experiment with.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144940/how-to-change-the-page-height-on-current-page-so-as-to-include-each-section-in-o

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/is-there-a-way-to-make-page-size-match-document-length

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! that looks perfect!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments by giving two links. The op did not mention which one solved it for her/him ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make "page" size match document length?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49686/is-there-a-way-to-make-page-size-match-document-length)