# how to get mathematical equations into image in latex?

Tags: graphics, equations, pdftex

how to get mathematical equations into image in latex? I want the code that convert all equations into image in the pdf file after compile the tex file.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to extract all equations from the PDF into separate image files?  Can you give a concrete example of what you would like to be able to do?

Comment: When we compile a tex file, the out put file normally pdf file and in that pdf file all equations becomes images and rest of them normal text.

Comment: Why do you want that? At the end do you want single pdf file (still)?

Comment: Just to rephrase to make sure I understand: when you compile your document, some equations are output as raster images and some are output 'normally' as pure PDF?

Comment: Yes I required as a single pdf file that contains the equations as images and other as normal text.

Comment: Can you post some code that illustrates this? How are you compiling? Using `pdflatex`?

Comment: Related/duplicate(s): [What document class should I use for a variable size image generator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51626/5764); [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866/5764)

Comment: There is a simple solution. Just use tex4ht. It compiles each equation to one .png file.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could write a package that compiles equations in subjobs, like so (call this package `imageeqn.sty`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{imageeqn}[2014/11/30 v0.1 Image equations]

\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newwrite\@out
\newcounter{imageeqn}

\begingroup \catcode `|=0 \catcode `[=1
\catcode`]=2 \catcode `\{=12 \catcode `\}=12
\catcode`\\=12 |gdef|@ximageeqn#1\end{imageeqn}[|immediate|write|@out[#1]|end[imageeqn]]
|endgroup

\def\imageeqn{\kernel@ifnextchar [{\@imageeqn}{\@imageeqn[]}}

\def\@imageeqn[#1]{%
\stepcounter{imageeqn}
\immediate\openout\@out=\jobname-eqn-\arabic{imageeqn}.tex
\immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\documentclass[convert={density=288,outext=.png}]{standalone}}
\immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\usepackage{amsmath}}
\immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\begin{document}}
\immediate\write\@out{\noexpand$}
\newlinechar='15
\begingroup \catcode`\^^M=12 %
\let\do\@makeother\dospecials\obeyspaces%
\@ximageeqn}

\def\endimageeqn{%
\endgroup%
\immediate\write\@out{\noexpand$}
\immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\end{document}}
\immediate\closeout\@out
\immediate\write18{pdflatex --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode \jobname-eqn-\arabic{imageeqn}.tex}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{\jobname-eqn-\arabic{imageeqn}.png}
\end{center}}
```

This package (which I wrote by modifying `python.sty`) defines an environment `imageeqn`, which takes the equation inside of it, generates a tex file, compiles it to png, and then includes the resulting png using `\includegraphics`. This can be used as follows (let's call this file `image.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imageeqn}

\begin{document}
Pythagorean theorem:
\begin{imageeqn}x^2 + y^2 = z^2.\end{imageeqn}
Some integral:
\begin{imageeqn}\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-x} \, dx.\end{imageeqn}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with the command line:

```
pdflatex --enable-write18 image.tex
```

The result is a pdf file that has the two equations embedded as rasterized images. I'm not sure why you would ever want to do this, but I enjoyed myself trying to figure out how to do this anyway :)

This implementation is pretty limited by the way: first of all, it won't compile if you put `\end{imageeqn}` on a new line. Second of all, it turns equations into text-style math (in dollar signs), so equation numbering, aligning, etc., are not supported.

**Solving the newline problem**

The first problem can be fixed, at least on Linux, by preprocessing the subjobs with `sed`. This can be done by replacing:

```
\immediate\write18{pdflatex --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode \jobname-eqn-\arabic{imageeqn}.tex}
```

in the above code by:

```
\immediate\write18{sed -i '/^$/d' \jobname-eqn-\arabic{imageeqn}.tex; pdflatex --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode \jobname-eqn-\arabic{imageeqn}.tex}
```

**Using preprocessing to make `\[`, `\begin{equation}` work**

Making `\[`, `\]`, `\begin{equation}`, `\end{equation}` work can be done by preprocessing the input with `sed`:

```
cat input.tex | sed 's|\\\[|\begin{imageeqn}|g' \
              | sed 's|\\\]|\end{imageeqn}|g' \
              | sed 's|\\begin{equation}|\begin{imageeqn}|g' \
              | sed 's|\\end{equation}|\end{imageeqn}|g' \
              > input2.tex
pdflatex --enable-write18 input2.tex
```

Perhaps `lualatex` may be of help here, but I don't know anything about that.

Comment: consider the following code: \documentclass{report}

\begin{document}


\[x^2 + y^2 = z^2.\]

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-x} \, dx.
\end{equation}

$\mathbb{U}$

\end{document}                                                   I need that when compile the above, output in the form of pdf file and all the equations are as images in the pdf file.

Comment: @Suresh: The above code provides a starting point. Since your question is quite specific (and to be honest: I don't understand why you would want this), I'm afraid you're going to have to tweak the code to make it work for your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I cooked up another answer. The following second version of the package `imageeqn.sty` reimplements the `equation` environment, the `\[`, `\]`, `\(`, `\)` environments, and inline math between dollar signs.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{imageeqn}[2014/11/30 v0.2 Image equations]

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{pgf}

\newcommand\ie@resolution{288}
\pgfmathsetmacro\ie@scale{72/\ie@resolution}

\newwrite\@out
\newcounter{ie@subjob}

% -- open subjob and write preamble
\def\ie@open{%
  \stepcounter{ie@subjob}%
  \immediate\openout\@out=\jobname-eqn-\arabic{ie@subjob}.tex%
  \immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\documentclass[convert={density=\ie@resolution,outext=.png}]{standalone}}%
  \immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\usepackage{amsmath}}%
  \immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\begin{document}}%
  \immediate\write\@out{\noexpand$}%
}

% -- close current subjob
\def\ie@close{%
  \immediate\write\@out{\noexpand$}%
  \immediate\write\@out{\noexpand\end{document}}%
  \immediate\closeout\@out%
} 

% -- compile and insert current subjob
\def\ie@emit{%
  \immediate\write18{pdflatex --enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode \jobname-eqn-\arabic{ie@subjob}.tex}%
  \includegraphics[scale=\ie@scale]{\jobname-eqn-\arabic{ie@subjob}.png}%
} 

% -- define \inlineimageeqn command
\newcommand\inlineimageeqn[1]{%
  \ie@open%
  \immediate\write\@out{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \ie@close%
  \ie@emit%  
}

% -- redefine 'equation' environment
\RenewEnviron{equation}{%
  \begin{center}
    \ie@open%
    \immediate\write\@out{\BODY}%
    \ie@close%
    \ie@emit%
  \end{center}}

% -- redefine '\[ \]' environment
\def\[#1\]{\begin{center}\inlineimageeqn{#1}\end{center}}

% -- redefine '\( \)' environment
\def\(#1\){\begin{center}\inlineimageeqn{#1}\end{center}}

% -- refine inline math
\catcode`\$=13
\def$#1${\inlineimageeqn{#1}}
```

The following simple example illustrates its use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imageeqn}

\begin{document}
Pythagorean theorem for $x$, $y$, and $z$:
\[
x^2 + y^2 = z^2.
\]
Some integral:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-x} \, dx.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to `barbara beeton` whose answer in [Remove all math for spelling and grammar checking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191215/remove-all-math-for-spelling-and-grammar-checking) inspired this approach.

Comment: I got the pdf file for the above code, but only the image box is displayed and no equation is inside.

Comment: @Suresh: It works fine on my system. Are you compiling with the `--enable-write18` flag? Are you using the latest texlive? Do the generated png files look ok?