# Cannot set pixel density in standalone package for PNG output

Tags: standalone, png

I want to output a PNG image with the `standalone` package. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[preview, convert={density=300}]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    Hello world
\end{document}
```

When I inspect the file properties of the resulting PNG file, I still get 72 dpi. Even without using the `preview` option, it's still at 72 dpi. However, if I convert to JPG using `convert={density=300, outext=.jpg}`, I'd get 300 dpi.

How can this be fixed? My particular requirement would be to use the `preview` option and use the PNG image format.

Comment: If I set `density=600` in the options, I get `PNG image data, 415 x 58` which is twice as the `208 x 29` that you get from the original input. The typeset "Hello world" is 50.02786pt wide, which corresponds to 0.69224in; 300*0.69224=207.672 that justifies the 208 pixels (and also the 415 at 600dpi).

Comment: Please check if `standalone` is using Image Magick or Ghostscript internally. Image Magick is the default under Linux if installed. See the manual section 4.6.2
*Conversion software* for more details. Also please state your `standalone` version, your LaTeX distribution and your OS.

Comment: @egreg: Could you recheck with the `ghostscript` option also set. I guess the installation of the OP uses Ghostscript which might cause the issue.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I get the same result with `ghostscript`: `\documentclass[preview, convert={ghostscript,density=300}]{standalone}` gives `PNG image data, 208 x 29, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced`

Comment: @MartinScharrer With the `ghostscript` option set, even my image viewer does agree about the density.

Answer (score 3):

The package manual states that “the following default settings are used: PNG format, a density of 300dpi, no explicit size […].”

So there's no surprise that `density=300` doesn't result in a different output.

I wouldn't trust the “file properties” of the resulting file. How should a picture viewer (or your OS) know what an inch is? It's just pixels at the output side now.

Consider the following example where I typeset a black 1 inch by 1 inch square.

The output `.png` is 300 pixels by 300 pixels.

### Code

```
\documentclass[
    preview,
    convert% uses default settings: density=300 and png
]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \rule{1in}{1in}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

To complement egreg's comment:

### Code

```
\documentclass[preview,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{printlen}\uselengthunit{in}
\newlength{\myWidth} \newlength{\myHeight}
\sbox0{Hello world}
\setlength{\myWidth}{\wd0}\setlength{\myHeight}{\ht0}
\begin{document}
\printlength\myWidth${}\times{}$\printlength\myHeight\ (\the\wd0 ${}\times{}$\the\ht0)
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Could you recheck with the `ghostscript` option also set. I guess the installation of the OP uses Ghostscript which might cause the issue. See also my comment to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and discovered that the convert command was ignoring the density setting unless I explicitly set the units. That is, the command

```
convert -density 300 foo.pdf foo.png
```

produces a png file at 72 dpi, but the command

```
convert -density 300 -units pixelsperinch foo.pdf foo.png
```

produces a png file at 300 dpi. So I suspect the problem is not with standalone but with the ImageMagick settings. I gave up at this point and simply created an AUCTeX command that issues the correct shell command to the pdf file after it has been LaTeXed, but this may provide a hint for someone else.

If you want to try the solution using AucTeX, customize Tex Command List in AUCTeX and add a command that runs

```
 mogrify -density 300 -units pixelsperinch -format png %P
```