# Conversion problem using standalone and imagemagick

Tags: errors, conversion, standalone

I'm trying to convert a table to png format using Imagemagick

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,border=8pt,convert=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{binary-units = true,
         table-format=7.0}

\begin{document}

    \minipage{1.08\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1.0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=6.0]
            S[table-format=6.0]
            S[table-format=6.0]
            SSS}
        \toprule
        Device & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 & 2015 & 2016 \\
        \midrule
        Non-smarthphones & 22686 & 55813 & 108750 & 196262 & 357797 & 615679 \\
        Smarthphones & 104759 & 365550 & 933373 & 1915173 & 3257030 & 5221497 \\
        Laptops e Netbooks & 373831 & 612217 & 917486 & 1340062 & 1963950 & 2617770\\
        Tablets & 17393 & 63181 & 141153 & 300519 & 554326 & 1083895\\
        Home gateways & 55064 & 108073 & 180562 & 267545 & 376494 & 514777 \\
        M2M & 23009 & 47144 & 92150 & 172719 & 302279 & 508022 \\
        Altri devices & 525 & 1460 & 5429 & 22966 & 84204 & 242681\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof*{table}{Traffico mobile globale al mese per dispositivo in \si{\tera\byte}}
    \endminipage

\end{document}
```

Here it is the table create using `standalone` package. I read the documentation and it says to use ImageMagick. The problem is when I compile it doesn't find the exacutable `imgconvert.exe`. So I put this exacutable into folder where there is tex file. Now when I compile I got another error:

```
imgconvert.exe: `%s' (%d) "gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE 
-dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dEPSCrop -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 
"-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300" 
"-sOutputFile=C:/Users/MAZZAR~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-31681PKeFVHE065o" 
"-fC:/Users/MAZZAR~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-3168A-Fab6j3iIUc" 
"-fC:/Users/MAZZAR~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-3168QXzuvG_UAP07" 
@ error/utility.c/SystemCommand/1890. imgconvert.exe: Postscript delegate failed 
`table.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/678.
imgconvert.exe: no images defined `table.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3066.
```

Comment: `convert` is also the MS tool for FAT to NTFS conversion of harddrives, therefore the recommendation is to rename Image Magick's `convert.exe` to `imgconvert.exe`. In order not to be blamed for any data loss due to my `standalone` package (even if this is very unlikly) I put the default executable name to `imgeconvert`. This can be change using the `convert={convertexe={convert.exe}}` class option. This all is also described in detail in the [`standalone` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/standalone).

Comment: I don't recognise the error you get, but I didn't tested `standalone` much under MS Windows. I developed it under Linux and there it works well. I fixed some quoting issues with Windows, one actually very recently. Maybe there is a similar issue here. I will try to debug this at my Windows machine soon.

Comment: Also, bugs with `standalone` should be reported to the [package bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues). (There is one for each of my packages.) Bug reports should not be posted here, see [Questions which are bug reports](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2622/2975) on Meta for the discussion about it.

Answer (score 17):

First, about the trouble with the executable name:

`convert` is also the MS tool for FAT to NTFS conversion of hard disk drives, therefore the recommendation is to rename Image Magick's `convert.exe` to `imgconvert.exe`. In order not to be blamed for any data loss due to my `standalone` package (even if this is very unlikely) I put the default executable name to `imgconvert`. This can be change using the `convert={convertexe={convert.exe}}` class option.
This all is also described in detail in the [`standalone` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/standalone).

I would recommend Windows users to either rename or copy the `convert.exe` file to `imgconvert.exe` or change the `standalone.cfg` file to include:

```
 \standaloneconfig{convert={convertexe={convert.exe},false}}
```

---

Now to the error message you get:

I tried this under Windows and found out that it depends on the version of Image Magick. With v6.6.9 I get the same error. Here it doesn't matter if it is called from `standalone` or manually from the command line. However with v6.8.1 I just downloaded today from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) it works without any issues (after selecting the right executable name as mentioned above).
It seems there is an issue with PDF using v6.6.9 and maybe other versions after it before v6.8.1.

Therefore the fix for your problem is to update Image Magick. If this doesn't fix your issue, or if you already have v6.8.1 installed, then please post the used version number here. Also try to convert it manually using the command line
`convert.exe -density 300 file.pdf  -quality 90 file.png`. If this also throws the same error it isn't an issue with `standalone` but only with ImageMagick.

Comment: Please, is `imgeconvert` a misspell of `imgconvert` or not?

Comment: @yo': Sorry, yes I misspelled that one. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you that "gswin32c.exe" cannot be found.
Install Ghostscript and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: I assume you're following some advice from the highly-upvoted answer in [Convert: Postscript delegate failed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9783216/914686)...

Answer (score 3):

For some reasons, I too get the same error and was never able to use standalone directly for conversion (I am on windows). It is because the name of the executable is simply `convert.exe` whereas the standalone searches for `imgconvert.exe`. `:-(` I just took a copy of `convert.exe` and renamed it as `imgconvert.exe` and put it back in the installation folder of `imagemagick`. Then your code works fine.

If it is not working for you, then the most possible reason (as is evident from your error report) is *the `imgconvert.exe` is not in the system's path as a result of which it is not found*. Try to add it to your system path or reinstall `imagemagick` (while doing that it will ask you whether you want to add it to the path).

Here is another method to get png files. But for this also `convert.exe` (here only `convert.exe`) must be in system's path. Otherwise this won't work!

(Compile with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.tex}
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,border=8pt,convert=true]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{binary-units = true,
         table-format=7.0}

\begin{document}

    \minipage{1.08\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1.0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=6.0]
            S[table-format=6.0]
            S[table-format=6.0]
            SSS}
        \toprule
        Device & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 & 2015 & 2016 \\
        \midrule
        Non-smarthphones & 22686 & 55813 & 108750 & 196262 & 357797 & 615679 \\
        Smarthphones & 104759 & 365550 & 933373 & 1915173 & 3257030 & 5221497 \\
        Laptops e Netbooks & 373831 & 612217 & 917486 & 1340062 & 1963950 & 2617770\\
        Tablets & 17393 & 63181 & 141153 & 300519 & 554326 & 1083895\\
        Home gateways & 55064 & 108073 & 180562 & 267545 & 376494 & 514777 \\
        M2M & 23009 & 47144 & 92150 & 172719 & 302279 & 508022 \\
        Altri devices & 525 & 1460 & 5429 & 22966 & 84204 & 242681\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof*{table}{Traffico mobile globale al mese per dispositivo in \si{\tera\byte}}
    \endminipage
\end{document}  
\end{filecontents*}
% compile with pdflatex
\immediate\write18{pdflatex --shell-escape mytable}
% convert to PNG
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 500 -alpha on mytable.pdf mytable-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
Check the folder for your \verb|mytable-00.png| file.
\end{document}
```

Your code is in between `\begin{filecontents*}` and `\end{filecontents*}`. You must have `imagemagick` installed and the executable should be in the system path for this to work.

Comment: I pasted your code and runned it. It works but no file png has been created. I put in the same folder of tex file imgconvert.exe. This is the result in the log: LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./mytable.tex'.

\openout15 = `mytable.tex'.


LaTeX Warning: Tab has been converted to Blank Space.


runsystem(pdflatex --shell-escape mytable)...disabled (restricted).

runsystem(convert -density 500 -alpha on mytable.pdf mytable-%02d.png)...disabl
ed (restricted).

Comment: I download imagemagick and installed it. After I renamed the exacutable to imgconvert.exe and put in the same folder of main tex file. When I execute no error appear but I got this warning that don't let me have png file. I checked the rights and I think I have access correctly

Comment: I have to include shell-escape to pdflatex?

Comment: Yes I got that big list...but It still doesn't work

Comment: @Mazzy Check if imagemagick is in system's path. See the edit.

Comment: By default, the command called by `standalone` on Windows is `imgconvert` because on some versions of Windows `convert` is a program that deals with file systems. You can specify the conversion program with the option `convertexe=convert` (be sure it's the right program).

Comment: Simply copying the convert.exe to your tex folder won't do the trick, since it then won't be able to find its libraries. You really have to add it to the system path.

Comment: Note that this is basically what `standalone` does internally. Only it uses `imgconvert` by default for reasons explained in the manual. However this solution results in the same error as the original for me. I also get the same error if I call `convert` in the command line myself. The reason lies with ImageMagick and disappeared after updating it. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a minimal example of how to compile a `.tex` file into a PNG file using TeX Live on Windows 10. First of all, save the following `tex` code in a file called `mini.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt, border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
Blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

`mini.tex` can be compiled into a PDF and then converted to a PNG image file with Tex Live on Windows 10 using the following `powershell` commands:

```
pdflatex mini.tex
$env:GS_LIB="C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/tlgs/Resource/Init;C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/tlgs/lib;C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/tlgs/kanji"
C:/texlive/2022/tlpkg/tlgs/bin/gswin32c.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile="mini.png" mini.pdf
```

- The `$env:GS_LIB=...` command above only needs to be used once per terminal session, in order to set the `GS_LIB` environment variable, so that `gswin32c` knows where to find the files `gs_init.ps`, `cidfmap`, and `kfwin32.ps` respectively
- The path names in this command as well as the full path of `gswin32c.exe` may need to modified depending on the location of these files in a given installation of Tex Live
- Alternatively (IE instead of setting the `GS_LIB` environment variable) these paths can be included in the `gswin32c.exe` command (without needing to first set any environment variables) by specifying the `-I` flag individually before each path ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876349/8477566))
- The double quotes around `mini.png` appear to be necessary to prevent `gswin32c` returning the error `Error: /undefinedfilename in (.png)`
- Building `mini.tex` into `mini.pdf` and then converting this into `mini.png` with the commands shown above successfully produces the the following image:

[image: mini.png]

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue today.

Changing `convert` in the `\documentclass` setting to `magick` can solve it.

Change the tex file from

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,border=8pt,convert=true]{standalone}
...
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

to

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,border=8pt,magick=true]{standalone}
...
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add the full answer. If it is ever promoted to the top answer, then it's easier for people to work from a complete answer instead of scraping together from multiple answers.