How to export (and import) latex tables to Illustrator?
I have been working on the figures of my research paper. I have used Latex to create visually and aesthetically pleasing tables. They look quite good, however, I couldn't find a good way to upload these tables into illustrator without compromising the quality of the tables.
I have tried to import the pdf files as pdf, eps, png, and I encountered a different issue each time. With pdf embedding illustrator shows missing font errors. Uploading these fonts didn't help. With eps, it automatically distorts tables. And as png, tables get pixelated.
Is there a way to solve this issue? Although it would be great, I don't mind if I cannot edit the tables on Illustrator at this point.
Can I download the tables as png, or tiff files? I used overleaf to get my tables done, so I could only download them as pdf file.

Welcome to TeX.SE! You could convert your PDF into PNG https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419536/how-to-convert-pdf-file-to-image-in-latex-file
