# Compiling snippets without extra clutter

Tags: amsmath, dvi, svg

Assuming that I have some equations in latex

```
A_{m,n} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,n}
 \end{pmatrix}
```

Can I compile this into a dvi file or svg path without adding extra code or extra clutter ? I would just like to set the font size, that's all, I would like to feed this code to latex and get a single image not just a whole document that is automatically fitting the given math equation.

Comment: @cmhughes I don't think so

Comment: then please edit your question to clarify what it is that you want. Because in my interpretation of your question, the [accepted answer to the linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11880/21344) would work for your needs too.

Comment: @PaulGessler that answer suggests to add the usual `\documentclass<...>` and `\begin<..>` tags, that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I don't have documents, I have math equations written using the tex syntax .

Comment: If you truly cannot add anything to this snippet, I think [command-line MathJax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440296/how-to-use-mathjax-from-command-line) is your best option. Because if you wanted to use this code with LaTeX, you'd need (at minimum) `\usepackage{amsmath}` (for the `pmatrix` environment), which would then require a `\documentclass{<...>}` (for the `\usepackage{<...>}`).

Comment: @PaulGessler did you managed to get that working ? Because it's listed as experimental and it doesn't even work with some entities like matrices and symbols like the `+` sign.

Comment: Nope, I've not tested any of that. But that's the only option I can see if you're unwilling/unable to use a document class and/or packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have code of equation in `equation.tex`, then it can be compiled using command:

```
pdflatex  '\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} $\input{equation}$ \end{document}'
```

You can also create a custom shell/batch file that will compile a file given a parameter.

Comment: I must confess that I don't see how this approach is supposed to be either simpler or more parsimonious than providing the four simple instructions `\documentclass{standalone}`, `\usepackage{amsmath}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` inside the .tex file that contains the equation of interest. I guess you're not actually claiming it's simpler or more parsimonious...

Comment: @Mico You have the advantage when you have many files with equations. Adding simple 5 lines N times over can be tiring.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that steals from one of the answers to [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document)

The command `pdflatex wrapper myequation` produces a pdf with just

[image]

with this `wrapper.tex`

```
\def\ReadCommandLineArg#1 {%
  \def\CommandLineArg{#1}%
  \input{\jobname}}
\unless\ifdefined\CommandLineArg
\endinput\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ReadCommandLineArg\fi

\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty} % suppress page number
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\input{\CommandLineArg}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

and your `myequation.tex`

```
A_{m,n} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\
  a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n} \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  a_{m,1} & a_{m,2} & \cdots & a_{m,n}
 \end{pmatrix}
```

If there's more white space than you want in the pdf you can crop it with `pdfcrop`.

I don't know what you mean by "set the font size". You could probably tinker with this idea to make it do that.

**Edit:** to crop automatically, use the standalone package with `$...$` instead of the `equation*` environment, as in the other answer.

```
\def\ReadCommandLineArg#1 {%
  \def\CommandLineArg{#1}%
  \input{\jobname}}
\unless\ifdefined\CommandLineArg
\endinput\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ReadCommandLineArg\fi

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\input{\CommandLineArg}$
\end{document}
```

And, answering a question you haven't asked, but that may come up, you can have multiple aligned equations if you use `aligned` and not `align`:

```
\begin{aligned}
e^{i\pi} & = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi) \\
& = -1 
\end{aligned}
```

Comment: I haven't picked this solution because the output of the other command is already cropped, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Of course automatic cropping is better. See the edit above, using the `standalone` package. Now you can use either solution.