# Convert pdf image to png. TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, png

I'm making a small automata with TiKZ and I need to convert it to a png without having all the empty space around. Right now I get a whole page but I only want the automata.

I have followed the instructions from this link but I couldn't make it work.
[Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible/11880#11880)

My original code:

```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=6cm,on grid,auto]

  \node[state,initial] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
  \node[state,accepting](q_3) [right=of q_0] {$q_3$};

  \path[->] 
  (q_0) edge              node {bb+(a+ba)(ab)*(a+bb)} (q_3);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the link uses the [`standalone` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone), while you're just using `article`. Add `\pagestyle{empty}` to your preamble, followed by a `pdfcrop` call and use the suggested ImageMagik `convert` sequence to take the output PDF into PNG.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `standalone` class with `tikz` option.

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

  \usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=6cm,on grid,auto]

  \node[state,initial] (q_0)   {$q_0$}; 
  \node[state,accepting](q_3) [right=of q_0] {$q_3$};

  \path[->] 
  (q_0) edge              node {bb+(a+ba)(ab)*(a+bb)} (q_3);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked but for some reason L=2 appears at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: Have you changed your example? Otherwise, this should not be able to appear.

Comment: No it's the exact same code you gave me. Also the page-nr "1" is there as well.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. Copy the code from my answer and test it. There shouldn't any page numbers appear.

Comment: I did that but now it doesn't work at all. I use this command in the terminal: `convert -density 300 third.pdf -quality 200 3.png`

Comment: @user59272 Does the PDF appear correctly and the conversion do something odd? Or does your PDF not appear correctly? I suspect you are talking at cross purposes here. There are 2 distinct steps and you need to be clear which one is not working for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did when it worked but the code in my post correctly creates a pdf with the command `pdflatex third.tex`. Then I want to convert that into a png. When I use user SLx64's code to create a pdf I get the following error-message: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./third.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.cls' not found.`

Comment: @user59272 This error means you don't have `standalone` class instaled. You don't need it if you follow Werner suggestions: 1.- insert `\pagestyle{empty}` in your code. 2.- compile with `pdflatex`. 3.- Use `pdfcrop` to reduce white space. 4- Convert to png.