# Convert Tex File into an image

Tags: graphics, png

I would like to know what do I have to do if I want to convert the my Tex document into an image. 
I'm new to Latex World, sorry if it is a dumb question for somebody

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. To clarify, do you mean an image or do you mean compile the document to a the final output?

Comment: if you mean "image" such that it can be embedded into another document, is the document you want to convert just one page, or multiple pages?

Comment: I mean an image. Right know when I compile the code I get some files inluding a pdf document. My intention is to transform the text document into an image in order to copy it to Word.

Comment: I mean just one page.

Comment: Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866/17423 helps?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to comment but what exactly you are talking about? You want to convert a 1 page Tex document to image? Simply you can build as pdf and then convert pdf to images with many free tools.

Comment: Okey but I heard there is an easier method using directly the latex compiler to transform it into an image

Comment: Check [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible) then. You can do that in the `\documentclass`

Comment: If it's one page `.pdf` document, you can include it anyway as image or using `pdfpages` package anyway. There is no need to convert to another image format again

Answer (score 1):

You must have ImageMagick installed. The following simulates everything you need to generated images  from your TeX input file.

```
% filename.tex
% compile it with
% pdflatex -shell-escape filename.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{pdflatex main.tex}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 100 main.pdf main-\@percentchar d.png }
\makeatother

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,scale=0.5,controls]{5}{main-}{0}{19}
\end{document}
```