# How to re-center a "standalone" TikZ image to be converted to png

Tags: tikz-pgf

I’m trying to construct png icons following the method explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible/11880#11880).
 Below is an example file that needs to be adjusted because part of the border is eaten up (all the upper part and the very end of the rightmost part).
How should I fix this ?

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=4600x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% "Nouveau" in green f=23/4

 \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
 % Proportionality constants
  \newcommand*{\jay}{0.25}%
  \newcommand*{\kay}{2}%
 \newcommand*{\hay}{3}%
 \newcommand*{\way}{4}%
  \newcommand*{\bay}{3.5}%
 % Fundamental coordinates of points or vectors
  \newcommand*{\xv}{-0.5*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\yv}{2*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\xfive}{0*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\yfive}{0*\jay}%
  % Deduced coordinates
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xu}{\bay*\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yu}{-\bay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xsix}{\xfive+\way*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ysix}{\yfive+\way*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xten}{\xfive+2*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yten}{\yfive+2*\yv}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xeleven}{\xten+\way*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yeleven}{\yten+\way*\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xone}{\xsix+\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yone}{\ysix+\yv}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwo}{\xone+\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwo}{\yone+\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xthree}{\xtwo+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ythree}{\ytwo+\kay*\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwentytwo}{\xtwo-\hay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwentytwo}{\ytwo-\hay*\yv}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwentythree}{\xtwentytwo+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwentythree}{\ytwentytwo+\kay*\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xseventeen}{\xtwentytwo-\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yseventeen}{\ytwentytwo-\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xeighteen}{\xseventeen+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yeighteen}{\yseventeen+\kay*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xseven}{\xtwo+\hay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yseven}{\ytwo+\hay*\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xeight}{\xseven+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yeight}{\yseven+\kay*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwelve}{\xseven+\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwelve}{\yseven+\yv}% 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xthirteen}{\xtwelve+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ythirteen}{\ytwelve+\kay*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfour}{\xthree+\hay*\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfour}{\ythree-\hay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xnine}{\xfour+\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ynine}{\yfour-\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfourteen}{\xfive+\xv-\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfourteen}{\yfive+\xv+\yv}% 
  \coordinate (A1) at (\xone,\yone);
  \coordinate (A2) at (\xtwo,\ytwo);
  \coordinate (A3) at (\xthree,\ythree);
  \coordinate (A4) at (\xfour,\yfour);
  \coordinate (A5) at (\xfive,\yfive);
  \coordinate (A6) at (\xsix,\ysix);  
  \coordinate (A7) at (\xseven,\yseven);
  \coordinate (A8) at (\xeight,\yeight);  
  \coordinate (A9) at (\xnine,\ynine);   
  \coordinate (A10) at (\xten,\yten);    
\coordinate (A11) at (\xeleven,\yeleven);    
\coordinate (A12) at (\xtwelve,\ytwelve);    
\coordinate (A13) at (\xthirteen,\ythirteen);    
\coordinate (A14) at (\xfourteen,\yfourteen);    
\coordinate (A17) at (\xseventeen,\yseventeen);   
\coordinate (A18) at (\xeighteen,\yeighteen);   
\coordinate (A22) at (\xtwentytwo,\ytwentytwo);  
\coordinate (A23) at (\xtwentythree,\ytwentythree);    
  \fill[fill=green] (A14) -- (A5) -- (A6) -- (A11) -- (A10) -- cycle;
  \fill[fill=green] (A6) -- (A17) -- (A22) -- (A1) -- cycle;
  \fill[fill=green] (A17) -- (A18) -- (A23) -- (A22) -- cycle;
 \fill[fill=green] (A7) -- (A8) -- (A13) -- (A12) -- cycle;
 %\draw (A23) -- (A4) -- (A8);
% \draw (A23) .. controls (A14) .. (A4);
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\dee}{\hay*(veclen(\xv,\yv))}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\deetwo}{(\hay+1)*(veclen(\xv,\yv))}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\anglestart}{atan2(\xtwentythree-\xthree,\ytwentythree-\ythree)}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\angletarget}{atan2(\xeight-\xthree,\yeight-\ythree)}%
 \fill[fill=green]  (A23) arc (\anglestart:\angletarget:\dee) -- (A13) arc (\angletarget:\anglestart:\deetwo) -- (A23);
 %\draw[step=0.1cm,gray] (-1,0) grid (15,6);
  %\draw [step=1cm] (-1,0) grid (15,6);
\coordinate (C1) at (3.4,5);
\coordinate (C2) at (4,4);
\coordinate (C3) at (5,3.6);    
\coordinate (C4) at (6,4.5);    
\coordinate (C5) at (7,4.7);
\coordinate (C6) at (8,4);
\coordinate (C7) at (8.6,3);
\coordinate (C25) at (9,2.7);    
\coordinate (C8) at (10,2.4);    
\coordinate (C9) at (11,2.8);
\coordinate (C10) at (11.5,2);    
\coordinate (C11) at (12,1);
\coordinate (C12) at (12.4,0.3);   
\coordinate (C13) at (12.6,0.3);    
\coordinate (C14) at (12.2,1);    
\coordinate (C15) at (11.7,2);
\coordinate (C16) at (11,3.1);    
\coordinate (C17) at (10,2.6);
\coordinate (C18) at (9,2.9);    
\coordinate (C26) at (8.2,4);
\coordinate (C19) at (8,4.3);
\coordinate (C20) at (7,4.9);    
\coordinate (C21) at (6,4.7);
\coordinate (C22) at (5,3.8);   
\coordinate (C23) at (4,4.2);    
\coordinate (C24) at (3.6,5);   
\filldraw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates { (C1)  (C2)  (C3) (C4) (C5) (C6) (C7) (C25) (C8) (C9) (C10)  
(C11) (C12) (C13) (C14) (C15) (C16) (C17) (C18) (C26) (C19) (C20) (C21) (C22) (C23) (C24)};
 \fill[fill=green] (A1) -- (A7) -- (A12) -- (A11) -- cycle;
% \draw [step=0.1cm] (-28,-4) grid (16,12);
%\draw [step=1cm] (-28,-4) grid (16,12);
% \draw (0,0) node {$\bullet$};
 \draw (A5)++(-20,2.5) node[scale=3] {\sf\Huge\textcolor{green}{nouveau}};
  \newcommand*{\xzed}{-140*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\yzed}{-10*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\xzedtwo}{50*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\dusttwo}{20*\jay}%
 \coordinate (Z1) at (\xzed,\yzed);
 \coordinate (Z2) at (\xzedtwo,\yzed);
 \coordinate (Z3) at (\xzedtwo,\yzed+2*\dusttwo);
 \coordinate (Z4) at (\xzed,\yzed+2*\dusttwo);  
 \draw (Z1)  -- (Z2) arc(-90:90:\dusttwo) (Z3) -- (Z4) arc(90:270:\dusttwo) (Z1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: without `\pagestyle{empty}` and `\noindent` and using `convert` from command line in windows it works for me. Although the line surrounding the icon goes over the lamp(?).

Comment: Don't use `\sf`. It was deprecated 20 years ago. Use `\sffamily` or `\textsf{}` instead.

Comment: @Ignasi "the line surrounding the icon goes over the lamp" is precisely the problem I want to fix. It seems using \noindent or \pagestyle{empty} changes nothing about that

Comment: Was this code generated by another program?

Comment: @JohnKormylo This one wasn't, though I do use programs sometimes to generate some TikZ code

Comment: Therefore the problem is your `TiKZ` code and not `standalone`'s clipping capability.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

The main problem in your code was on last line

```
\draw (Z1)  -- (Z2) arc(-90:90:\dusttwo) (Z3) -- (Z4) arc(90:270:\dusttwo) (Z1) ;
```

the radius `\dusttwo` was to short, instead of `20*\jay` I've used `22*\jay` (adjust it according your taste). Your command draws two paths `(Z1)  -- (Z2) arc(-90:90:\dusttwo)` followed by `(Z3) -- (Z4) arc(90:270:\dusttwo) (Z1)`. There's no reason for such division, one path is enough:

```
 \draw (Z1)  -- (Z2) arc(-90:90:22*\jay) coordinate (aux) -- (aux-|Z1) arc(90:270:22*\jay);
```

Some other comments:

The code worked for me without `\usepackage{calc}` (don't confuse it with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`, which was neither not necessary)

If you use `standalone` class for an isolated `tikzpicture` there is no need for `\pagestyle{empty}` and `\noindent` which introduced a little shift in final result.

And, if you need it, you can also introduce a `border=...` option in `standalone` which will be considered before clipping the result. I've not used here, it's just information.

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=4600x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm,y=0.25cm]
 % Proportionality constants
  \newcommand*{\jay}{0.25}%
  \newcommand*{\kay}{2}%
 \newcommand*{\hay}{3}%
 \newcommand*{\way}{4}%
  \newcommand*{\bay}{3.5}%
 % Fundamental coordinates of points or vectors
  \newcommand*{\xv}{-0.5*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\yv}{2*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\xfive}{0*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\yfive}{0*\jay}%
  % Deduced coordinates
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xu}{\bay*\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yu}{-\bay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xsix}{\xfive+\way*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ysix}{\yfive+\way*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xten}{\xfive+2*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yten}{\yfive+2*\yv}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xeleven}{\xten+\way*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yeleven}{\yten+\way*\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xone}{\xsix+\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yone}{\ysix+\yv}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwo}{\xone+\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwo}{\yone+\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xthree}{\xtwo+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ythree}{\ytwo+\kay*\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwentytwo}{\xtwo-\hay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwentytwo}{\ytwo-\hay*\yv}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwentythree}{\xtwentytwo+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwentythree}{\ytwentytwo+\kay*\yu}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xseventeen}{\xtwentytwo-\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yseventeen}{\ytwentytwo-\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xeighteen}{\xseventeen+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yeighteen}{\yseventeen+\kay*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xseven}{\xtwo+\hay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yseven}{\ytwo+\hay*\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xeight}{\xseven+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yeight}{\yseven+\kay*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtwelve}{\xseven+\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytwelve}{\yseven+\yv}% 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xthirteen}{\xtwelve+\kay*\xu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ythirteen}{\ytwelve+\kay*\yu}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfour}{\xthree+\hay*\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfour}{\ythree-\hay*\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xnine}{\xfour+\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\ynine}{\yfour-\xv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfourteen}{\xfive+\xv-\yv}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfourteen}{\yfive+\xv+\yv}% 
  \coordinate (A1) at (\xone,\yone);
  \coordinate (A2) at (\xtwo,\ytwo);
  \coordinate (A3) at (\xthree,\ythree);
  \coordinate (A4) at (\xfour,\yfour);
  \coordinate (A5) at (\xfive,\yfive);
  \coordinate (A6) at (\xsix,\ysix);  
  \coordinate (A7) at (\xseven,\yseven);
  \coordinate (A8) at (\xeight,\yeight);  
  \coordinate (A9) at (\xnine,\ynine);   
  \coordinate (A10) at (\xten,\yten);    
\coordinate (A11) at (\xeleven,\yeleven);    
\coordinate (A12) at (\xtwelve,\ytwelve);    
\coordinate (A13) at (\xthirteen,\ythirteen);    
\coordinate (A14) at (\xfourteen,\yfourteen);    
\coordinate (A17) at (\xseventeen,\yseventeen);   
\coordinate (A18) at (\xeighteen,\yeighteen);   
\coordinate (A22) at (\xtwentytwo,\ytwentytwo);  
\coordinate (A23) at (\xtwentythree,\ytwentythree);    
  \fill[fill=green] (A14) -- (A5) -- (A6) -- (A11) -- (A10) -- cycle;
  \fill[fill=green] (A6) -- (A17) -- (A22) -- (A1) -- cycle;
  \fill[fill=green] (A17) -- (A18) -- (A23) -- (A22) -- cycle;
 \fill[fill=green] (A7) -- (A8) -- (A13) -- (A12) -- cycle;
 %\draw (A23) -- (A4) -- (A8);
% \draw (A23) .. controls (A14) .. (A4);
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\dee}{\hay*(veclen(\xv,\yv))}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\deetwo}{(\hay+1)*(veclen(\xv,\yv))}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\anglestart}{atan2(\xtwentythree-\xthree,\ytwentythree-\ythree)}%
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\angletarget}{atan2(\xeight-\xthree,\yeight-\ythree)}%
 \fill[fill=green]  (A23) arc (\anglestart:\angletarget:\dee) -- (A13) arc (\angletarget:\anglestart:\deetwo) -- (A23);
 %\draw[step=0.1cm,gray] (-1,0) grid (15,6);
  %\draw [step=1cm] (-1,0) grid (15,6);
\coordinate (C1) at (3.4,5);
\coordinate (C2) at (4,4);
\coordinate (C3) at (5,3.6);    
\coordinate (C4) at (6,4.5);    
\coordinate (C5) at (7,4.7);
\coordinate (C6) at (8,4);
\coordinate (C7) at (8.6,3);
\coordinate (C25) at (9,2.7);    
\coordinate (C8) at (10,2.4);    
\coordinate (C9) at (11,2.8);
\coordinate (C10) at (11.5,2);    
\coordinate (C11) at (12,1);
\coordinate (C12) at (12.4,0.3);   
\coordinate (C13) at (12.6,0.3);    
\coordinate (C14) at (12.2,1);    
\coordinate (C15) at (11.7,2);
\coordinate (C16) at (11,3.1);    
\coordinate (C17) at (10,2.6);
\coordinate (C18) at (9,2.9);    
\coordinate (C26) at (8.2,4);
\coordinate (C19) at (8,4.3);
\coordinate (C20) at (7,4.9);    
\coordinate (C21) at (6,4.7);
\coordinate (C22) at (5,3.8);   
\coordinate (C23) at (4,4.2);    
\coordinate (C24) at (3.6,5);   
\filldraw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates { (C1)  (C2)  (C3) (C4) (C5) (C6) (C7) (C25) (C8) (C9) (C10)  
(C11) (C12) (C13) (C14) (C15) (C16) (C17) (C18) (C26) (C19) (C20) (C21) (C22) (C23) (C24)};
 \fill[fill=green] (A1) -- (A7) -- (A12) -- (A11) -- cycle;
% \draw [step=0.1cm] (-28,-4) grid (16,12);
%\draw [step=1cm] (-28,-4) grid (16,12);
% \draw (0,0) node {$\bullet$};
 \draw (A5)++(-20,2.5) node[scale=3] {\sf\Huge\textcolor{green}{nouveau}};
  \newcommand*{\xzed}{-140*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\yzed}{-10*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\xzedtwo}{50*\jay}%
  \newcommand*{\dusttwo}{20*\jay}%
 \coordinate (Z1) at (\xzed,\yzed);
 \coordinate (Z2) at (\xzedtwo,\yzed);
 \coordinate (Z3) at (\xzedtwo,\yzed+2*\dusttwo);
 \coordinate (Z4) at (\xzed,\yzed+2*\dusttwo);  
% \draw (Z1)  -- (Z2) arc(-90:90:\dusttwo) (Z3) -- (Z4) arc(90:270:\dusttwo) (Z1) ;
 \draw (Z1)  -- (Z2) arc(-90:90:22*\jay) coordinate (aux) -- (aux-|Z1) arc(90:270:22*\jay);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```