# Subequations with varioref and cleverref

Tags: hyperref, amsmath, cleveref, varioref

Can somebody tell me why the references don't work in this example?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Some group of equations:
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        f(x) &= x \label{eq1} \\
        g(x) &= x+1 \label{eq2} \\
        h(x) &= x+2 \label{eq3} \\
        k(x) &= x+3 \label{eq4}
    \end{align}
    \label{all-eq}
\end{subequations}
Reference to \eqref{eq1} works but a \vrefrange{eq1}{eq4} or 
\crefrange{eq1}{eq4} or \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4} or 
\vref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4} fail

\end{document}
```

This gives me:
    [image: output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  have you tried loading the `amsmath` package before the other three?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a *typical* error: Loading packages which uses counters and special reference formats after `cleveref` is wrong, since this package uses sophisticated macros in in the background, well, to do the clever reference ;-)

`cleveref` should be the **last** package to be loaded, even **after** `hyperref`

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
Some group of equations:
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        f(x) &= x \label{eq1} \\
        g(x) &= x+1 \label{eq2} \\
        h(x) &= x+2 \label{eq3} \\
        k(x) &= x+3 \label{eq4}
    \end{align}
    \label{all-eq}
\end{subequations}
Reference to \eqref{eq1} works but a \vrefrange{eq1}{eq4} or 
\crefrange{eq1}{eq4} or \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4} or 
\vref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4} fail

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder, haw you generate image in your answer. I prepare similar answer, but not figured out, how to show result in tight form. So on the end I give up ...

Comment: @Zarko: I just use the screenshot device from `Gimp` and then export the image as `.jpg`. The Adobe reader snapshot tool does not maintain the link borders, unfortunately.

Comment: @Cristian Huppfer, thank you for your answer. I usually use 'preview' package, but using it I didn't find a way to combine some text and equations. Unfortunately I newer use 'Gimp' (does it exit in Windows?).

Comment: @Zarko: I never use `preview`... but here's a download link for Windows (untested, since I am no Windows user ;-)) http://download.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.8/windows/gimp-2.8.14-setup-1.exe.torrent

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

@Zarko, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible