# How can I insert original text into a beamer frame, keeping the section*'s format?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\origintext}[??]{?????}         %<-------------How ?
\section{aaa}

\subsection{bbb}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  frame 1


\frame{test frame 1}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% frame 2

\origintext{

\section*{sec title}

\subsection*{subsec title}

sadsadf
asfsaf


asfasf

}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  frame

\frame{test frame 3}

\end{document}
```

thanks a lot!  @cfr @barbara beeton @Christian Hupfer.  Yes, I want show sth. from another .tex file use `\documentclass{article}`, hope looks like the result pdf file. the `\section*{}` generate bold large font ...  Barbara Beeton gives a way, but I want generate it directively

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{sec title}

\subsection*{subsec title}

sadsadf
asfsaf


asfasf
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by `\origintext`? LaTeX code displayed as LaTeX code?

Comment: how cound i define a new command \origintext{} to show the original text with section*{}'s format:font,size,...

Comment: actually, origintext from a documentclass{article}

Comment: Sorry, your question is incomprehensible to me

Comment: i only want to show some article's text in a frame, but the section's in beamer not function, because beamer explain section as structure

Comment: this is a guess ... you want to show what the "original text" looks like when it is on a page in an article.  if that's what you want, then the easiest way i know of is to set just that sample *separately* using the document class of the original (making sure to set `\thispagestyle{empty}`), then insert the result in the `beamer` file with `\includegraphics`.  some techniques for cropping the image are suggested in answers to this question: [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866/579)

Comment: Please don't vote to close a question asked less than 1 hour ago: give the author a chance to improve it in response to comments. Especially when it is the OP's first question and some code is presented. I know this question is unclear in its current form and that the code is not a complete example, but the OP is engaging with discussion in comments and, even if they weren't, an hour would be much too soon to assume they won't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\origintext}[1]{%
\begingroup
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
#1
\endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{aaa}

\subsection{bbb}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  frame 1


\frame{test frame 1}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% frame 2
\frame{
\origintext{

\section*{sec title}

\subsection*{subsec title}

sadsadf
asfsaf


asfasf

}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  frame

\frame{test frame 3}

\end{document}
```