# Export tikz as image file

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, export

I have created a tikz picture as a standalone.

Can I export the tex file as an image instead of as a pdf?

Comment: No, but you can easily convert the pdf to jpg or png.

Comment: A couple possible solutions are discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11880/55879.

Comment: `standalone` provides `convert` option. For this you will need `imagemagick` installed.

Comment: Or you can directly convert it using imagemagick → `convert -density 300 yourfile.pdf yourfile.png` (or `.jpg` whatever)

Comment: QTikZ is a nice editor cum preview pane and offers export to PNG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved the best results with `pdftoppm`, the anti-aliasing is much better than imagemagicks `convert`.

Just do:

```
$ pdftoppm -png -r <dpi> document.pdf > document.png
```

I usually use 300 or 600 dpi.

`pdftoppm` comes with `poppler` (package `poppler-utils` on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Texmaker, right-click on the pdf, then choose `convert page to png image` choice. **Note:** if you intend to include this image in your tex file, then you can include the pdf directly. As a matter of fact, the quality of the pdf is better than converting the pdf to an image.