# How can I export a flowchart as an image on ShareLatex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, sharelatex, export, flow-charts

I have built a flowchart on a ShareLatex project using **tikz** library and it's working fine.

I need to put this flowchart on a slide for a presentation (using PowerPoint, Google Docs or whatever), so I would like to export my flowchart as an image (png, jpeg, ...).

Is there a method which can help me with this issue?

I know that I can take a screenshot of the flowchart but I would like to know if a better solution exists.

Comment: Download the pdf and convert that (you might even insert it in your presentation). Another way: Make a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,
it has worked. I have found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275023/export-tikz-as-image-file?rq=1) that I didn't find before