# Outputting TeX to PNG or JPEG?

Tags: math-mode, output

I found a couple of interesting formulas and would like to post an image of them on Twitter.  Anyway, I'd like the formulas to look good, so *obviously* I'll be typesetting them with TeX...  So is there a good - and preferably as direct as possible - way to make output from TeX into a PNG or JPEG file?

Comment: Do not use jpeg for something with text/symbols in it. That will look horrible.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11880/36296, the standalone class can automatically convert to png