# Cannot get inequalities to align *and* be centred

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

I am trying to align some inequalities, but for some reason they are shifted to the right of the page. Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    \vert x-a \vert &< \varepsilon = \delta \\
    \frac{\vert (1+x)-(1+a)\vert}{1} &< \varepsilon \\
    \frac{\vert (1+x)-(1+a)\vert}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} &< \varepsilon \\
    \frac{\vert (\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+a})(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+a})\vert}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} &< \varepsilon \\
    \vert \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1+a} &< \varepsilon
\end{align*}
\end{equation*}
```

I am pretty new to Latex, so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

P.s. How can I get the "output" of the code to display on this post? I feel like it would make the issue a lot more clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the `align*`environment? You cannot nest `align` in `equation`. For that, use `aligned` or `split`. You can post a screenshot of the result with an icon in the tool bar at the top of the edit window.

Comment: @Bernard Would using the 'align*' environment mean simply removing the '\begin{equation*}' and '\end{equation*} lines? If so that does not change anything.

Comment: regarding your question of how to get your output to display here, this question has some good advice: [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866).  after you've done that, click on the icon to the right of the `{}`, above the question box; this brings up a window that allows you to post a `.png` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest `align*` into `equation*`: it doesn't make sense, because `align` is by itself a display making environment. If you think to it, the unstarred variant `align` numbers each line; so it should be

```
\begin{align*}
A &< B \\
...
\end{align*}
```

without any `equation*` around it.

You *might* do

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
A &< B \\
...
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

and the result would be the same except perhaps for the spacing around the display and for the fact that the former can be split across pages (with `\displaybreak` before the relevant `\\` command) and the latter can't.

However, such a display will look awful anyway, because the centering will be with respect to the width of the longest left-hand side plus the longest right-hand side, so the alignment point will appear too much on the right.

Such unbalanced lines should be treated, in my opinion, with `gather` and some more generous interline space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\lvert x-a \rvert < \delta = \varepsilon \\[1ex]
\frac{\lvert (1+x)-(1+a)\rvert}{1} < \varepsilon \\[1ex]
\frac{\lvert (1+x)-(1+a)\rvert}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} < \varepsilon \\[1ex]
\frac{\lvert (\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+a})(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+a})\rvert}
     {\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} < \varepsilon \\[1ex]
    \lvert \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1+a}\rvert < \varepsilon
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible improvement is remembering that when a square root vinculum happens to fall near a closing parenthesis, a thin space is needed; so the fourth display line should be

```
\frac{\lvert (\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+a}\,)(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+a}\,)\rvert}
     {\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} < \varepsilon \\[1ex]
```

The difference is small, but noticeable by absence.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's an error message when nested. Your shifted environment is only a visual effect due to the dissymmetry between the l.h.s. and the r.h.s. Look at the result with the `showframe` option of `geometry`, to visualise the margins. B.t.w. I replaced the pairs  `\vert … \vert` with pairs `\lvert … \rvert`, which will have a better horizontal spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \vert x-a \vert &< \varepsilon = \delta \\
    \frac{\lvert (1+x)-(1+a)\rvert}{1} &< \varepsilon \\
    \frac{\lvert (1+x)-(1+a)\rvert}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} &< \varepsilon \\
    \frac{\lvert (\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+a})(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+a})\rvert}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} &< \varepsilon \\
    \lvert \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1+a} \rvert&< \varepsilon
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
    \begin{document}

  \begin{align*}
   \vert x-a \vert &< \varepsilon = \delta \\
    \frac{\lvert (1+x)-(1+a)\rvert}{1} &< \varepsilon \\
   \frac{\lvert (1+x)-(1+a)\rvert}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} &<       
    \varepsilon \\
    \frac{\lvert (\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+a})(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+a})\rvert}    
    {\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}} &< \varepsilon \\
    \lvert \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1+a} \rvert&< \varepsilon
   \end{align*}


      \huge
     \begin{tabular}{rl}
     $ x-a$  &$< \varepsilon = \delta$ \\
     &\\
    $\frac{| (1+x)-(1+a)|}{1}$ &$< \varepsilon$ \\
    &\\
   $\frac{| (1+x)-(1+a)|}{\sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1+a}}$ &$< \varepsilon $\\
  &\\
   $\frac{| (\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+a})(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+a})|}   
   {\sqrt{1+x}     +     \sqrt{1+a}}$ &$< \varepsilon $\\
   &\\
    $ \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1+a} $& $< \varepsilon$\\
  \end{tabular}
```

% second uses normal latex commands. I am unable to paste the out put but you can check it yourself.