# How do I add spaces when I'm doing $$ $$?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, formatting

Like for example, if I have:

For example when I use the double quotes and make everything center and bigger, I can't really type sentences or anything, because it all comes together:

x = 4 or x = 5

becomes

`$$ x=4 or x=5$$`
See how the 'or' is squished? How do I space it out?

Comment: I don't know why it didn't show up ... but yeah I think you get the point

Comment: the "or" should be treated as text:  `\text{ or }`, with the spaces inside the text string.  also, better to use `\[ ... \]` than `$$ ... $$` -- see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Thank you, and do you know why it doesn't show up? When I'm on mathoverflow and stuff the formatting works, here it doesnt show?

Comment: in this forum, we prefer to see the input code, since that's where the problems are found.  a visual example of the output can be prepared using the methods described here: [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866)

Comment: @KracX - Math.SE and similar sites use MathJax. The syntax may look similar to LaTeX, but the underlying engine is completely different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has already been [answered in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343701/how-do-i-add-spaces-when-im-doing/343744#comment843459_343701) but let's go right on ahead and provide a full answer down here.

For our purposes, LaTeX has three *modes*: math mode, paragraph mode and left-to-right mode (LR mode).

In math mode, LaTeX treats everything as maths. It doesn't know that `or` is a word, it just treats it as maths. What this means is that Roman (as in the Roman or Latin alphabet we use in English) letters are set in italics by default. A string of Roman letters `abc` is treated as a string of variables, `a`, `b` and `c`, multiplied together. This is normally what you want with maths, right? If you have `ab` you usually mean the variable *a* times the variable *b*.

Now, if I write `or`, LaTeX doesn't know that's the English word "or", it just treats it as the variable *o* times the variable *r*.

Next thing: spacing in math mode is handled automatically - and very smartly - by TeX. White space in the input is ignored in the output:

```
a b    cd        e   f
```

And

```
abcdef
```

Produce the same result. (The spacing around these letters will be suitable for a string of variables being multiplied as we discussed above.)

Spacing around operators and relations such as `\sin`, `\log`, `+`, `-`, `=`, `\in` and so on is all done for you.

```
x\sin x+d=4
```

And

```
x    \sin x+      d     = 4
```

Will produce the same result, with the appropriate spacing around the sin the + and the =.

So what do you do if you want to have some text in math mode, including proper spaces around the text?

The simplest way is to be sure to load the `amsmath` package and use the `\text{}` command. This, I believe, puts us in LR mode, but it doesn't really matter for our purposes, what it means is that LaTeX is back to treating things as text! `or` is now taken to be a word, one or more spaces in the input produces a space in the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  x = 4 \text{ or } x = 5
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, there are two types of math mode. Display math mode is used for displaying equations, they will be centred, there will be a skip above and below to visually separate them, large operators like `\sum` will appear large and limits will generally be set above and below the operator. In TeX, display math mode was accessed by `$$ ... $$`, but [in LaTeX, we prefer `\[ ... \]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: I often want more space around words in equations like this. In such cases I use either `\qquad\text{ or }\qquad` or `\quad\text{ or }\quad`.

Comment: @Andrew Good point, I'd add it in, but I don't think it would fit so well in mine. A second answer focusing on general spacing commands in math mode, however, would be a wonderful complement - or I guess there must be an answer somewhere on here already if you'd rather add a link? :)

Comment: I suspect that it is partly a matter of personal taste (and so should be avoided!). I don't think that I am qualified to write a general answer about spacing math-mode:) Happy to leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would always prefer something like

```
\[ 
\text{$x=4$ or $x=5$} 
\]
```

since it handles the spacing around the *or* correctly (hacking around with `\quad` and friends rarely does).

Comment: But be careful, this probably gives you the in-line size for math symbols (such as integral signs), which might come out too small compared to displayed equations.

Comment: Good point, if this is an issue then `\displaystyle` is your friend