# Latex code of a table with rotated columns with "sideways" doesn't work

Tags: tables, rotating

This latex code intents to produce a stand alone picture of a table.

I have the following latex code that has been generated under Rstudio by a xtable function and encapsulated by me (code lines surrounding the begin/end table's code) :

```
\documentclass[crop=true, varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
% latex table generated in R 3.3.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
\hline
& \begin{sideways} CA \end{sideways} & \begin{sideways} CB \end{sideways} &     \begin{sideways} CC \end{sideways} \\ 
\hline
RA & 1 & 4 & 7 \\ 
RB & 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 
RC & 3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I generate a .png picture with the 2 following lines based on Windows10/Miktex2.9 :

```
pdflatex.exe -output-format=dvi ./drugs_cross_tex.tex
dvipng.exe -T tight -D 600 -z 9 -q -o ./drugs_cross_tex.png ./drugs_cross_tex.dvi
```

Unfortunatly, the .png picture produced is incorrect because the 3 columns (CA, CB, CC) are not 90 deg rotated (but they are shifted to the right).

[image]

Here is the log file :
[click here to download](http://dl.free.fr/iyZFOTziD)

Anyone can tell me how to make this latex code working ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why not doing the conversion to PNG directly with `standalone`?

Comment: Hello egreg, I don't understand what you mean by "doing the conversion to PNG directly with standalone". I run Rstudio. The xtable function produce the latex code (the part of code starting by \begin{table} and ending by \end{table}) and dump it in a file. the header and footer code lines has been added by me to make it works with the "latex to dvi" processor. What I need is just to make pictures (of statistic tables) without having to use complex Tools such as sweave, knitr, lyx, ...

Comment: Apparently `dvipng` doesn't understand the `dvips` special for rotation.

Comment: You'r right! It was dvipng. In pdf output format, both "sideways" and "rotatebox" methods work. Now I need to find another way to get a picture file with Miktex Tools...

Answer (score 2):

If you have ImageMagick installed, then you can simply run

```
pdflatex -shell-escape
```

on the file

```
\documentclass[convert={density=1200}]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
% latex table generated in R 3.3.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
\hline
& \begin{sideways} CA \end{sideways} & 
  \begin{sideways} CB \end{sideways} &     
  \begin{sideways} CC \end{sideways} \\
\hline
RA & 1 & 4 & 7 \\
RB & 2 & 5 & 8 \\
RC & 3 & 6 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(I removed the useless `table` environment, so also `varwidth` is unnecessary.)

This will produce a PNG at 1200 dpi (use the resolution you prefer).

Read section 4.6.2 in the manual of `standalone` for some quirks about Windows.

Here's the PNG I get

> [image]

(I added the block quote to show it's transparent).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `sideways`, but this is not indented for a situation like that. Use `\rotatebox` instead. If you want a little space above the headings, use something like `\rotatebox{90}{Title~}`.

[image: rotated]

```
\documentclass[crop=true, varwidth=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
% latex table generated in R 3.3.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
\hline
& \rotatebox{90}{CA} & \rotatebox{90}{CB} & \rotatebox{90}{CC}\\ 
\hline
RA & 1 & 4 & 7 \\ 
RB & 2 & 5 & 8 \\ 
RC & 3 & 6 & 9 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello TeXnician, Your code seems correctly processed (no error) but the result is the same for me (header not rotated, but shifted to right). Thus, the problem seems to come from MikTex pdflatex and/or dvipng ... any idea ?

Comment: @Syl87 Please compile your code using `pdflatex` into a PDF file. If that's correct then it's probably a problem with `dvipng`. Probably you should follow egreg's suggestion and do the conversion via `standalone` class.

Comment: Yes! With pdf output format, both codes (sideways and rotatebox) worked! :-)   But, do you know how can I simply output a picture (any format : png, jpg, svg, ...) with the Miktex Tools (or another simple tool chain) ?

Comment: @Syl87 If you do not want to use screenshot, you should have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11880/124577 (the updated solution).

Comment: Ok, thanks a bunch for your help and the link.