# arara: cropping the output PDF file then converting it into image using ImageMagick

Tags: arara, pdfcrop

How can I create a **single** rule for `arara` that crops the output PDF file using `pdfcrop` command then convert the output cropped file the same way done by [CarLaTeX's convert rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339227/2288) (shown below)?

```
!config
# Convert .pdf to any format file allowed by ImageMagick convert command (the default is png)
# author: CarLaTeX
# last edited by: CarLaTeX, Dicember 26th 2016
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample usage: 
# - these both create a .png file
# % arara: convert
# % arara: convert: {format: png}
#
# - this creates a .gif file with red background
# % arara: convert: {format: gif, background: red}
#
# - this creates a .png file with a trimmed image 
#   (use the parameter "otheroptions" to add any option not already explicitly considered by the rule, 
#   that is any option different from -background, -alpha, -density and -quality}
# % arara: convert: {otheroptions: -trim +repage}
#
#
# This rule is really just a shortcut for commands like the following:
#
#  convert -density 300 myfile.pdf myfile.png
#
# which will output myfile.png
#
identifier: convert
name: convert
commands: 
- <arara> @{ isWindows( "cmd /c convert", "convert" ) } -background @{background} -alpha @{alpha} -density @{density} @{otheroptions} "@{ getBasename(file) }.pdf" -quality @{quality} "@{ getBasename(file) }.@{format}"
arguments:
- identifier: density
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.density}
  default: 150
- identifier: otheroptions
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.otheroptions}
- identifier: quality
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.quality}
  default: 100
- identifier: background
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.background}
  default: white
- identifier: alpha
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.alpha}
  default: remove
- identifier: format
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.format}
  default: png
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote the following rule based on Carla's code (save it as `pconv.yaml`):

<sub>*(Ouch, I am not used to version 3.0 syntax! I desperately need to publish version 4.0 as soon as possible!)*</sub>

```
!config
identifier: pconv
name: 'pdfcrop + convert'
commands:
- 'pdfcrop @{ini} @{margins} @{ getBasename(file) }.pdf @{ getBasename(file) }-tmp.pdf'
- '@{ isWindows( "cmd /c convert", "convert" ) } -background @{background} -alpha @{alpha} -density @{density} @{otheroptions} -strip @{ getBasename(file) }-tmp.pdf -quality @{quality} @{ getBasename(file) }.@{format}'
- '@{ isWindows("cmd /c del", "rm -f")} @{ getBasename(file) }-tmp.pdf'
arguments:
- identifier: ini
  flag: "@{ isTrue(parameters.ini, '--ini') }"
  default: "add here your default value"
- identifier: margins
  flag: "--margins @{parameters.margins}"
- identifier: density
  flag: "@{parameters.density}"
  default: 150
- identifier: otheroptions
  flag: "@{parameters.otheroptions}"
- identifier: quality
  flag: "@{parameters.quality}"
  default: 100
- identifier: background
  flag: "@{parameters.background}"
  default: white
- identifier: alpha
  flag: "@{parameters.alpha}"
  default: remove
- identifier: format
  flag: "@{parameters.format}"
  default: png
```

Now, from the TeX file (e.g, `foo.tex`):

```
% arara: pdftex
% arara: pconv
\nopagenumbers
Hello world!
\bye
```

**Update:** In your example, use this line instead:

```
% arara: pconv: { ini: yes }
```

Now, running `arara`:

```
$ arara foo.tex 
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFTeX... SUCCESS
Running pdfcrop + convert... SUCCESS
Running pdfcrop + convert... SUCCESS
Running pdfcrop + convert... SUCCESS
```

We will have a corresponding `foo.png` image:

[image: foo]

And that's it. `:)`

**Note:** For some odd reason, I had to include `-strip` to the `convert` program. I am not sure the reason, it may be the version I have or some restriction of the generated PDF file. Your mileage may vary...

Comment: Thanks for help. But [this MWE](https://pastebin.com/fvqdKLWM) doesn't work. It fails in the conversion.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou I need more info, then. `:)` Output of `arara -v foo.tex` and `arara.log` will help.

Comment: My bad. Here it is https://pastebin.com/VHnn4mey.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: no worries. `:)` It's odd, I've never seen `pdfcrop` fail before. What's the output when you run `perl.exe c:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\pdfcrop\pdfcrop.pl test.pdf test-tmp.pdf` in the command line? Does it fail too?

Comment: Yes, it fails. However, I have to add `--ini` to make it run successfully.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: interesting. I will update the code and add an `ini` flag too.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. But is it necessary for me to understand the meaning of different `pdfcrop` options? or the output quality would be the same in either case?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: I updated the rule to include the `--ini` flag for `pdfcrop`. I really don't know too much of `pdfcrop`, as I am really surprised it failed with you. I didn't even know about the `--ini` flag! I think your question is beyond my humble comprehension of those tools, perhaps a follow-up question might enlight us all (regarding `pdfcrop`, of course). `:)`

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: my pleasure, poke me at any time!

Comment: Use `\nopagenumbers` instead of `\def\folio{}`.

Comment: @PauloCereda How can I set a default value for the true-false condition of `--ini`? Additionally, in the help file of `pdfcrop`, for example,  margins can be set as `--margins '5 10 5 20'`, so how can I set it here using these values?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: I updated the rule and added the `default` key to the `ini` parameter, please edit the value and add the default fallback. Regarding `--margins`, you will only be able to set up just one value (which will be applied to all margins) because of a bug/restriction of `arara` 3.0 (solved in the unreleased version 4.0); this is achieved by setting `% arara: pconv: { margins: 10 }`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello! Is it possible to add a rule compatible with arara v5?

Comment: @Diaa We wrote rules for `convert` and `pdfcrop` in the official repo: https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/development/rules/arara-rule-convert.yaml and https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/blob/development/rules/arara-rule-pdfcrop.yaml They are targeted for the release of version 6, but are compatible with version 5 as well. Hope it helps! `:)`