# LaTeX in pdf annotations

Tags: viewers

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 17 and a given pdf file. Are there any ways to create a sticky note (or other annotation) which will contain two things:

- some editable non-LaTeX text (like any usual annotation)
- a rendered LaTeX formula (for example .png image)

*Comment by KeKs Dose below shows how to paste .png (or other image) formula only. I edited my post to highlight two above mentioned requirements.*

I have only pdf file and don't have any other sources (.tex, .docx etc) of this file.

Also I would like to know if there exists other PDF editors that have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your LaTeX formula in a *.tex document, render it and produce a *.png. How to do that, see here [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866/4736) , please.

Then open the PDFeditor and insert the pictures. Under Windows I used PDF Annotator (https://www.pdfannotator.com/de/ ) to this end; under Linux there is PDF Master editor (https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/ ).

However, the only contibution from the LaTeX side is the png of the formula.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to show that annotation should contain not only LaTeX formula but also editable text. Unfortunately, I can't vote for you useful answer because I don't have enough reputation.