# Running LaTeXiT as a command-line instruction

Tags: macros, graphics

I wonder if it is possible to run LaTeXiT as a command-line instruction that takes options.
Specifically, I want to run something like

`LaTeXiT -if abc.tex -of abc.png`

or

`LaTeXiT < abc.tex > abc.png`

in a Terminal of MacOS such that the resulting image file `abc.png` is just like one generated via pressing the `LaTeX it!!` button of LaTeXiT with the content of `abc.tex` entered into the text-editing area. I understand that there is an executable file LaTeXiT under the directory `/Applications/TeX/LaTeXiT.app/Contents/MacOS`. But it does not seem to support the above command-line options.

Comment: Something very similar can be done using the `standalone` documentclass with automatic crop and png conversion, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible.

Comment: @Marijn, thanks for the pointer. But I hope the latex source can be stored in the generated image file, just like what LaTeXiT does.